# Tips for golfing in Kotlin

Tags: code-golf, tips

Given Google's recent announcement of official [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/) support for Android development, I thought it might be timely to poll the community for some awesome golfing tips for this relatively new JVM language.

Kotlin includes a unique combination of features among it's JVM siblings which makes it potentially attractive for golfing:

- [operator overloading](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#operator-overloading)
- [local](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#local-functions), [infix](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#infix-notation), and [static extension functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extensions)
- [smart casts](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#smart-casts)
- [Groovy-style type-safe builders](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/type-safe-builders.html#type-safe-builders)
- [type aliases](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/type-aliases.html#type-aliases)
- [ranges](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/ranges.html#ranges)
- an extensive functional [collections package](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/index.html)
- [scripting support](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/command-line.html#using-the-command-line-to-run-scripts)

So, how do I squeeze the last few bytes out of my Kotlin program? One tip per answer, please.

Comment: Would there be interest in a golfing language that shortens some of Kotlin's longer names, but doesn't add a lot of extras (at least initially)? I am thinking of making common 1 letter, making string char counts shorter and adding single letter strings with only 1 quote mark?

Comment: *Common functions

Comment: Seems Kotlin golfing interest is not that high :( http://data.stackexchange.com/codegolf/query/793250/top-kotlin-golfers

Comment: I plan to start submitting more Kotlin solutions! I'll have to check out that project of yours as well.

Answer (score 7):

## Use `+` instead of `toString`

As one might expect, `String` overloads the `+` operator for string concatenation, like so.

```
print("Hel" + "lo")
```

However, checking [the docs](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-string/plus.html) tells us that it accepts `Any?`, not just `String`. As stated:

> Returns a string obtained by concatenating this string with the string representation of the given other object.

In other words, `String + anything` makes sure to call `.toString()` on the right hand side before concatenating. This allows us to shorten `it.toString()` to `""+it`, a massive 8 byte savings at best and 6 bytes at worst.

---

## Use `fold` instead of `joinToString`

Related to the above, if you're calling `map` and then `joinToString`, you can shorten that by using `fold` instead.

```
list.map{it.repeat(3)}.joinToString("")
list.fold(""){a,v->a+v.repeat(3)}
```

Comment: TIL fold is a thing, nice

Comment: Just as a note to be fair to `joinToString`, this example shouldn't use map, but instead use the transform lambda of `joinToString` itself: `list.joinToString(""){it.repeat(3)}` so the tip only saves 2 characters

Comment: About `""+it`, I find `"$it"` more convenient because you don't need parentheses when chaining with other stuff

Answer (score 6):

Starting from 1.3 you [can omit args in fun main()](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew13.html) completely, thus shaving off 18 chars (that is, the length of `args:Array<String>`).

Answer (score 5):

## Submitting Lambdas: A Guide

[According to meta consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6915/how-do-we-calculate-the-length-of-lambda) the default for most challenges allows submitting lambdas/anonymous function bodies. Part of this consensus is that the declaration/assignment of the lambda doesn't have to be included. Take the typical lambda:

```kotlin
val f={a:Int,b:Int->a+b}
```

We can omit the declaration, that being `val f=` which saves us 6 bytes.

```kotlin
val f=              // declaration
{a:Int,b:Int->a+b}  // lambda
```

For the rest of this tip I will write the declaration on one line and the lambda body on the next line to make it clear that it is separate. Know that the declaration line won't count to the score; on TIO you'd include it in the Header and put the lambda as the Code [(see here.)](https://tio.run/##y84vycnM@1@WmKOQZvu/OtHKM69EJwlE6tolaifV/k8rzVPITczM09BUsFUoKMrMK9FI0zDUMdLU/A8A)

### Type Inference and You

Kotlin has a fairly robust system of *type inference*. If the compiler can infer the type of something, you can omit the type information. Lambdas themselves are typed; their type signatures are expressed as:

```kotlin
(Param1Type, ...ParamNType) -> ReturnType
```

Therefore, the type of the above is `(Int, Int) -> Int`.

The type information of a lambda can be inferred from two places:

- The lambda body
- The declaration/use site (when assigned to a variable with a type annotation, or passed to a function)

In the given example above, the types of the parameters are stated *in* the lambda body, and the return type of the lambda can be inferred by the expression in the body because the types of everything is known. This is why the type of the lambda doesn't have to be stated in the declaration; the compiler knows its complete type signature!

...but what if we did?

### A Parlor Trick

```kotlin
val f:(Int,Int)->Int=
{a,b->a+b}
```

By moving the type information of the lambda into the declaration, it's removed from our actual answer. Thanks to inference, the types of `a` and `b` are known, and the return type is known, so this compiles, and it's free bytes!

### Inferred `it` Parameter for Single-Param Lambdas

If a lambda only takes one parameter and its type can be completely inferred, you don't even have to specify a parameter in the lambda body! The inferred parameter will be named `it`. Take the two examples:

```kotlin
val shuf:(List<T>)->List<T>=
{l->l.shuffled()}
                              // -2
val shuf:(List<T>)->List<T>=
{it.shuffled()}
```

The compiler knows that this lambda takes one parameter and it knows what type it is, so if it isn't bound to a name in the lambda body, it is named `it` instead. You can use this to save 2 bytes in the degenerate case above, but if you have to refer to the parameter many times, it will be shorter to simply give it a name as in the former.

```kotlin
{it*it*it*it}
{n->n*n*n*n}
```

### Lambdas With Receiver

Kotlin allows you to specify a *receiver* parameter for a lambda. Basically, you can rebind `this` inside. You indicate this lambda takes a receiver by writing the receiver type and a dot before the type signature:

```kotlin
Recv.(Param1, ...ParamN) -> Ret
```

Where this is useful is highly dependent on your approach.

```kotlin
val f:(Int,Int)->Int=
{a,b->a+b}
                       // -1
val f:Int.(Int)->Int=
{this+it}
```

Of course, what's most useful is that `this` is the implicit receiver of member access. So if your submission consists mostly of a call chain on one of the parameters, or you refer to a field a couple times, this is extremely useful.

```kotlin
val shuf:(List<T>)->List<T>=
{l->l.shuffled()}
                               // -5
val shuf:List<T>.()->List<T>=
{shuffled()}
```

It can be a bad call to use `this` instead of `it` e.g.

- If there's only one parameter to the lambda and you don't need to call any methods on it
- You need to [destructure the parameter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/188801/42096)
- etc.

### Some Examples

Examples can help you learn!

- [pleTriwapt Sgpin (Triplet Swapping)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/201444/42096)
- ["Multiply" two strings](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/201037/42096)
- [Count sum of all digits](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/172953/42096)

Answer (score 3):

## Extension Functions

Extension functions can really help to reduce the names of built in methods, and chains of them, an example could be:

`fun String.c() = this.split("").groupingBy{it}.eachCount()`

but this only helps if:

A) The call is long enough to cancel out the definition

B) The call is repeated

## Use of lambdas rather than methods

Lambdas can return without using the return keyword, saving bytes

## KotlinGolfer

A project I have started [here](https://github.com/jrtapsell/kotlinGolfer) which takes pretty Kotlin code and gives posts with tests and TIO links automatically

Answer (score 3):

## Defining Int's in params

This will likely have some pretty specific use cases where it may be worth it, but in recent question I golfed I found I could save a few bytes by defining my variable as optional parameters rather than defining them in the function.

Example from my answer to [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/188391/a-scene-of-jimmy-diversity) question:

defining variable in the function:

`fun String.j()={var b=count{'-'==it}/2;var a=count{'/'==it};listOf(count{'o'==it}-a,a-b,b)}`

defining variables as params:

`fun String.j(b:Int=count{'-'==it}/2,a:Int=count{'/'==it})=listOf(count{'o'==it}-a,a-b,b)`

because `var a=` is the same length as `a:Int=` it will be the same number of bytes to define them (this is only the case for `Int`) however since I now only have 1 line in the function I can drop the `{}` and I also drop a single `;` (the other is replaced with a `,`)

So if there are any functions that require defining an Int, and would be a 1 liner if you didn't define the int in the function - then doing it as a parameter will save a couple bytes

Answer (score 3):

## You don't need to add a `;` after the imports if the last element is `*`

for instance, you can do this

```kotlin
import java.util.*import kotlin.random.*import kotlin.random.Random
```

even this

```kotlin
import java.util.*import kotlin.random.*fun main(){}
```

Comment: Please separate the tips by answers

Answer (score 2):

## The `to` infix function

There is a standard infix function named `to` that creates `Pair`s of two values. It's commonly used with `mapOf()` for defining `Map`s but it's can potentially be a lot shorter than the `Pair()` constructor.

```
Pair(foo,bar)   //constructor
foo to bar      //best case 
(foo)to(bar)
((foo)to(bar))  //worst case
```

Comment: Most of the time it is better to use ranges instead of pairs (for numbers). `foo..bar` is shorter then `foo to bar` also `range.last` is shorter then `pair.second`

Answer (score 2):

## Destructuring in lambda arguments

Say you want to accept a `Pair<*,*>` in a lambda. Normally, handling this would be annoying. As an example, here's a lambda that takes a `Pair` and checks if the two values are equal:

```
{it.first==it.second}
```

This is long-winded and clumsy. Luckily, Kotlin allows you to destructure any destructable type (any type that implements `componentN()` methods, such as `Pair`, `Triple` etc.) as arguments to a lambda. So, we can rewrite this in the following way:

```
{(a,b)->a==b}
```

It looks similar to pattern matching a tuple in something like F#, and it is in many cases. But a wide variety of types in Kotlin support destructuring (`MatchResult` is a useful one.)

You can take more arguments, though. Say your lambda had to take a `Pair` and an additional value. You'd simply write the lambda signature like this:

```
(a,b),c->  // pair first
a,(b,c)->  // pair second
```

Answer (score 2):

## you can assign the functions (most important case is the main however) an unit type function

for instance instead of doing
`fun main(){println("hello world")}`

you can do

`fun main()=println("hello world")`

which shaves off a mere byte

Answer (score 2):

## The `repeat` function sometimes can shave off a few bytes in some cases

the repeat function basically translates to this,

for `repeat(100){something(it)}`

it becomes `for(it in 0..100-1){something(it)}`

the main problem of this is that the it starts from 0 as always and goes until times-1 which might not be ideal for some cases. I'd suggest, for any for loops, converting for loops to repeat loops and checking the byte count, like you might convert it then name the variable i instead of it etc. This will most certainly save you bytes if you use the variable "it" frequent enough.

Answer (score 0):

## Get STDIN

If you want to read a line, you can do `readln()` instead of `readLine()!!`