# All ASCII characters with a given bit count

Tags: code-golf

(Title with thanks to @ChasBrown)

[Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17585/56555)

**The Background**

This challenge is inspired by a question that I recently posted on [Puzzling Stack Exchange](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/81925/sum-letters-are-not-two-different). Please feel free to follow the link if you are interested in the original question. If not then I won't bore you with the details here.

**The Facts**

Every printable standard ASCII character has a decimal value between 32 and 126 inclusive. These can be converted to their corresponding binary numbers in the range 100000 to 1111110 inclusive. When you sum the bits of these binary numbers you will always end up with an integer between 1 and 6 inclusive.

**The Challenge**

Given an integer between 1 and 6 inclusive as input, write a program or function which will output in any acceptable format all of the printable standard ASCII characters where the sum of the bits of their binary value is equal to the input integer.

**The Examples/Test Cases**

```
1 -> ' @'
2 -> '!"$(0ABDHP`'
3 -> '#%&)*,1248CEFIJLQRTXabdhp'
4 -> ''+-.3569:<GKMNSUVYZ\cefijlqrtx'
5 -> '/7;=>OW[]^gkmnsuvyz|'
6 -> '?_ow{}~'
```

An ungolfed Python reference implementation is available [here (TIO)](https://tio.run/##dc1NCoMwEAXgfU8xuErQjfGnIOQAXfUA6kKtqVk4kRjBnj5NLbUtxFm9GT7eTA8zKGTW3noBgkgKxQncKF7WWxBKwwoSQTd470nCopidP@o1DW8lkpXuh5Y3JSvqfe/42ExEoonaL5IC5mUkHeVc/pRtr0NedoN2le8O3ZtFIyg7aVcCwQWnxRQQV3hdzBYDCGE2mggSU@pyUGFw@tfMp9mRTnw6OdKpT6dHOvPp7EjnPp3v2j4B).

**The Rules**

1. Assume the input will always be an integer (or string representation of an integer) between 1 and 6 inclusive.
2. You may write a program to display the results or a function to return them.
3. Output may be in any reasonable format but **must be consistent for all inputs**. If you choose to output a quoted string then the same type of quotes must be used for all inputs.
4. Standard loopholes prohibited as usual.
5. This is code golf so shortest code in each language wins.

Comment: Are we allowed to return/print a list of the decimal ascii values or do we need to have them in the form of characters (eg. `63` vs `?`)?

Comment: Must be the actual characters.

Comment: "the same type of quotes must be used for all inputs" Python, for example, uses single quotes (`'`) for the string representation of a string by default, but uses double quotes (`"`) if the string contain a single quote and no double quotes. Not that this specific case will matter much, as you're probably better off returning the actual string instead of its representation, and you can still use single quotes in such a string for input anyway, but I feel it's worth mentioning here.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Agreed. That is why I thought it might be interesting just to throw that in as an extra rule :-)

Comment: Thanks  @RIKER. The point of the format of the test cases was to show different acceptable formats of output however I'll leave your edits in place.

Comment: Seeing as there are only 6 possible inputs, you may as well include them all as test cases.

Comment: @ElPedro I hope you don't mind, I just added the remaining two cases just to complete the list.

Comment: @flawr No problem but you may want to escape the sigle quote in test case 4 ;-)

Comment: @ElPedro I wasn't sure what to do as it is probably a good idea to have some quotes, as there is a space in the first example, but the usual quotes both appear in the output:) Edit: maybe use french guillemets (`« »`)? :D

Answer (score 30):

## x86-16 machine code, IBM PC DOS, <del>29</del> 25 bytes

**Machine code:**

```
00000000: be81 00ad b330 b108 d0c8 12dd e2fa 3adc  .....0........:.
00000010: 7502 cd29 fec0 79ec c3                   u..)..y..
```

**Listing:**

```
BE 0081     MOV  SI, 081H   ; SI = memory address of command line string
AD          LODSW           ; AL = start ASCII value (is 20H from space on cmd line)
                            ; AH = target number of bits (in ASCII)
        CHR_LOOP:
B3 30       MOV  BL, '0'    ; BL = counter of bits, reset to ASCII zero
B1 08       MOV  CL, 8      ; loop through 8 bits of AL
        BIT_LOOP:
D0 C8       ROL  AL, 1      ; rotate LSB of AL into CF
12 DD       ADC  BL, CH     ; add CF to BL (CH is always 0) 
E2 FA       LOOP BIT_LOOP   ; loop to next bit
3A DC       CMP  BL, AH     ; is current char the target number of bits?
75 02       JNE  NO_DISP    ; if not, do not display
CD 10       INT  29H        ; display ASCII char in AL (current char in loop)
        NO_DISP: 
FE C0       INC  AL         ; increment char to next ASCII value
79 EC       JNS  CHR_LOOP   ; if char <= 127, keep looping
C3          RET             ; return to DOS
```

Standalone PC DOS executable program, input number from command line.  Output is displayed to console window.

[image]

Comment: For a moment I thought it said "Download and test *AT* ABCT.COM", as if you had registered a domain just for this answer.

Answer (score 14):

## [CP-1610](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Instrument_CP1600) assembly ([Intellivision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intellivision)), 20 DECLEs<sup>1</sup> = 25 bytes

Takes \$N\$ in **R0** and a pointer to the output buffer in **R4**. Writes all matching characters in the buffer and marks the end of the results with **NUL**.

```
                ROMW    10              ; use 10-bit ROM width
                ORG     $4800           ; map this program at $4800

                ;; ------------------------------------------------------------- ;;
                ;;  test code                                                    ;;
                ;; ------------------------------------------------------------- ;;
4800            EIS                     ; enable interrupts

4801            MVII    #$103,    R4    ; set the output buffer at $103 (8-bit RAM)
4803            MVII    #2,       R0    ; test with N = 2
4805            CALL    getChars        ; invoke our routine

4808            MVII    #$103,    R4    ; R4 = pointer into the output buffer
480A            MVII    #$215,    R5    ; R5 = backtab pointer

480C  draw      MVI@    R4,       R0    ; read R0 from the buffer
480D            SLL     R0,       2     ; R0 *= 8
480E            SLL     R0
480F            BEQ     done            ; stop if it's zero

4811            ADDI    #7-256,   R0    ; draw it in white
4815            MVO@    R0,       R5

4816            B       draw            ; go on with the next entry

4818  done      DECR    R7              ; loop forever

                ;; ------------------------------------------------------------- ;;
                ;;  routine                                                      ;;
                ;; ------------------------------------------------------------- ;;
      getChars  PROC

4819            MVII    #32,      R1    ; start with R1 = 32

481B  @loop     MOVR    R1,       R3    ; copy R1 to R3
481C            CLRR    R2              ; clear R2
481D            SETC                    ; start with the carry set

481E  @count    ADCR    R2              ; add the carry to R2
481F            SARC    R3              ; shift R3 to the right (the least
                                        ; significant bit is put in the carry)
4820            BNEQ    @count          ; loop if R3 is not zero

4822            CMPR    R2,       R0    ; if R2 is equal to R0 ...
4823            BNEQ    @next

4825            MVO@    R1,       R4    ; ... write R1 to the output buffer

4826  @next     INCR    R1              ; advance to the next character
4827            CMPI    #127,     R1    ; and loop until 127 is reached
4829            BLT     @loop

482B            MVO@    R3,       R4    ; write NUL to mark the end of the output

482C            JR      R5              ; return

                ENDP
```

#### Output for N=2

NB: The opening parenthesis looks a lot like an opening square bracket in the Intellivision font. Both characters are distinct, though.

[image: output]

*<sup>screenshot from [jzIntv](http://spatula-city.org/~im14u2c/intv/)</sup>*

---

*<sub>1. A CP-1610 opcode is encoded with a 10-bit value, known as a 'DECLE'. This routine is 20 DECLEs long, starting at $4819 and ending at $482C (included).</sub>*

Comment: +1 just for being (a) a solution for the Intellivision, and (b) the first Intellivision code I've ever seen.

Comment: @Eight-BitGuru Coding on the Intellivision is pretty fun. And today's homebrew games are written in 16-bit ROM, which unlocks the full power (ahem...) of the CPU. :)

Comment: Impressive! Had no idea the Intellivision had a frame buffer and a built in character set. So much more advanced than the Atari 2600 for sure. Very nicely done!

Comment: @gwaugh The GROM (for Graphics ROM) contains all printable ASCII characters and a few common graphical shapes. Fun fact: it also contains some executable code that did not fit in the main ROM.

Comment: Definitely more advanced than the 2600, but if memory serves, Mattel didn’t reveal any of the advanced stuff hiding out in ROM, so third-party devs were either limited to straight machine code or had to suss out the fancy stuff on their own. Might be apocryphal.

Answer (score 12):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 62 bytes

```python
lambda n:[chr(i)for i in range(32,127)if bin(i).count('1')==n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PcvBCoQgEIDhV5mbCkOgbQWBT1J7sDZrosYQO@zTm6fO//9d/7QFNtnbMR/unH4OuB/mLUpSPkQgIIboeF1kbVCbTpGHibjkag43Jym0UNbyN7@7RoM1frDBtocrEicgBCGqPRToC1X5AQ)

Comment: `sum(map(int,bin(i)[2:]))==n` can become `bin(i).count('1')==n` to save 7 bytes.

Answer (score 10):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>41</s> 34 bytes

```perl6
{chrs grep *.base(2)%9==$_,^95+32}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/OjmjqFghvSi1QEFLLymxOFXDSFPV0tZWJV4nztJU29io9n9xYqWCHlBxWn6RgqGenpn1fwA)

Anonymous code block that takes a number and returns a string of valid characters.

#### Explanation:

```perl6
{                                }  # Anonymous code block taking a number
      grep                ,^95+32   # Filter from the range 32 to 126
           *.base(2)                # Where the binary of the digit
                    %9                # When parsed as a decimal modulo 9
                      ==$_            # Is equal to the input
 chrs                               # And convert the list of numbers to a string
```

It can be proven that for any number \$n\$ in base \$b\$, \$n \equiv \text{digitsum}(n) \pmod{b-1}\$ (clue: remember that \$b \pmod{b-1}=1\$).

We can use this to get the digitsum of our binary number by parsing it as a decimal number and moduloing by 9, which is valid because the range of numbers we are using is guaranteed to have less than 9 bits. This is helped along by Perl 6's automatic casting of the binary string to a decimal number when used in a numeric context.

Answer (score 9):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes

```
žQʒÇbSOQ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6L7AU5MOtycF@wf@/28MAA)

**Explanation**

```
žQ        # push the printable ascii characters
  ʒ       # filter, keep elements whose
   Ç      # character code
    b     # converted to binary
     SO   # has a digit sum
       Q  # equal to the input
```

Answer (score 7):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 60 bytes

*Using [Jo King's modulo trick](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/184649/58563)*

```javascript
n=>(g=x=>x>>7?'':Buffer(x.toString(2)%9-n?0:[x])+g(x+1))(32)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZchLCsIwEADQvfeQzlBaNPWDhaTgFVyKi1KT0FJmJE3L3D66lbzlm/qtX4YwfmJF/LbJ6UTagNeijRhz7Yqiva/O2QBSR37EMJIHhftbRd2hfcoLSw9SHhGhUZgGpoVnW8/swcFvd/@jsmmyOWVzzuaCmL4)

---

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org),  <s>70</s>  69 bytes

```javascript
n=>(g=x=>x>>7?'':Buffer((h=x=>x&&x%2+h(x>>1))(x)-n?0:[x])+g(x+1))(32)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZclLCoMwEADQfe@hzhCUNrYKQiL0GqULsUlUJBF/zO1T665k@97Q7M3Szv20ptZ9lNfCWyHBCBKSpCzrJKmem9ZqBuhOjGOKOOvg2BsiEKa2vlYveiMzQOxnOUffOru4UWWjM6Dh0Mu/8EDyQO6BPAIpEP0X)

#### Commented

```javascript
n => (              // n = input
  g = x =>          // g = recursive function, taking a byte x
    x >> 7 ?        //   if x = 128:
      ''            //     stop recursion and return an empty string
    :               //   else:
      Buffer(       //     create a Buffer:
        (h = x =>   //       h = recursive function taking a byte x
          x &&      //         stop if x = 0
          x % 2 +   //         otherwise, add the least significant bit
          h(x >> 1) //         and do a recursive call with floor(x / 2)
        )(x)        //       initial call to h
        - n ?       //       if the result is not equal to n:
          0         //         create an empty Buffer (coerced to an empty string)
        :           //       else:
          [x]       //         create a Buffer consisting of the character x
      ) +           //     end of Buffer()
      g(x + 1)      //     append the result of a recursive call to g with x + 1
)(32)               // initial call to g with x = 32
```

Comment: [60 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZchLCsIwEADQvfeQzlBaNPWDhaTgFVyKi1KT0FJmJE3L3D66lbzlm/qtX4YwfmJF/LbJ6UTagNeijRhz7Yqiva/O2QBSR37EMJIHhftbRd2hfcoLSw9SHhGhUZgGpoVnW8/swcFvd/@jsmmyOWVzzuaCmL4) using Jo's modulo trick.

Comment: @Shaggy Oh. That's a nice one.

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
ØṖOB§=ʋƇ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wjIc7p/k7HVpue6r7WPv///@NAA)

```
ØṖ       printable ascii character list
  OB     to binary
    §    popcount
     =   equal to input?
      ʋƇ filter (implicitly output)
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 7 bytes

```
∈Ṭ&ạhḃ+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AUUAuv9icmFjaHlsb2cy/3t3IiAtPiAidz9@4oaw4oKC4bag4bqJfeG1kP/iiIjhuawm4bqhaOG4gyv//1sxLDIsMyw0LDUsNl0)

A predicate which [functions as a generator](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10753/85334), takes input through its output variable, and produces each character through its input variable. Because Brachylog.

```
           The input variable (which is an element of the output)
∈          is an element of
 Ṭ         the string containing every printable ASCII character
  &        and the input
   ạh      converted to a codepoint
     ḃ     converted to a list of binary digits
      +    sums to
           the output variable (which is the input).
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 9 bytes

```
;EÆ¶Xc¤è1
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=O0XGtlhjpOgx&input=Ng) or [test all inputs](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&header=xA&code=O0XGtlhjpOgx&footer=KyIgPSAiK1Y&input=NgotbVI)

```
;EÆ¶Xc¤è1     :Implicit input of integer U
;E            :Printable ASCII
  Æ           :Filter each X
   ¶          :Test U for equality with
    Xc        :  Character code of X
      ¤       :  To binary string
       è1     :  Count the 1s
```

Answer (score 5):

## Excel (2016 or later), 76 bytes

```
=CONCAT(IF(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(DEC2BIN(ROW(32:126)),0,))=A1,CHAR(ROW(32:126)),""))
```

Takes input from A1, outputs in whatever cell you put this formula. This is an array formula, so you need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to input it. The "2016 or later" is because it needs the `CONCAT` function (the deprecated `CONCATENATE` won't take an array as argument).

Comment: I like this. I'm a Lotus Notes and 123 guy so this works for me :-)

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <strike>77</strike> 68 bytes

#### Approach using for loop

-9 bytes thanks to Giuseppe

```r
n=scan();for(i in 32:126)if(sum(intToBits(i)>0)==n)cat(intToUtf8(i))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P8@2ODkxT0PTOi2/SCNTITNPwdjIytDITDMzTaO4NFcjM68kJN8ps6RYI1PTzkDT1jZPMzmxBCIcWpJmARTW/G/yHwA)

#### Previously:

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <strike>78 69</strike> 66 bytes

-12 bytes thanks to Giuseppe

```r
a=32:126;cat(intToUtf8(a[colSums(sapply(a,intToBits)>0)==scan()]))
```

Turns the numbers 32 to 126 into a matrix of bits then sums across the rows to find which match the input number.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P9HW2MjK0MjMOjmxRCMzryQkP7QkzUIjMTo5Pye4NLdYozixoCCnUiNRByzplFlSrGlnoGlrW5ycmKehGaup@d/kPwA)

Comment: Use `intToBits(x)>0` rather than `as.single`

Comment: Nice, I tried `|0` and got an error and just assumed the logic operators wouldn't work.

Comment: [66 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/P9HW2MjK0MjMOjmxRCMzryQkP7QkzUIjMTo5Pye4NLdYozixoCCnUiNRByzplFlSrGlnoGlrW5ycmKehGaup@d/kPwA) for the "previous" approach using `sapply` rather than `matrix`

Answer (score 5):

## C (standard library), <strike>74</strike> 67 bytes

```
i;j;k;f(n){for(i=31;i<126;k||puts(&i))for(k=n,j=++i;j;j/=2)k-=j&1;}
```

Using only standard library functions. Thanks go to @gastropner for improvement from 74 to 67 bytes.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FctLCoAgEADQtZ7CVcxQERa0meYwIRijZNFnZZ3daP14rl2cK0UoUCQPCbPfDhAeLMlk@5Hi8@z3dUIliD9FTk3guv5H6LjH2HKoLL1F0mXWWRKgyVp5sEj61ap8)

Comment: [67 bytes](https://tio.run/##Fcs7CoAwDADQuT1FJ0lQEevgEHMYKVTSYhU/U/XsFefHc@3iXClCgSJ5SJj9doDwYEmm3o4Un2e/rxMqQfwpcmoC1/U/QscWY8uh6uktki6zzpIATdbKg0XSr1blAw "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: @gastropner that is an amazing improvement! Thank you!

Comment: I think you need to start at index 31 in order to pick up space in the `f(1)` case (because the `++i` skips it).

Comment: @LambdaBeta You're absolutely right, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

## Java 8, <s>131</s> 71 bytes

-60 bytes thanks to everyone in the comments
Returns a `java.util.stream.IntStream` of codepoints

```java
n->java.util.stream.IntStream.range(32,127).filter(i->n.bitCount(i)==n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY4xa8MwEEZ3/4obJbCPJoV2MA6UQKBDoZCxdFBsyT1XPgXpnBKMf7urtkO7dLo3fPd4g7mYauje19ablODJEM8FsdjoTGvhMA95gJOQxyTRmhEfWY7fBE5ltr2NwLpeivN08tRCEiP5XAJ1MGadymvi/uUVTOyTnosDOGhWrnb/qzEa7q263Zab7b1GRz4HKap2jCeSfZhYFOmmYb3WX7VZ3obOPofMCRpw6NSdRgkPMZqr0nVxvCaxI4ZJ8JxzxLNi@wE/ber3ubwp/6jQW@7lTWfBsqyf)
Using HashSet, 135 bytes. Returns a `Set<Object>`:

```java
n->new java.util.HashSet(){{for(int i=31;i++<126;add(Long.toBinaryString(i).chars().map(c->c-48).sum()==n?(char)i+"":""),remove(""));}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY5BT4QwEIXv/IqG0zRIk12NMSBrYuLGg572aDyMpUARWtIOmA3Z346jHjzNS95737weF8z7@nPTA8YoXtG6NbGOTGhQG3Fcew6omeygToZEA@wJJ8tLMs0fg9UiEhKfxdtajNyGEwXr2rd3DG2Ua3IUTbW5/ODMl/hnPWPsmAdyXRsffqG2ut6VNsvud/vbEusaXrxrFflH6zCc/6hgpdIdhghSjTiBzg86v7mTKs4jyKpyD/BjS5ulaZGm8iqY0S8GWPLky1YmjWpgz3kKBrmiog9kahY84wl1B6dzJDMqP1NRTPyTZJlw8xs)

Comment: [128 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZU5NS8NAEL3nVyw9zaAZsIoKMRE9FDyIh3oTD9PtJm5MNmF3Uwghvz1OW8GDp8fM@6z5wGm9/150wyGoV7ZuSqyLxpesjdpMtQhoiLahEL3hlrYneHhUYeiNV2@72uhYqBJexFXJx2E2J/2wa6xWIXIUOHR2r1rJBnFbV318KvZVwCnZqFLli0uLfz0Sd64iz64ycL2@vFrfIZW2kXVg08JR7J6tYz@eU8Ei6S/2AZBa7kGnhU5v7pHC0ALmuTu93zuZfOTgqEV9sVrhkiXbMUTTUjdE6iUsNg7@Jj15z2OQut@ikkq4RblPBCBilszz8gM "Java (JDK) – Try It Online")

Comment: Static access from non-static context reeeeeee. Thanks.

Comment: `Long.toBinaryString(i)` can be `Long.toString(i,2);`

Comment: Small tip: [without streams is usually shorter ;)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/184655/52210)

Comment: To continue on my first comment: if you take the input as a `Integer` instead of `int`, `Long.toBinaryString(i)` can actually be `n.toString(i,2)` to save some more bytes.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen that's what my first comment does

Comment: @ExpiredData Ah, you're right. Since Benjamin responded to you I thought he had already edited your changes into his answer, but apparently not.. In that case just `n.toString(i,2)` stands as suggested golf. :) Oh, and the `+""` can be removed as well I now notice.

Comment: [92 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZY4/S8RAEMX7fIotZ8AseIIWMRERDizE4uzEYrK3Gzcmu2F3cnCEfPY43BUWVo/5897v9XSisj/@bGagnNUb@bAUPrBNjoxV@6WXBz2zH3TmZGnUh4s8Pqk8Tzap97a3hhvl4FVcnWwCVmsxze3gjcpMLHKK/qhGyQZx@9B9filKXcal2Cun6i2UzT@OxF1ROlHoLNztbm53D6idH6Qd@LIJuvX8EufA4LGuA@qRpo8ojcCUDZhvSmhwq4rDObMddZxZT4LnIcAf7jklOmfN8VoNnHZwjzJfDoCIVbGu2y8), but still using your stream approach.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Just get rid of the final map: [71 bytes](https://tio.run/##ZY4/a8MwEMV3f4obJagFTaEdXLuUQCBD6ZCxdDg7kjlXPhvpFAjGn90VydCh0@P@vPd7A16wHM4/W@cxRvhA4qUgFhscdhYOy5AfTBLyJkqwOJrTTV7fIKbZBvhsB9tJA04ds6vPG9bVWsyp9dRBFJQsl4nOMOZsld3E/dc3YOijXooDOKg3Lpt/nBx3R5mA3Fv1tHt43L1o48jndorKhk1Lsp8SiyJd16y3qjhdo9jRTEnMnEniWf0lv4eA12hkurdQzjj1rPN8OyitdVWs6/YL). Java deals with integers as characters [since version 5...](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#%3Cinit%3E(int%5B%5D,int,int))

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Oh, now it's not much longer than [my 67 bytes answer without stream](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/184655/52210). (Your TIO in your comment fails however because you forgot to modify the lambda signature.)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen You're right. Here's the fixed version: [(still) 71 bytes](https://tio.run/##dY4xa8MwEEZ3/4obJbCPJoV2MA6UQKBDoZCxdFBsyT1XPgXpnBKMf7urtkO7dLo3fPd4g7mYauje19ablODJEM8FsdjoTGvhMA95gJOQxyTRmhEfWY7fBE5ltr2NwLpeivN08tRCEiP5XAJ1MGadymvi/uUVTOyTnosDOGhWrnb/qzEa7q263Zab7b1GRz4HKap2jCeSfZhYFOmmYb3WX7VZ3obOPofMCRpw6NSdRgkPMZqr0nVxvCaxI4ZJ8JxzxLNi@wE/ber3ubwp/6jQW@7lTWfBsqyf). And yes, I saw your version which I upvoted less than 10 minutes ago ;)

Comment: Thanks for filling my inbox guys. I did not know `bitcount` existed, nice.

Answer (score 4):

## Dyalog APL Extended, <s>24</s> 22 bytes

```apl
⎕ucs a⌿⍨⎕=+⌿2⊤a←32…126
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qKNdIe3/o76ppcnFComPevY/6l0B5NlqA5lGj7qWJD5qm2Bs9KhhmaGRGUjx/zQuQ640LiMgNgZiEyA2BWIzAA)

-2 bytes thanks to [ngn](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/24908/ngn)

Alternative 22 bytes in regular Dyalog APL by ngn:

```apl
⎕ucs 32+⍸⎕=32↓+/↑,⍳7⍴2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG9qZv6jtgkGXI862hXSQPzS5GIFYyPtR707gBxbY6NHbZO19R@1TdR51LvZ/FHvFqP/QKX/07gMudK4jIDYGIhNgNgUiM0A)

Comment: `(`expr`)∘=` -> `⎕=`expr

Comment: without extended: `⎕ucs 32+⍸⎕=32↓+/↑,⍳7⍴2` (⎕io←0)

Answer (score 4):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), <sup><s>31</s> <s>27</s></sup> 23 bytes

```
((=1#.#:)u:@#])32+i.@95
```

*-2 thanks to south*

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FOJT31NAVbKwV1BR0FAwUrINbVU3AO8nFbWlqSpmuxXUPD1lBZT9lKs9TKQTlW09hIO1PPwdIUIrtNkys1OSNfIU1JW8FQwUjBWMFEwVTBDCK5YAGEBgA)

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup><s>31</s></sup> 27 bytes

*-4 bytes thanks to Galen*

```
[:u:32+[:I.]=1#.32#:@+i.@95
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/o61KrYyNtKOtPPVibQ2V9YyNlK0ctDP1HCxN/2typSZn5AM1Oagr6FoppCkYQgUUlVQ0DBydXDwCEqAyRlAZZVU1TS0dQyMTC2dXN08vn8CgkIjEpJSMAqg6Y6g6@/j88uraOqioGdd/AA)

### Original Answer

```
a.#~&(95{.32}.])]=1#.2#:@i.@^8:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/E/WU69Q0LE2r9YyNavViNWNtDZX1jJStHDL1HOIsrP5rcqUmZ@QDNTqoK@haKaQpGEIFFJVUNAwcnVw8AhKgMkZQGWVVNU0tHUMjEwtnVzdPL5/AoJCIxKSUjAKoOmOoOvv4/PLq2jqoqBnXfwA)

- `2#:@i.@^8:` produces the binary numbers 0 through 255 (`2 ^ 8` is 256)
- `1#.` sums each one
- `]=` produces a binary mask showing where the sum equals the original input
- `a.#~ mask` uses that binary mask to filter J's full ascii alphabet `a.`
- `&(95{.32}.])` but before doing so take only elements 32...126 from both the alphabet and the mask

Comment: [`[:u:32+[:I.]=1#.32#:@+i.@95`](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/o61KrYyNtKOtPPVibQ2V9YyNlK0ctDP1HCxN/2typSZn5AM1Oagr6FoppCkYQgUUlVQ0DBydXDwCEqAyRlAZZVU1TS0dQyMTC2dXN08vn8CgkIjEpJSMAqg6Y6g6@/j88uraOqioGdd/AA "J – Try It Online") for 27 bytes

Comment: Thanks Galen.  TIL you could do `i.@95`

Comment: [25 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FOJT31NAVbKwV1BR0FAwUrINbVU3AO8nFbWlqSpmuxUyO21MpBuS7a1lBZT9nKIVbT2Eg7U8_B0hQiv02TKzU5I18hTc1OwVDBSMFYwUTBVMEMIrlgAYQGAA)

Comment: @south Thanks.  I shaved an additional 2 off using your idea.

Answer (score 4):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 86 bytes

```cs
n=>Enumerable.Range(32,95).Where(x=>"0123456".Sum(g=>x>>g-48&1)==n).Select(x=>(char)x)
```

Thanks to @ExpiredData for giving me the idea to use `Sum()`! When I get back to my PC, I will replace the string `"0123456"` with unprintables, saving three bytes.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY1NC4JAFADv/grxEPvIlrTsS3cvURB0yoNnW572QF@wriCIv93q1HUYZky3Mh3N155NRuzC24X7Fm35bDAzr9JqXamZlf5j@Si5RrGJw2MCsnihRTEoHayjeLNNdoHM@1bUSg9a16vtYRGBUgwyxwaN@5ni14UB5tSr3lZ8rz6pKKVsn9JyCZ7vF5Yc3olRBON6OvljNAUhhZ2zxLU8v9mUTlSCACCdPw)

Comment: [Sum and - instead of Count and ==](https://tio.run/##RY3LCsIwEADvfkXxtIsx@MRHm1xEQfCkQs81bO1C3UKaSkH89lq9eB2YGVePXc3doRGXsAR13EvzIJ/dSkpckXlrc9OJsX@sz5ncCeYztVmiTgvyBK2xu0qe5IO@VpfgWe7QqhnqS/MAZ6wbL9ZojPSASnLhK8A3jy128SCvPPTziM005mQV82iEgyhKPQc6sRAMX5P3NnpN30PFqv71dT90WYAcGBHj7gM "C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler) – Try It Online")

Comment: @ExpiredData Thanks for the idea to use `Sum()`!

Answer (score 4):

## Java 10, <s>98</s> <s>97</s> <s>94</s> <s>70</s> 67 bytes

```java
n->{for(var c='';c-->31;)if(n.bitCount(c)==n)System.out.print(c);}
```

-24 bytes thanks to *NahuelFouilleul*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ZU@xasNADN3zFY8sucPYEAoder0snTo0S8bS4XKxjRJHDndnQwmmn@7KrunQCkmgJ@np6ex6l59Pl9E3Lka8OeL7CiBOZaicL7GfSqBv6QSvXgWvywDWRuBBQjwml8hjD4bFyPnuXrVB9S7A283Xxvg83z1sjaZKcXGk9NJ2nJTX1rI@fMZUXou2S8Ut0AybYTQrob11x0ZoF/ZZwFXkqUOSwfr9Ay7UUf/Imw7KNshuDejZPkrOsqUJ/LtC2foJ6/mJybjwin6rv9MNq6U3zE8P4zc)

**Explanation:**

Contains an unprintable character with unicode value `127`.

```java
n->{                         // Method with Integer parameter and no return-type
  for(var c='';c-->31;)     //  Loop character `c` in the range ['~', ' '] / (127,31):
    if(n.bitCount(c)         //   If the amount of 1-bits in the two's complement binary
                             //   representation of the current characters
                    ==n)     //   equals the input:
      System.out.print(c);}  //    Print the current character
```

Comment: [-24bytes](https://tio.run/##ZU9Na8MwDL33Vzx6qU1IoAx2mOdedhpsvfQ4dnDdJKhLlWI7gVHCfnqmZGGHTUgCPX28p7PrXX4@fYy@cTHi1RHfVgBxKkPlfIn9VAJ9Syd49Sx4XQawNgIPEuIxuUQeezAsRs53t6oNqncB3m6@Nsbn@e5uazRV6qXlujhSemo7Tspra1kfPmMqL0XbpeIaaIbNMJqVXL52x0YuLwSzhosoVIckg/XbO1yoo/5ROHHKNshuDejR3kvOsqUJ/GOhbP2A9fzHZFx4Rb/V3@mG1dIb5r@H8Rs) using Long.bitCount

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul Ah, I always forget about that builtin in Java! Thanks a lot. And 3 more bytes can be saved by using `n.bitCount`. :)

Comment: Yeah, Java beats JavaScript once more! I love those character challenges :P

Answer (score 4):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 52 bytes

```
[ 32 126 [a,b] [ bit-count = ] with filter >string ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYyxDoIwFEV3v@J@gJKAiYNGV@PCYpxIh9I8oAFKfX2E@PX1JWz35J6czjpZOH/er/p5xWxlKNiGntK@Wy@bT4SRONCERN@VgtM3CfvQJ0QmkV9UENwOFzTlsTW5wblCWSlaRTTQzsktq0p3GGxeBnR@EmI89hJMnm3UrHVjkf8)

- `32 126 [a,b]` Create a range of printable ascii values
- `[ bit-count = ] with filter` Select values with the bit count indicated by the input
- `>string` Convert the result from a sequence of code points to a printable string

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 69 bytes

```python
lambda n:[chr(i)for i in range(32,127)if sum(map(int,bin(i)[2:]))==n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dco7DoAgDADQq3RsExbrYELCSZQBP2gTKQR18PTo@vLKex9ZuUU3tTOkeQ2gdlyOikIxVxAQhRp037Bn0/FAEuF6EqZQUPQ2s@hfR7aeyDn1rdSfMSITtQ8)

Comment: That's exactly what I got when I golfed my ref implementation. +1

Answer (score 3):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 10 bytes

```
₵R⟪¤cbΣ=⟫⁇
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AR0A4v9nYWlh///igrVS4p@qwqRjYs6jPeKfq@KBh///Mw)

```
		| implicit input, n
₵R		| push printable ascii
  ⟪	⟫⁇	| filter the list where:
   ¤cbΣ		| the sum of the code point in binary
       =	| is equal to n
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 48 bytes

```ruby
->n{(' '..?~).select{|x|x.ord.digits(2).sum==n}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vWkNdQV1Pz75OU684NSc1uaS6pqKmQi@/KEUvJTM9s6RYwwgoU5pra5tXW/u/QCEt2ij2PwA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-a`,  <s>50</s> 43 bytes

*@NahuelFouilleul saves 7 bytes*

```perl
map{$_=chr;unpack('B*')%9-"@F"||say}32..126
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z83saBaJd42OaPIujSvIDE5W0PdSUtdU9VSV8nBTammpjixstbYSE/P0Mjs/3/jf/kFJZn5ecX/dX1N9QwMDf7rJgIA)

Comment: could save one byte using `"@F"` instead of `$F[0]`

Comment: [48 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z83saBaJd42OaPIujSvIDE5W0PdSUtd07auUt9QX19XycFNqaamOLGy1thIT8/QyOz/f@N/@QUlmfl5xf91fU31DAwN/usmAgA)

Comment: [43 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z83saBaJd42OaPIujSvIDE5W0PdSUtdU9VSV8nBTammpjixstbYSE/P0Mjs/3/jf/kFJZn5ecX/dX1N9QwMDf7rJgIA) using `%9` trick by @JoKing

Answer (score 3):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://gitlab.com/n9n/k), 20 bytes

**Solution:**

```
`c$32+&(+/2\32+!95)=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/z8hWcXYSFtNQ1vfKAbIULQ01bQ1@/8fAA)

**Explanation:**

Evaluated right-to-left:

```
`c$32+&(+/2\32+!95)= / the solution
                   = / equals?
       (          )  / do this together
               !95   / range 0..94
            32+      / add 32, so range 32..126
          2\         / break into base-2
        +/           / sum up
      &              / indices where true
   32+               / add 32
`c$                  / cast to character
```

Comment: `\`c$32+&32_(+/!7#2)=` or `\`c$(31<)#&(+/!7#2)=` brings it to 19.

Answer (score 3):

## 6502 assembly (NES), 22 bytes

Machine code:

```
a0 1f a6 60 c8 98 30 fb ca 0a b0 fc d0 fb e8 d0 f1 8c 07 20 f0 ec
```

Assembly:

```
    ldy #$1f ; Y holds the current character code
NextCharacter:
    ldx $60 ; load parameter into X
    iny
    tya
    bmi (NextCharacter + 1) ; exit at char 128, #$60 is the return opcode

CountBits:
    dex
Continue:
    asl
    bcs CountBits
    bne Continue

CompareBitCount:
    inx ; fixes off-by-one error and sets Z flag if bit count matches
    bne NextCharacter
    sty $2007
    beq NextCharacter ; always branches
```

[Full program](https://hastebin.com/raw/xemikiwege.asm). Tested with FCEUX 2.2.3, should work on any standard NES emulator.

Inspired by Ryan Russell's answer. Input given at CPU address $60. Outputs to the console's Picture Processing Unit memory.

Comment: Hello and welcome to PPCG. Is there any way to verify your solution apart from building a cartridge, i.e. an (online) emulator or specification?

Comment: @JonathanFrech I've added a full program that can be assembled and run locally. As I understand, the NES environment is not really standardized for codegolf.

Answer (score 3):

## VBA, 146 bytes

```
Sub Main()
n=3
For i=32 To 127
b=CStr(Application.WorksheetFunction.Dec2Bin(i))
If Len(b)-Len(Replace(b,"1",""))=n Then MsgBox Chr(i)
Next
End Sub
```

I wonder if somehow it could be done using Excel alone, I am not a excel formula pro....

Comment: `=IF(LEN(DEC2BIN(32))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(DEC2BIN(32),"1",""))=A1,CHAR(32),"")` Checks against the value in cell `A1` and displays the character if the binary sum matches. It needs to be repeated 95 times, one for each ASCII value that we need to check, so it comes out at around 7100 bytes - not very golfy but at least it can be done!

Comment: @ElPedro - thanks to the `Let()` command, this can actually be compacted into a really satisfying [Excel answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/240721/61846) at 86 bytes

Comment: You can get this down to 91 bytes if you convert this to an immediate window function, use `[...]` evaluation, take input from `A1` and output to the VBE debug window - `x=[Dec2Bin(ROW(1:126))]:For i=32To 126:?IIf(Len(Replace(x(i,1),0,""))=[A1],Chr(i),"");:Next` - Check out [Tips for Golfing in VBA](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/5175) for more info

Answer (score 3):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles), 5 bytes

```
|_~`^+`@ 2
```

That's 10 nibbles each encoded as half a byte in the binary form.

Translation:

```
|          filter
 _         printables (since stdin is empty)
 ~         not
  `^       xor
    +      sum
     `@2   to base 2
        $  filter var (implicit)
    @      first input arg (implicit)
```

It uses not of the xor to set itself up for implicit args (instead of == which wouldn't be able to use any)

Usage:

```
nibbles <filename>.nbl <input number>
```

Nibbles isn't on TIO yet...

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3.10](https://www.python.org), 58 bytes

```py
lambda n:(chr(i)for i in range(32,127)if i.bit_count()==n)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3rXISc5NSEhXyrDSSM4o0MjXT8osUMhUy8xSKEvPSUzWMjXQMjcw1M9MUMvWSMkvik_NL80o0NG1t8zShJmih6TDUMde04uIsKMoEKlRS0svKz8zTSAOarAnVsWABhAYA)

It's kind of like [Lynn's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/183631/112099).
Just it uses the `.bit_count` introduced in Python3.10, so its shorter

More info about `.bit_count` here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html

Comment: I really like the idea of going through old questions and finding where new functions can shave a few bytes off! +1 from me.

Answer (score 3):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 60 bytes

```
{n->(32..127).filter{n==it.countOneBits()}.map{it.toChar()}}
```

Note:
For the moment Kotlin's STDOUT in ATO is always empty.
And TIO doesn't support countOneBits().

More information about how to count bytes for a Kotlin answer:
https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/202985/112099

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LYwxCsJAEEX7nCIEhN1iBxILRUwKrQTBQi-wSFZHN7MhmdgsOYlNGr1TbuMGU314n_fe36djizSMC9NRXGkkIX300jY2G3Eglqo4Ysvb_V03RZx_OjZqPW49qUIsM4A0W0kwaLlsPOU5MlxdR3yicofcCtlDpWsfMLspEUA_N5RIAYI8_XWDxJaEEcgSHg7p4s4c4E0kiZR9NEvD8N8f)

Comment: you can use [this ATO link](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LYwxCsIwFEB3T1EyJUM_tA6KtB0UB0Fw0AuE0ujX-FPSX5fQk7h00Tt4FG9jS50ePHjv-b45tkj956FtZFZyR6ziYo8NZ5uL9kWUv1o28fKbBYoLOU8BknShwKDlygfKc2QoXUt8oGqN3EjVwV3XYdDsxsUguv8jlQnAGDu_1eUl1B6JLUkjkRVcHdLJHXmQZymEUt1MiKns-4k_) just dropping the `fun main`

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 10 bytes

```
6Y2tB!si=)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/3yzSqMRJsTjTVvP/fxMA)

### Explanation

```
6Y2        % All ASCII Chars
   t       % dup
    B      % convert each to binary
     !     % transpose
      s    % sum
       i=  % equal to the input?
         ) % Keep truthy elements
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 70 bytes

```
FromCharacterCode/@Select[32~Range~126,s=#;Tr@IntegerDigits[#,2]==s&]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcHBCoMwDADQXxEET4Kswi5SKDiE3YbuVnoIXYiFtYU0Z389vpdBTswgKYKS1Y1rXk9giIK81h9O7sA/RvGzuXYohNfDPMdm@@XL7l0ECfmVKEnz/WiCtW0Ig344FekceRNUbw)

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 83 bytes

```powershell
param($n)[char[]](32..126|?{([convert]::ToString($_,2)|% t*y|group)[1].count-eq$n})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vyCxKDFXQyVPMzo5I7EoOjZWw9hIT8/QyKzGvlojOjk/ryy1qCTWyiokP7ikKDMvXUMlXsdIs0ZVoUSrsia9KL@0QDPaMFYvOb80r0Q3tVAlr1bz////RgA)

Takes input `$n`, constructs a range from `32` to `126` and pulls out those numbers where `|?{}`: the number, `convert`ed `ToString` in base `2`; converted `t`oCharArra`y`; `group`ed into `0`s and `1`s; taking the `[1]` index of that grouping; taking the `.count` thereof, and checking that it's `-eq`ual to our input `$n`umber. Those numbers are then cast as a `char`-array and left on the pipeline. Output is implicit, with newlines between elements.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 10 bytes

```
Φγ⁼Σ↨℅ι²Ｉθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMMtM6cktUgjXUfBtbA0MadYI7g0V8MpsThVw78oJTMvMUcjU1NHwUgTSDgnFpdoFGoCgfX//8b/dctyAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
 γ          Predefined ASCII characters
Φ           Filtered by
      ι     Current character's
     ℅      ASCII code
    ↨       Converted to base
       ²    Literal 2
   Σ        Summed
  ⁼         Equals
         θ  First input
        Ｉ   Cast to integer
            Implicitly printed
```

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 72 bytes

```php
for($x=31;$x++<126;)echo$argn==count_chars(decbin($x),1)[49]?chr($x):'';
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwMWVll@koZJYlJ5na2itAGbY2JpBWdramgrVXAoKqckZ@RARHYUAj4B4V38f6/9gjRW2xobWKhXa2jaGRmbWmiCFEMNsk/NL80rikzMSi4o1UlKTkzLzgKo1dQw1o00sY@2TM0CaNa3U1a3/Q82HGoywgav2PwA)

Comment: `count_chars(decbin($x),1)[49]` can just be `decbin($x)%9`

Answer (score 2):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 92 bytes

```
func[n][repeat k 95[if n = length? replace/all enbase/base c: form #"^_"+ k 2"0"""[prin c]]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYzBCsIwEETPzVcM69FDRVAwIP5Dr8sqMd1oMYkl1u@PtYhzeId5zBTta6c9iwm2hnf2nIWLjuomPHDY8RCQcUTUfJvuJ8wqOq@tixGar@6l7RfwFuFZElZ0vtB6nm5pQ0Q8liHDi0j9nSbswQZzFsUJZEGyNAHpbyYQNY2R@gE)

Answer (score 2):

### C(MSVC) 50 bytes

```
i;f(n){for(i=31;i++<127;n-__popcnt(i)||puts(&i));}
```

### C(gcc), 60 bytes

```
i;f(n){for(i=31;i++<127;n-__builtin_popcount(i)||puts(&i));}
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##BcFBCsMgEAXQdTyFqzKDuEgL7WKSs0giWD4ko7S6SnJ281703xh7hyRSPlL@EebXKHBuGp8fUR/C2rBVaCi5xNy0Evg8S6t/eoBZrg6tdl@gxPYwQ6I3i7nM0G8)

Comment: Can you not use `||` instead of `?n:`?

Comment: You can remove one byte by combining the increment with the check: `i;f(n){for(i=32;i++<127;n-__builtin_popcount(i)||puts(&i));}`

Answer (score 2):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) with Communications Package, 32 bytes

```matlab
@(n)t(sum(de2bi(t=' ':'~')')==n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999BI0@zRKO4NFcjJdUoKVOjxFZdQd1KvU5dU13T1jZP83@ahqEmV5qGEYgwBhFmmv8B)

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 94 bytes

```
: f ( n -- n s ) 94 [0,b] [ 32 + 2 >base [ 49 = ] count over = ] filter [ 32 + ] map >string ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LU7NDoIwGLv7FD1qFKJITITIxQPhQkiMJ8Jh4IZE3OY2THz6OX4u/dqmaT9GGiOUvd@yPI3woorTHm9inhP4kihN1cwV4S3VkIoa85Oq4waafgbKG@dq44xWI15leYSiuKY2AsMaHJ7nQGODc4hyv6srlDgG2CJAUhNNnQzPuKBCIwZXKr5ucZSs642jS7pyX0gk8xBie0J5mMseg4Q/IRuvEnIJj9T@AQ)

Comment: That is an impressive amount of necessary whitespace

Comment: @Unrelated String yes, it is :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 77 bytes

```hs
import Data.Char
b 0=0
b k=mod k 2+b(div k 2)
f n=[chr k|k<-[32..126],b k==n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzO3IL@oRMElsSRRzzkjsYgrScHA1gBIZtvm5qcoZCsYaSdppGSWgViaXGkKebbRyRlFCtk12Ta60cZGenqGRmaxOiDltnmx/3MTM/MUbBVyEwt84xUKSkuCS4p88hRUFNJsVOyiDfX0zGL/AwA)

Answer (score 2):

## C (GCC) - 134 Bytes

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int _,char**v){for(char c=32;c<127;c++)__builtin_popcount(c)-atoi(v[1])||putchar(c);}
```

Compile with `gcc chars.c -o chars`, and run the resulting program with the number of bits as the command-line argument.

Compiles with no warnings.

This program utilizes the [`__builtin_popcount`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) builtin that is present in GCC, which resolves to a `POPCNT` instruction on most x86 hardware built in the last dozen or so years.

Answer (score 2):

## Scala, <s>88</s> 87 bytes

```scala
(y:Int)=>32 to 126 map{x=>BigInt(x).bitCount->x}filter(_._1==y)map(_._2.toChar)mkString
```

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Scala, but are static calls possible like in Java? And if yes, can bytes be saved by changing `(y:Int)=>` to `(y:Integer)=>` and `Integer.bitCount(x)` to `y.bitCount(x)`?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Can't use `Integer` but I can cast the value to `BigInt` and use `bitCount` on that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [Z80Golf](https://github.com/lynn/z80golf), 25 bytes

```
00000000: cd03 806f 0e20 517d 45cb 3a9b 10fb de30 ...o. Q}E.:....0
00000010: 2002 79ff 0ce2 0600 76                   .y.....v
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zcy7DYQwFETRnCqmgqexjW0gpwBKwD8SJDIkVtrajVdLxo0mmfMZuB17qZVPE2KiwUBXwKwJq3xCb2OAWccAxRKQsiFE5BAs31mmNoXdH1CN0KSGH0sjYtagI@Ed3sn1u8pZq70B)

```
  call $8003    ; A = getchar(), e.g. '5'
  ld l, a       ; L = A
  ld c, ' '     ; C = ' '
next:           ; do {
  ld d, c       ;   D = C
  ld a, l       ;   A = L, e.g. '5'
  ld b, l       ;   B = L (way more than enough)
more:           ;   while (--B ≠ 0) {
  srl d         ;       shift D right, bit 0 goes into Carry
  sbc a, e      ;       A -= 0 + Carry
  djnz more     ;   }
done:
  sbc a, '0'    ;   A -= '0' + Carry
  jr nz, omit   ;   if A == 0:
  ld a, c       ;       putchar(C)
  rst $38
omit:
  inc c         ;   C++
  jp po, next   ; } until overflow, i.e. stop when C becomes 0x80 = -128
  halt
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 61 bytes

```hs
f n=[toEnum k|k<-[32..126],sum[k`div`2^i`mod`2|i<-[0..6]]==n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hzza6JN81rzRXIbsm20Y32thIT8/QyCxWp7g0Nzo7ISWzLMEoLjMhNz8lwagmE6jAQE/PLDbW1jYv9n9uYmaegq1CbmKBb7yCRkFpSXBJkU@eXpqmQrQhSNV/AA)

The type of `f` is `f :: (Enum t) => Int -> [t]`. That's more general than necessary, and it means  you need to e.g. `putStrLn` the result for Haskell to infer that you want a `[Char]` result.

I don't know what the rules say about that, but replacing `toEnum k` with `['\0'..]!!k` is a workaround costing 3 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 81 bytes

```forth
: f 127 32 do 0 i begin 2 /mod >r + r> ?dup 0= until over = if i emit then loop ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fc1NDoMgGIThvad447bRKvYnqZHepQWURIUQ7PXp5@LJbCYzLqS8NLM7o5QXjl49GRQm0OH52NnvKK5bMOjEhaR5myPSTRx79ivhZxMT3kndbj6TF7uzhhAZZTFytlvaGhpNLRffxFj1xEqJQdzEXTyI5Q8)

#### Code Explanation

```forth
: f           \ start a new word definition
  127 32      \ set up loop parameters
  do          \ loop from 32 to 126
    0 i       \ set up values for counting bits
    begin     \ start an indefinite loop
      2 /mod  \ divide by 2 and get quotient and remainder
      >r + r> \ add the remainder to the counter
      ?dup 0= \ check if quotient equals zero
    until     \ end the loop if it is
    over =    \ check if the result equals the input number
    if        \ if it is
      i emit  \ output the char for the current ascii value
    then      \ end the if
  loop        \ end the counted loop
;             \ end word definition
```

Answer (score 2):

## Perl 5 - 42+1

This is a modification of @Xcali solution, saving one character.  Perl's unpack has a built-in bit counting mechanism, no need for the mod-9 trick.

```
#!perl -a
map{$_=chr;unpack('%B*')-"@F"||say}32..126
```

Comment: Nice, you can save another byte reordering the body of the `map` too: https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z83saBaJd42OaPIWsnBTUm3NK8gMTlbXdVJSz2/SKE4sbLW2EhPz9DI7P9/43/5BSWZ@XnF/3V9TfUMDA3@6yYCAA

Answer (score 2):

## MS Excel, 76 bytes

An anonymous worksheet function that takes input from cell `A1` and outputs to the calling cell.

```vb
=Let(a,Row(32:126),Concat(If(Len(Substitute(Dec2Bin(a),0,))=A1,Char(a),"")))
```

[Try it Online](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AiH8VHSCOZ0DfqNyiK6KIgwfeeE?e=19oXWb)

### Explanation

```vb
=Let(...)                      ' begin variable definition block
   a,Row(32:126),              ' assign array `[32...126]` to variable `a`
         Dec2Bin(a)            ' convert `a` to binary 
       Substitute(~,0,)        ' for each binary element, remove all `0`s, leaving only `1`s
     If(Len(~)=A1,Char(a),"")  ' iff number of `1`s equals input, print that char 
   Concat(~)                   ' concat array and output
```

Comment: Seriously cool. I had no idea you could do that. I'm not an Excel  expert. My idea Was just posted as a bit of fun. Respect and +1

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
æqäí¼.ö
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=917184a1ac2e94&i=1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6&a=1&m=2)

Answer (score 2):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$10\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 8.231 bytes

```
Fcp'=#xSbC
```

[Try it online!](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyJGY3AnPSN4U2JDIiwiNCJd)

### Explained (old)

```
VR32 127Co0*v=Mv'Sb
VR32 127            # Put the range [32, 127) into the register
              Mv'   # to each item in that range:
                 Sb # get the sum of the on bits in the binary representation of the number
         o0*v=      # multiply the register by whether each item in the bit count list equals the input and remove 0s. This acts as a makeshift filter that can use global input. 
        C           # convert the remaining items to their ascii character equivalent
```

Answer (score 2):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 12 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
♣⌡╒T≥gæâΣk=$
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##AS4A0f9tYXRoZ29sZv//4pmj4oyh4pWSVOKJpWfDpsOizqNrPST//zEKMgozCjQKNQo2)

**Explanation:**

```python
♣             # Push 128
 ⌡            # Subtract 2: 126
  ╒           # Pop and push a list in the range [1,126]
   T≥         # Remove the first 31 items: range [32,126]
     g        # Filter this list of integers by,
      æ       # using 4 characters as inner code-block:
       â      #  Convert the integer to a binary-list
        Σ     #  Sum the bits together
         k    #  Push the input-integer
          =   #  Check if it's equal to the sum
           $  # Convert the remaining integers to characters with this codepoint
              # (after which the entire stack is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 8 bytes

```
kP'Cb∑?=
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwia1AnQ2LiiJE/PSIsIiIsIjFcbjJcbjNcbjRcbjVcbjYiXQ==)

#### Explained

```
kP'Cb∑?=
kP       # printable ACSI characters with no spaces in between them
  '      # lambda filter
   C     # char
    b    # binary
     ∑   # summate
      ?  # input
       = # equal?
```

Comment: I am clueless about how this works. Would you care to add a short explaination?

Comment: @ElPedro How bout now? I edited it to include the explanation - hope u understand :3

Answer (score 2):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
kcæCh2BS=
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faGm0kpdS7IKlpSVpuharspMPL3POMHIKtl1SnJRcDBVesNAUwgAA)

##### Explanation

```python
kcæCh2BS=  # Implicit input
kc         # Printable ASCII characters
  æ        # Filtered by:
   Ch      #  Their ordinal
     2B    #  Converted to binary
       S=  #  Has a sum equal to the input
           # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>124</s> 113 bytes

-11 bytes thanks to @ceilingcat

```cpp
#import<string>
auto a(int n){std::string f;for(int i=30,j,k;++i<127;f+=i*!j,j=n)for(k=i;k;k/=2)j-=k&1;return f;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVH7U9NAEP45@Su2QbFpE2kKFMzlqqgI@OAl@KJF4yUpl6SXmFwEreFPt2wSGKbOuHMzN/vt69tvWZqaE8bm8yU@TZNMOrnMuJgMVbeQCbhtLiQIfZZLz7abEAQkSLI6wOlqzwiNiHS73LH6GyToUt5phUZIhV4lRZSTiEQrtK@HJo2WLZL5ssgE9ihxomBx4fng8ARb@@50qKpV26nLRVuHmaqwCzfrQFLItJD52WAMtEIVDZ5pRvW3RtqDdm/r@cvdw28NsvRwWe8YVn9t88X2q73Xb4@OTz65372LtAk/6pqPV9cHT2xn5827/fenHz5/GY2YH/Aw/pHJqyZpZYPQ4cHHs/H5JJqKvPj56/efJvL0a3I5K68rpySqgitCIwQSswh@DoUBAZSjpq/UsjHkD44D2p7ANWxA0yqfw4IhUqf7wovRwWqlxrXtq9Rn0vfspuxODQ4mWON/y@C@bovJwo3tu3F4S/0/43AVhQe4CrSQf0N9kftCaqlW7/aSPaKW878siN1JPjcvbwA)

Iterates through the printable character codes, finds those that match the number of 1 bits desired, returns the string containing those characters concatenated.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why does `i` start at 30 instead of 31? It's currently looping in the range `(30,127)`, but shouldn't this be `(31,127)`?

Comment: You don't have to add the #include statements to your code length, [TIO](https://tio.run/##LY3LDoIwFETX9itqTIwIRMREF7f1X5rSkkuhkD7iwvDr1vpYzsyZGbksdS9l2uG0zC4wHxza/k52aOUYO0UZztlTYrqT6HNErZiUX4RU1IcO0q9AxQFtoLZ4/rUGPbuvh/zSVENloCyRndsbDDxjn9RwBANDzc3@XJkTbwvQJcfjdoDVqRCdzTNrIp@VSaA9FPRJNnKOgTKWH68FkM0fbICs6SX1KHqf6scb) 97 bytes

Comment: @KevinCruijssen: this relies on `j` being zero-initialized; the `j=n` condition is only run _after_ the first loop, so since `j` is 0 the first time around, the first loop does nothing. Hence the first value that is actually checked is 32.

Comment: @JohanduToit why don't I have to add the `#import` statement? Aren't imports considered part of the code (since they are necessary for it to function)?

Comment: @NeilA. sorry, you are correct. You can still save one byte by using a 'for' loop instead of the 'while'.

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (Client && NodeJs), 222 bytes

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##jc7BboJAEIDhe5/CmzOBTgTUJiaLaXyEHo2HBRbdFlmyiw1L47PTUXowbdJw20y@mX/f5ad0udVN@1ybQg2lGDqR7ono1VrpIYpfkD6Ud4AHcpXOFSQxklXFhZ8gwwJFCpKaizvBl9/cNgtqzVtrdX2EmLfOsgG@GXQY9ptxTqU1591J2h03ocArhhLD/QHvWM9EOgNN/iGTjRkfiCC7WU4t@Jym/oqIv2FGXohu@/OtjHpkPRaG3NTOVIoqc4QoLCH6sy0DcW/M54hPjzxmHk/nCfNkOl8yX07nK@ar6XzNfP0vH74B)

```
x=>[...Array(127).keys()].slice(32).reduce((a,d)=>(a.push({y:[...d.toString(2)].map(x=>+x),z:String.fromCharCode(d)}),a),[]).map(i => (i.y.reduce((a,b)=>(a.y+=+b,a),{y:0,z:i.z}))).reduce((a,b)=>(b.y==x?a.push(b.z):0,a),[])
```

Answer (score 1):

## T-SQL, 153 bytes

Query returns 1 row for each character.

```sql
DECLARE @ INT=6

SELECT char(number)FROM
spt_values,(values(1),(2),(4),(8),(16),(32),(64))x(x)WHERE
type='P'and number/32in(1,2,3)GROUP BY number
HAVING sum(number/x%2)=@
```

**[Try it online](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1037194/all-ascii-characters-with-a-given-bit-count)**

## 186 bytes

Putting all characters in same row:

```sql
DECLARE @ INT=6

SELECT string_agg(char(h),'')FROM(SELECT
iif(sum(number/x%2)=@,number,-1)h
FROM spt_values,(values(1),(2),(4),(8),(16),(32),(64))x(x)WHERE
type='P'and number/32in(1,2,3)GROUP BY number)c
```

**[Try it online](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1037180/all-ascii-characters-with-a-given-bit-count)**

Answer (score 1):

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Attache), 25 bytes

```
${{x=1~Bin[Ord@_]}\ascii}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SywpSUzOSP2fpmBl@1@lurrC1rDOKTMv2r8oxSE@tjYmsTg5M7P2v19qakpxtEpBQXJ6LFdAUWZeSUhqcYlzYnFqcXSajoKhlVnsfwA)

### Alternatives

**26 bytes:** `${{x=1~(Bin@Ord@_)}\ascii}`

**26 bytes:** `${{x=Sum@Bin@Ord@_}\ascii}`

**28 bytes:** `${Char!{x=Sum@Bin@_}\32:126}`

**28 bytes:** `ascii&${{y=Sum@Bin@Ord@_}\x}`

**34 bytes:** `ascii&{Mask[_2=Sum@Bin=>Ords@_,_]}`

**35 bytes:** `` ascii&{Mask[_2=1&`~@Bin=>Ords@_,_]} ``

### Explanation

```
${{x=1~Bin[Ord@_]}\ascii}
${                      }   lambda with named parameter `x` (for scoping)
  {              }\ascii    select all ascii characters...
     1~                       where the number of 1s
       Bin[Ord@_]             in the character's binary representation
   x=                         equals the parameter
```

Answer (score 1):

## 6502 Assembly (NES), 29 bytes

Outputs as tiles to the screen.

Machine code: (xx represents branch displacement bytes which I would probably get wrong assembling by hand)

```
A2 1F
E8
30 xx
86 01
A9 00
06 01
F0 xx
69 00
10 xx
69 00
C5 00
D0 xx
8E 07 20
D0 xx
60
```

Assembly:

```
; Output buffer address in $2006 PPU_ADDR. bits in address 0.
    ldx #31 ; initialize first printable character
@loop:
    inx
    bmi @done ; stop at 128 (127 won't match on input 1-6)
    stx 1 ; initialize address 1 with character
    lda #0
@bits:
    asl 1 ; load a bit into carry
    beq @next
    adc #0 ; add the carry to a
    bpl @bits ; branch always
@next:
    adc #0
    cmp 0
    bne @loop
    stx $2007
    bne @loop
@done:
    rts
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Clean](https://github.com/Ourous/curated-clean-linux), 65 bytes

```
import StdEnv
$n=[c\\c<-[32..127]|sum[(c>>p)rem 2\\p<-[0..6]]==n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY2xasMwFEVn6SseJmAbbGO7kECJPLVDIZtHSYMqK6nAehK2Uij026OqWzse7uEevRqFyfnlvhpwymKyLvgtwhyXV/ykB2RcC6HPLX8au24YT/J7vzte6WkK9WYcjEKEvPZdd5SSMZRpjmqLlDDglJAKGyieiyafB6iEAQZVCWUDpq5B@8UEbzHuWRLIJiizGf0cN4u3/3MpsKgpESKfIpxb4MNvssm4mvjHzYUDIFAi00NfV3XbU/t2SS9fqJzVGT7S0Pe9S@37Dw)

Defines `$ :: Int -> [Int]` giving a list of codepoints.

Answer (score 1):

## Rust - 112 bytes

```
fn a(i:u32)->String{std::str::from_utf8(&(0..128u8).filter(|x|x.count_ones()==i).collect::<Vec<u8>>()).unwrap()}
```

Going for worst reasonable answer. Rust does not allow simple conversions from ints to chars to strings.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 92 bytes

```
f=(b,c=32)=>c<127?(c.toString(2).match(/1/g).length-b?String.fromCharCode(c):"")+f(b,c+1):""
```

I like `Number.prototype.toString(n)`.

```
f=(b,c=32)=>                                                                                 //function declaration, starting at character code 32.
            c<127?                                                                           //check for out of range
                  (c.toString(2)                                                             //if the number in binary has
                                .match(/1/g).length                                          //number of 1 bits
                                                   -b?                                       //equal to b
                                                      String.fromCharCode(c):"")             //then add the character
                                                                                +f(b,c+1)    //next character

  :"" //base case for out of range(127)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 52 bytes

```
sn31[dP]sP[1+dd[2~rd0<B]dsBx[+z3<S]dsSxln=PC6>M]dsMx
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcwxC4MwEIbh3V/h7mJymkFsIXYOHDiGTJ5DQRx6KYQO/esxVzpk@75neGnLkPkE5QkDo1cdkdffF/XzEoiX5LsPzGuZazrOGz7M3ZXjUrZosfFx59jy@xn3KWCz2VKY2oBKkodLP9EiuhYQgVoGkaGWUWSsxYiYv@QL)

`sn` to store our target bit count from top-of-stack into register `n`. `31` starts us off at our first ASCII value (the main macro increments it immediately). `[dP]sP` is a printing macro, we call this when the bit count is equal to the target. Into our main macro, `M`... `1+dd` increments top-of-stack and duplicates it twice. `[2~rd0<B]dsBx` uses integer division by two w/ remainder to break a decimal value down into binary bits on the stack. `[+z3<S]dsSx` sums stack items until we're back to three values on the stack - our summation and two copies of our ASCII value. `ln=P` compares the summation with `n`, our target bit count, and runs the printing macro `P` if they're equal. `C6>M` keeps running `M` through ASCII value 126.

One thing to note that I sometimes forget about when golfing in `dc` is that there's no harm in burying macros `B` and `S` inside of `M` since they're *always* going to run at least once per run of `M`. This saves a byte in each case - `dsBx` instead of `sB` outside of macro `M` and then `lBx` inside.

Comment: Have never heard of dc before but it looks cool. +1 for the good explanation.

Comment: @ElPedro, it's a fun language to mess around with. Somewhat golfy in that commands are all a single character, but then you get into issues like conditionals only being able to run macros. So if you want to print if something ==0, you can't `0=p` but rather must make a macro that prints `[p]sp` and then call that. Stack movement is also very limited. A lot of little things working against you that makes it a fun challenge.

Answer (score 1):

## [Clam](https://github.com/dylanrenwick/Clam), 11 bytes

```
p#:\bcqQ'a-
```

Prints an array of characters

### Explanation

```
            - Implicit Q = first input
p           - Print...
        'a- - ASCII characters (dictionary access)
 #          - Where...
   \        - The sum of...
    b       - The binary bits of...
     cq     - The charcode of the character
  :         - Equals...
       Q    - Q
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 43 bytes

```julia
y->filter(x->count_ones(Int(x))==y,' ':'~')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcpBCsMgEADAc33FEgLuQoT2VgJ67ytC22iwyBqsAfeSr9vOeT5His9b68G@/Ba5i3EhpuoLNuPe@eC6ZPZffHDFRmStTBr0rE9N3fOqQi4gYOE639VlL5FrYhxGAeNgmPaSVwwoRKT@u/8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 52 bytes

```arturo
$->x[to[:char]select 32..127=>[x=∑digits.base:2&]]
```

[Try it!](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?81lHFN)

Outputs a list of characters, which seems to be allowed.