# pleTriwapt Sgpin (Triplet Swapping)

Tags: code-golf, string

### Intro/Background

I was looking at a Flybuys card at Coles recently and noticed that if I took something like this:

[image: Flybuys]
[Source, randomly found on the Internet](http://moneyoff.com.au/images/fly-buys4.jpg)

And swapped some words around, I'd get this:

[image: Buyflys]

After I finished laughing (don't judge my sense of humour please),  I said to myself: "I need a program that can generate text like that". So I devised a set of rules for substring swapping and wrote yet another CGCC challenge!

### The Challenge

Given a single string as input, output a string with its substrings swapped. This can be done by:

- Splitting the string into chunks of three. The last triplet can possibly be shorter. (`abcdefgh => [abc, def, gh]`)
- Swap every triplet with every other triplet, leaving the last triplet in place if there is an odd amount of triplets.

The above bullet point more succinctly:

> [D]ivide the list into adjacent pairs and swap each pair ~ @FlipTack

### Test Cases

```
Input->Output 
flybuys->buyflys
Once->eOnc
Triplet->pleTrit
Code Golf->e GCodolf
TopAnswers!->AnsTops!wer
Never gonna let you down->er Nevna gon yoletownu d
I'm Sorry, I Haven't a Clue-> SoI'm, Irryven Haa C't lue
Can I please have my vegetables back?-> I Canasepleve  havegmy bleetaacks b?
You are filled with determination-> arYouille fwited eteh dnatrmiion
->
```

[Reference Program](https://tio.run/##bVKxboMwEJ3DV1xZAgqNmmaLFFVVhjZLM6RLFTE4cAa3xkbGBPH19GySCkX1Yt97T@/dHdS9LbVaD0OOHHjU6NZkGG@CmTWilmgb2MIppRKrmp5hGMy4NpCVzIBQMOpJDnQEB4kqctIYtltYX3F3bnZLVteo8lE0oUd7ZzuCKBvc3PGLmyCYUZSDror/zcdOhWvTMFVg9JSM/V3VMTzCKoHn@M7lJNJkUsACVin1dodMJSllGbStUbSg5bcWk5BgyFiDfo0hl/257ZswgfCgMnT356hzz53OEd605B7X9atqOjTNgys/8IIGCq0Uoxks9LqFXHfKcft5BUdtTJ/AHt7ZBdXcAoOdbH3CjinCKYTagJJoqHq4YIGWnSU1dmbZz4sTfpEnMwhcSIk5dMKWkKNFUwnFrNA@LKRZA/8HODtarZ@ONlgboWwUHowoSC43IW3JcfEfdezc58k9wyPPxcMv)

### Some Test Cases Explained

```
flybuys
[fly, buy, s] (split)
[buy, fly, s] (swapped)
buyflys

Once
[Onc, e] (split)
[e, Onc] (swapped)
eOnc

Triplet
[Tri, ple, t] (split)
[ple, Tri, t](swapped)
pleTrit

Code Golf
[Cod, e G, olf] (split)
[e G, Cod, olf] (swapped)
e GCodolf

TopAnswers!
[Top, Ans, wer, s!] (split)
[Ans, Top, s!, wer] (swapped)
AnsTops!wer
```

### Rules

- Input/output can be taken/given in any reasonable and convenient format
- The input will not contain newlines
- Strings can be of any length, and can be empty
- Input will only contain printable ASCII characters
- All standard loopholes are forbidden

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the answer with the lowest bytes wins

Comment: Maybe this could use some better wording - how about "divide the list into adjacent pairs and swap each pair"?

Comment: No, the output for `Input` should be `putIn`.

Comment: @S.S.Anne I assume you mean output for `Input` should be `utInp` per the [Reference Program](https://tio.run/##bZAxb4MwEIVn@BVXT1ihUdNsSAxVh6pThnaLGCicE1eubdlGEb@enjGpEKoX7Pc@vXucHcPV6OM09ShAFN4MrkNe5Vlw0ioMHmo4N/TEH0tXxvJMGAfdtXUgNSSecKAjBSjURUQ51DUcFz2ee9y@tRZ1n6CVneJjbBJReaw2/u4O5BmNitJC/B@emspY07X6gsVTmfotNIdHOJTwzDcpZ9mUqwfs4NBQt42yRhqa5TAMTtOC9t9GrobkU9d6nNfI3rUdAiuZUOPXMHpWAjvpDuP3M/Hx@mp6hDejxKwb@6L9DZ1/YDQmn5dPgfGv5mAqb53UoWAnJy9St6piVDB6/M/6uMXN9LMjitnj0y8).  Though I get you were saying that humorously. :)

Answer (score 8):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 13 bytes

```
[:;_2|.\_3<\]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Pc9RS8MwFAXg9/2KM1@CsA3Rt6oMKagDUdC9iBsjW2@3apaMJN0o@N/rqSx9KNye8@WGfLcXE1XiPoPCCFfI@I0nyN9fHtuv7HZ1/TtZrG7uFsv2cjCQzc5BreumNE1QGGcooTgzCercypvdpIqjpPxgZO6rmCrOTGJ/Ck@5K5wpU88/Zl1wFg82zN0hDE/i@x3uwJRBGPZ7PF7laDW2zqJxvMGdbI0iHWFJwpKEJQlLknQeH26m1H6EmffNUSyetUauVISpJS3pBCEFHQVdJwg7lDbNkGurg/CZRwF2ZNt9g7URiVpvfgLW0/612tJT0v9LUNJT0lPST/vN2n@6ujJGUJ6qKAUkyg6F1dHvq8rZtJWKlqqzBWipaKloO9j@AQ)

Example input: 'flybuys'

- `_3<\]` Box every group of 3

  ```
  ┌───┬───┬─┐
  │fly│buy│s│
  └───┴───┴─┘
  ```
- `_2|.` Split *that* into groups of 2, and reverse each one:

  ```
  ┌───┬───┐
  │buy│fly│
  ├───┼───┤
  │s  │   │
  └───┴───┘
  ```
- `[:;` Raze the result:

  ```
  buyflys
  ```

Answer (score 7):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 24 bytes

```perl6
{S:g/(...)(..?.?)/$1$0/}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HZCxbsIwEIZ3P8WPhAhIJMDSoVIdVQyUpR1gqaoOhlyCVWNHtgFFVZ@d/u1yvrvvO@vsXqJ7uJ8HTFo83b93j91iWlXVjKGu6tlivBovFz/3ZAZUH8vPatLOUcAmFHM2Vp9oQ4SzXpLWVeqdzdOi1MXs3rrhcBlSqRmZJ/Xmj1Jq4aH20fZOcqkZmWe1Do1gE1xLARtWTNU@9M8@3SSmUamZsU4jlupVrhLRBe8NeA2GcEETbp7DEYRsE7JNyDah2hZn7EKMwxxbvJir@CLDYO0u3ImEnISchJyEnFCtjecE9zRJcOIg@FdX6SSbg5OEgzl@1bxiC5p0aNL5NzuadGjSoVmrdy5qoqC1zkmDm80nNJIlnq032Qa@gJzWH0dLToucFjktKqrUvw)

Simple regex substitution that swaps every pair of three and up to three.

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
s3ṭ2/
```

A full program accepting a string which prints the result.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/7/Y@OHOtUb6////j8wvVUgsSlVIy8zJSU1RKM8syVBISS1JLcrNzEssyczPAwA)**

#### How?

```
s3ṭ2/ - Main Link: list of characters
s3    - split into threes
   2/ - 2-wise reduce with:
  ṭ   -   tack
      - implicit, smashing print
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Gema](http://gema.sourceforge.net/), 13 characters

```
<u3><u3>=$2$1
```

Sample run:

```
bash-5.0$ echo -n 'flybuys' | gema '<u3><u3>=$2$1'
buyflys
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/NTfz/36bU2A6EbVWMVAz//0/LqUwqrSwGAA) / [Try all test cases online!](https://tio.run/##lZFNb9NAEIbP2V8xsUy3lYgChVtrSlWhkguVgAtKLbSxx4lVZ9faXSdYhd8e3tlIhQMcevDOx/vM7Mx6ZcLmUHPVGc80u6bIIX6vTODiVE2WuunG1TAGXRYaFlHQkr6zFUuO4aTEV9/2HUfJwSKKKX3jaqZb1zUJplvEEqQK11/bsGcfpiLCRyZMkUjyJ96xp7Wz1hAa0@gGqt3epkaeIEOADAEyBMhSmC30lr4478eXtKCPZsdWRzJ00w2clUUGDQQ0ENBAQAMhcprYWNRhBzwBbVBO25F2vOZoVh0HWpnq4UqGAAUWFFhQiV2DBQUWFNirtMo3jC6v27RdxzXt27ihmiP7bWtNbF3aCQQ4IagBAQ4EOBDgBFJnSvW@tbEh/ZNezN6@CvQPe47z3mrSC9sPEfYzh6ET58OPnit0hnv3oJVqnKdWIJyU5Y/Tp3@/fF/@yi7w3mriU3WR5afE1cbRTNBUleG2uevjfM1bMw@@Sg7pw@Xw5p18RX6evz5oOsuUmjxj8qf@WX68XbzHP8MdZUxIMtVy@RdXFP9Dy5JOTo4ryPYyVO0sH34D)

Comment: I immediately thought of Gema when I saw this challenge and was wondering if you'd reply.  It's as elegant as I thought it would be.

Answer (score 5):

## Brainfuck, <s>37</s> 33 bytes

```
,[>,>,>>,>,>,<<[.>]<[<]<<<[.>]>,]
```

-4 bytes thanks to @JoKing

You can [try it online](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fJ9pOBwjBhI6NTbSeXaxNtE2sDYRppxP7/39IUWZBTmqJQnB5YkFBZl46AA)

Cell layout is `|a|b|c|0|d|e|f|`, I read unconditionally and then print what is there to be printed.

Probably still golfable...

Answer (score 5):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 17 bytes<sup>SBCS</sup>

```apl
⍬∘(⍋⍋-6×3≤6|⍋)⊃¨⊂
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkG/x/1rnnUMUPjUW83EOmaHZ5u/KhziVkNkKP5qKv50IpHXU3/04AqH/X2QTQBBdcbP2qbCOQFBzkDyRAPz@D/aQrqIUWZBTmpJQrB5YkFBZl56epcQMG0nMqk0spidQA)

Uses `⎕IO←0`, i.e. 0-based indexing.

#### How it works

Uses [`⍬⍋` generating index](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155586/78410) trick, though [simply using `⍳≢` gives the same byte count here](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qn/6O2CQb/04CkxqPe7ke9m3XNDk83ftS5xKwGyNF81DHjUeeiR13Nh1Y86mr6/z9NQT2kKLMgJ7VEIbg8saAgMy9dnQsomJZTmVRaWawOAA) (thanks @ngn for pointing this out).

```apl
⍬∘(⍋⍋-6×3≤6|⍋)⊃¨⊂
⍬∘( ⍋-6×3≤6|⍋)     ⍝ Generate some numbers to apply "sortBy" on the input
⍬∘          ⍋        ⍝ Generate 0-based indexes
          6|         ⍝ Modulo 6
        3≤           ⍝ 1 if 3≤x is true, 0 otherwise
      6×             ⍝ 6 times
⍬∘  ⍋-               ⍝ Subtract from the original 0-based indexes;
                     ⍝ the result looks like 0 1 2 ¯3 ¯2 ¯1 6 7 8 3 4 5 12 13 ..
   ⍋          ⊃¨⊂  ⍝ "sortBy"; sort the input in the increasing order of above
```

Answer (score 4):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <del>60</del> 57 bytes

```php
for($a=str_split($argn,3);$b=$a[$i++|0];)echo$a[$i++],$b;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLNFQSbYtLiuKLC3IyS4CcovQ8HWNNa5UkW5XEaJVMbe0ag1hrzdTkjHwoP1ZHJcn6//@0nMqk0srif/kFJZn5ecX/dd0A)

Answer (score 3):

## [W](https://github.com/A-ee/w), 5 bytes

```
"jC?┐
```

Uncompressed

```
3,2,_r
```

## Explained

```
3,%Split the input into chunks of three
2,%Group the inputs into chunks of two
_r%Reverse every two-chunk of the input
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
s3s2Ṛ€
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/7/YuNjo4c5Zj5rW/P//P6QosyAntUQhuDyxoCAzLx0A)

A full program taking a string and implicitly printing the rearranged string. This could be turned into a monadic link that returns a Jelly string by adding `F` (flatten) to the end.

### Explanation

```
s3     | Split into sublists length 2
  s2   | Split into sublists length 2
    Ṛ€ | Reverse each
```

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 36 bytes

```javascript
x=>x.replace(/(...)(..?.?)/g,"$2$1")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PZHBbsIwDIbveQqDkGglWsauqEUTB8ZlO4zLhJBqilu6haRKQqFPz37YtEvi@Puc2s0Xd@xL17QhMfYgtyq7XbP8mjppNZcSTaM0TWMsi3QRT@vJcPQ8mg3jW8eOSvbiKaOi0v3@3Pskx4rYq3dTSpILNrXB3VpCkmNFHNQSn6GV1RUEWuGEUG1s@2L8RZwfJDkinP0AR/UmnTiqrTFMuIZ6e6aDvRgUOwJEGhBpQKQB1Xp8og/rXD@hNb1yJ2YciGmpz@gJBBwEHAQcBBxQLdmgAn1iLjqikE49dVJL4L3GpHsuvxe4Yk0w4cCE8zBrmHBgwoG5UJ9olJ1Q1WgtB7o04UgHCeJOjeHQWEwADuvOqQKHBQ4LHBYUleRF6lvdhEIV6Ynb6EpZTte/HGg8V5V1FN2fg8lWv28SKyqt8fgnqbZ1xNun3YSqxx7/B5RlxNvZLp7ffgA)

Simple regex substitution.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
3ô2ôíS
```

Outputs as a list of characters.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f@PAWo8NbDq8N/v8/JL/AMa@4PLWoWBEA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##FY0xTsNAEEWv8tkmILkiB7CQkSAUpAgNQhTjeJysWO9Eu2tb21FxAGquQJeewjfJRcy4mj//f70vkWrL85BLg8vXN0yZ5/V0vp3O0@9uvi@fLp8/uDbTn7lRVcxvpnW57nM0hdn6Pet5CfbkOKmqpGE8iGsXV053Po4c4pV@zzxwwEG8J2gXWXo0MnqNNqsOOwkhF9jgkQb2qwRC5foFXpFXW/kUGUdN0WUMfOBEteOImvYfpfZeFUiB0VrnuMFo0xENJw6d9ZSsLEvm/R8).

**Explanation:**

```python
3ô      # Split the (implicit) input-string into parts of size 3
  2ô    # Split this list into parts of size 2
    í   # Reverse each inner pair of triplets
     S  # Convert it to a flattened list of characters
        # (after which this is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 62 bytes

```
: f ( s -- s ) 3 group 2 group [ reverse concat ] map concat ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NZAxT8MwEIX3/opHl4JEGGBLB1RlKFnCEBgQYrgml9TCsY3jJIoQvz1cVceD7ed3fp99DVXB@uW9zItjitbbwSnTouefgU3FPZznEGbnlQnYb/IixZtXTnNIyoncpXhJ0eAWPZJEpjs8XWPwGNdPeB7Z94zKmooCvtCRW8V@@d1AxrbR82mY@@1VvQo8biMvqszWjKPVzepadzD9JPk38aS40NBaYwhyD7MdUNvJRDvfdSit9/M9crzQyGYXQMj0sAIzMmIJk@TNZ6lAN2PklgOdtLTkRNX3c6z9kHDyjEZpzTUmFc6oObDvlKGgrFD/pANN/PTD8g8)

[Factor](https://factorcode.org/) defies golfing :)

Answer (score 2):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 10 bytes

```
3/2/{-1%}%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/31jfSL9a11C1VvX//7ScyqTSymIA)

## Explanation

```
3/         # Split the input into chunks of three
  2/       # Group the inputs into chunks of two
    {-1%}% # Reverse every two-chunk of the input
           # This deals with the last two-chunk, in which
           # no reversing is done
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 10 bytes

```
⭆⪪Ｓ⁶⪫⮌⪪ι³ω
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYpBCsJADEX3niLLCdSV4KYnUBDEniC0qQ3EmSGmLZ4@Duji8@C9Py5kYyGNuJtkT4M3PG9U01BVPF1yXf0nE3ZwbrsWyenBG9ub/y/p4IQt7YjYR3zKCmQMs6jyBLv4AhM720syuZR8iOOmXw) Link is to verbose version of code. Splitting into groups of 6 and splitting those works out shorter because it keeps the two numbers separate. Explanation:

```
  Ｓ         Input string
 ⪪ ⁶        Split into substrings of 6 characters
⭆           Map over substrings and join
       ι    Current substring
      ⪪ ³   Split into substrings of 3 characters
     ⮌      Reverse the substrings
    ⪫    ω  Join together
            Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <del>50</del> 42 bytes

```hs
s(a:b:c:d)=take 3d++a:b:c:s(drop 3d)
s x=x
```

-8 bytes thanks to [Post Rock Garf Hunter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56656/post-rock-garf-hunter).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RVDBbsIwDL3nK94qJECFXXZDotPUaRvSNA7sMm3T5BIXItKkSlJov74L7YGTn/1sv2cfyZ9Y615VtXUBzxTo/sVqSYVmzErr/uZCBPYhJ88ea3wLJKXuiqbzySLirdnzAD6dqjWHAedWMl6tLkfG1k/GX9j5uyH/4DM7HKwxhDiBzjaQ9mIGcjOtsLPOdQts8EZnNtMAQq6bUSYnE4moFP3gGHlUHc584HC17FHQ/vQ4dH7FteQYpdKaJS4qHCE5sKuUoaDsqJf8ClGRMvE0aQXqJuyCezfRiIl4mW2bEGMicP0Fbp@Y4KfFMrsNTNAiTZEss@QaPdrez2hVrPYrOV8HOjEeZJqOFT@TztaxMBexcd32/T8)

Comment: [lambdas are rarely a good idea, yours costs you 3 bytes](https://tio.run/##RZBBT8JAEIXv@yueDQmQUi/eiGBIjUpi5KAXo8Zs2Sls2O42u1Ogif@9Lu2B07zNN7PvzexlOJAxna5q5xmPkuXtkzNKFoYwKZ3/nQrBFDiXgQIW@BJIStMWTRuSWdQbu6VefHhdG@Je504Rnp0pB@LqlQ0n8uGmf7/RkTx2zlqJOIHWNVDuZHu4Hld4d963M6zxIo9kxwyJ3DSDTS5tBNEp5sE@clQtjrQjvkQOKOT28NB3fsZvpSeU2hhSOGneQxGTr7SVrN3gl/wIUUlt42rKCdQNv7N/tTGIjTpbbhqONRG43ALXS4zwfUa2vA6McEaaIsmWyaUGnLswkfNivp2r6d@EZuX0Pgu10bxi3KkFpelAA0oRuxfnrvsH "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: [In fact the whole split binding costs you](https://tio.run/##RVDBbsIwDL3nK94qJECFXXZDotPUaRvSNA7sMm3T5BIXItKkSlJov74L7YGTn/1sv2cfyZ9Y615VtXUBzxTo/sVqSYVmzErr/uZCBPYhJ88ea3wLJKXuiqbzySLirdnzAD6dqjWHAedWMl6tLkfG1k/GX9j5uyH/4DM7HKwxhDiBzjaQ9mIGcjOtsLPOdQts8EZnNtMAQq6bUSYnE4moFP3gGHlUHc584HC17FHQ/vQ4dH7FteQYpdKaJS4qHCE5sKuUoaDsqJf8ClGRMvE0aQXqJuyCezfRiIl4mW2bEGMicP0Fbp@Y4KfFMrsNTNAiTZEss@QaPdrez2hVrPYrOV8HOjEeZJqOFT@TztaxMBexcd32/T8 "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: @PostRockGarfHunter Ah, I was comparing the lambda to `let` or `where`. I wasn't even thinking about pattern guards. (And I would have never guessed using `take` and `drop` separately would be shorter.) Nice catches!

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://bitbucket.org/ngn/k), 15 bytes

```
,//|'0N 2#0N 3#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY/LTsMwEEX3fMU0RQpIRUWwSxYV6qJ0UxawQVWkOs04jeLYle0@LB6/Hq7xxvbcc2Y07h90q8dRFrP5/Dt/3NDTFMfzdPTF1@02/NpC0rXcmb6820nRqfJahtLeVz83fptJFepTcFmZ4ULhsirGb3rPyBh3Cj5sd1TskeFC4VO8NA3TyigZZVqhjO/UYY4v2l3YugkgngjcBHXCGz6zpdZoLQiDKZgTNeai4yBLoMhBkYMiB02N63ygd2NtmNGaXsWZde5J0FKd4sZAEIAgAEEAghBp2lho9OETwjEd0E5DoDO37EWt2FEt9v0iDloTVEhQIf2rLVRIUCFBXaSRn1hdWCbZKcUNXTp/oIY926HTwncm/gkCtCiQhAANAjQI0KJTjX8)

`0N 3#` chunks of 3; last may be shorter

`0N 2#` pairs of chunks; last may be a singleton list

`|'` reverse each

`,//` flatten

Answer (score 2):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 13 bytes

```
3co2co)<-FL\[
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/f/fODnfKDlf00bXzScm@v9/T/VcheD8oqJKHQVPBY/EstQ89RKFRAXnnNJUAA)

```
3co # Chunks of 3
2co # Chunks of 2
)<- # Map - Reverse
FL  # Flatten
\[  # Concatenate
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-P`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 7 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
ò3 ò cw
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVA&code=8jMg8iBjdw&input=IkNvZGUgR29sZiI)

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 153 bytes

```php
$c=($h='array_chunk')($h(str_split($argn),3),2);foreach($c as&$i)count($i)-1&&[$i[0],$i[1]]=[$i[1],$i[0]];echo implode(($m='array_merge')(...$m(...$c)));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY3BS8MwGMXv@Ss@R1gb6IbTYx1DBuouenAXmWWk6dcmLE1Ckm70n7fGgpf34L3H7znppqedkw4mKrY5lduMe8/Hs5CDuWQsJXmI/hycVjGn3HeGFY@seGBlaz1yIXMqgIclVUzYwaSNYqvNcnmi6nRfFUk3VbU9zV7MWVWikBZU77RtMM9p///Zo@8wfa7Xa9rPKhhj5TTvF99mUU6tHuthDOTDCCRHr5zGSPaJA69Wt@Ro3bMJN/ThjrzjFT101hgOaQWjHaCxN0MOWQ@f1vuxgAO88SuaLAKHvR6Q7LlJYaLygCBTB/0IV@ww8lpjgJqLy458JRT3CK3SGhu4qSihwYi@V4ZHZc2PdX8WptXLLw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 43 bytes

```lua
print(((...):gsub('(...)(.?.?.?)','%2%1')))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RZJBi9swEIXPq18xSzGSwQ5sj4E4lFC2ubSFbg/Fm1LFHjtmZSlIcrb59emzsptisEfzvnmSR2MmfTGu0YY6WpFxuq3ry9EPNiqlFotFvuzDtFcyxWqxnp9cFjL7mD3IPM8vu50QVwPP2nyfKwuEYTIRhslJiPTBsptsEwdnk5u40yGwjyqw4SYq@UEWNAu0WtFDQfJnGGxPo2teuL060esQD8h4pnjQlpxl0r6fRrZRwvC2L2wE2/b9aJFDDEjXtejMeT@dQ1nhjTiIb7bhsmJ8xJMfjoZjWeGNOIqNa5kenekA0CNWCMWTO36y4ZV9uC8rRFiHeyzFVz6xp95Zqwk2dHYTte7VotgTRKQhIg0RaYhiK0f64bw/F7SlL/rEVkbStDETzgQFOhToUKBDgQ5RbPD3W8I5dWA6oJDGM52456j3hgPtdfOyhsWWQIIBCSaRPUgwIMGAXItfOKhGT7vBGLQ6NbnlyH4crJ7vC0bag5p16qCDgg4KOiggoqzEPAud8zTYY0FuigiurV/2o47NAWNU/362Wbkr86ys0gLhs5U5GiXuOoXK/3Pxfpur2asgVdefvXd@SX@yIIn/HjE13BZoakyp3S5fYntspVLBtT5Pc/E2mkrJDHcP@Iamw95QDM3l8jYH/wA)

Take input as argument, print result to stdout. TIO link include program that check all testcases given in question. Uses Lua patterns to capture three and up to three characters, then swap those groups.

Answer (score 1):

## [naz](https://github.com/sporeball/naz), <s>210</s> 190 bytes

```
2a2x1v1x1f1r3x1v2e2x2v1r3x1v3e2x3v1r3x1v4e2x4v1r3x1v5e2x5v1r3x1v6e2x6v1r3x1v7e2x7v5v1o6v1o7v1o2v1o3v1o4v1o1f0x1x2f0a0x1x3f2v1o0x1x4f2v1o3v1o0x1x5f2v1o3v1o4v1o0x1x6f5v1o5f0x1x7f5v1o6v1o5f0x1f
```

I finally fixed the bug in the linked implementation that made solving challenges like this one impossible!

The main part of this program uses a *ton* of conditional instructions to properly split strings of any length, so I've split it onto multiple lines in the below explanation to aid readability.

Works for any input string terminated with the control character STX (U+0002).

Edit: Saved 20 bytes by calling function 5 directly from functions 6 and 7 instead of repeating its logic verbatim.

**Explanation** (with `0x` commands removed)

```
2a2x1v                       # Set variable 1 equal to 2
1x1f1r3x1v2e2x2v             # Function 1
                             # Read a byte of input
                             # Jump to function 2 if it equals variable 1
                             # Otherwise, store it in variable 2
  1r3x1v3e2x3v               # This pattern continues for the next 5 bytes of input
  1r3x1v4e2x4v               # ...
  1r3x1v5e2x5v               # ...
  1r3x1v6e2x6v               # ...
  1r3x1v7e2x7v               # ...
  5v1o6v1o7v1o2v1o3v1o4v1o   # Output variables 5, 6, and 7, then variables 2, 3, and 4
                          1f # Then, jump back to the start of the function
1x2f0a                       # Function 2
                             # Add 0 to the register
1x3f2v1o                     # Function 3
                             # Output variable 2
1x4f2v1o3v1o                 # Function 4
                             # Output variables 2 and 3
1x5f2v1o3v1o4v1o             # Function 5
                             # Output variables 2, 3, and 4
1x6f5v1o5f                   # Function 6
                             # Output variable 5, then variables 2, 3, and 4
1x7f5v1o6v1o5f               # Function 7
                             # Output variables 5 and 6, then variables 2, 3, and 4
1f                           # Call function 1
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 21 bytes

```perl
s/(...)(..?.?)/$2$1/g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYxBS8QwFITv@RUjLKwL2qLguUgPuhc9uBePr9vXbjB9LyRpS/68MV5mYL7h8xzcSymxvW@a5lSja7pTe3g@PLVzKZPLw5qj@ZQrm0uw3nEyvY6MN3WTuah/lbhziHfmgzcOmFWEUF/IumLUXcz5uOBLQ8gPOOOdNpZjAqF3K5uepI7VSpFxqwxLxsYzJxocRwx0/enMd1VRYEzWOR6x23TDyInDYoWSVflV/1@xPPo/)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <del>67 77 75</del> 63 bytes

<del>`s` is the variable holding the string to manipulate.</del>

```python
''.join(sum([(s[k+3:k+6],s[k:k+3]) for k in range(0,len(s),6)],()))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NZLBaoNAEIbP@hRTLyqRUgj0EAih9NDm0h7SSwmhbHQ02@iu7K5JJLSvnv4r3ZM7830zOs72oztoNb9VXFPZfNWDymy@uEWG3WAUpen9t5bIDV22zez2OJsvjrPHXUE44zTf5VRrQ0eSioxQDWcPRcu@SfGYQ8vyPL/Fjq2ztKRtHEVZUrfjfhhtUlCCJyKb5MVE3lXJPs04hNyHkX3LzqfxROQCedYV04tu66mEXhD7INTp/knZMxt75znOyNg7JILxxic21GilBOENNOqBKn1WUztDwADAAMAAwKF2nXa00caMBa3pVZxYpY4EPbfDNMBGQwCCAAQBCIKn4eOFQiUmEpbpgAbUjXTihp3Yt2xpL8rjyrdaE1RIUCFNagMVElRIUFeh6ScmEIaplm3LFZ2lO1DFjk0nlXBST6MJA80LVEOABgEaBGjeyeNdHPut@rX5xU7rW8TRpaARW/RhHPVGKpcl6ZUvPZfo85PSL6VXwyXLkw@TezTphMuCscTfCnj5f9suuCDx7Q8)

**Edit**:
77 bytes to respect the rules of Code Golf

```python
f=lambda s:''.join(sum([(s[k+3:k+6],s[k:k+3])for k in range(0,len(s),6)],()))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NZI9a8MwEIbn@FdcvVgmphQCHQKhlAxtlnZIlxIyKPY5USNLRlI@TGj/evrKoEl39zw6@3zuh3CwZna/twstu10jyc@L4vHHKiP8qRMb4TfH6Wx@nD5vK4QIZtuytY6OpAw5afYsnirN0MvqudxWoizLexbYB08L2mSTichbPexOg88rynEi83lZjeTT1BzLjCDVvpzqNYdYxoksJLK0DdOb1e14hd6QxyTds/2r8Rd2/iFyxKj4BxSS8cFndrS3xkjCE2iwJ2rsxYztHAEDAAMAAwCnu6uio7V1bqhoRe/yzKYIJGmpT@MAawsBCAIQBCAIkaaXlwY3MZH0TAc0oG6gM@85yJ1mTztZH19iqxVBhQQV0qjuoUKCCgnqS2r6jQmkY2qV1tzQRYUDNRzYdcrIoOw4mnTQokAtBGgQoEGAFp0y22ZZXGpcW9zruL55NrlWNGCLMc0mvVMmiLy48bXnGn1@C/qj4ua4ZnWOaf6IJp0MIhkLfK2EF6244t/I7v8)

**Edit 2**: Dropped the `f=`

```python
lambda s:''.join(sum([(s[k+3:k+6],s[k:k+3])for k in range(0,len(s),6)],()))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NZI9b8IwEIZn8iuuWeKIqKqExICEUMXQsrRDu1SUwZALuDh2ZJuPCLV/nb6O5Ml39zy@5HLp@nCwZnJv5t93LdttLcnPiuLxxyoj/KkVa@HXx/FkdhxPNxVCBJNN2VhHR1KGnDR7Fk@VZuhlNS03lSjL8p4F9sHTnNbZaCTyRvfbU@/zinKcyHxeVgN5NzuOZUaQap9OdZpDLONEFhJZ2prpxepmuEIvyGOS7tnu2fgLO/8QOWJU/AMKyXjjMzvaW2Mk4QnU2xPV9mKGdo6AAYABgAGA091V0dKHda6vaEWv8symCCRpqU/DAB8WAhAEIAhAECJNLy8NbmIi6ZkOaEBtT2fec5BbzZ62cndcxFYrggoJKqRB3UOFBBUS1EVq@oUJpGNqlNZc00WFA9Uc2LXKyKDsMJp00KJADQRoEKBBgBadMttkWVxqXFvc67C@WTa6VtRjizHNRp1TJoi8uPG14x36/Bb0R8XN8Y7VOab5I5q0MohkzPG1Ep434op/I7v/Aw)

**Edit 3**: [Post Rock Garf Hunter](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56656/post-rock-garf-hunter) made this version which gets rid of the `sum(...,())` call, bringing the byte count down to 63!

```python
lambda s:''.join(s[k+3:k+6]+s[k:k+3]for k in range(0,len(s),6))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NZFNb8IwDIbP9FeYXtqKCk1C2gEJoYkD47Id2GVCHELrQkaaVEn4qND219mbSjnV9vPYreuu9yejZ89ns1CiPdSC3DzLpj9G6tztzpPZ/Dx53U8QIpjtG2PpTFKTFfrI@UupGF5RvhbFM/HsvKMF7ZLRKE8b1R8uvUtLSvFE5tKiHMinrjiUGUGsfVnZKfahjCcyH8nK1Exro5qhhdbIQxL7TPem3Y2tGweOGBU3RiEaH3xlS0ejtSC8gXpzodrc9DDOEjAAMAAwAHDs3WQtbY21fUkbehdX1pknQSt1GRbYGghAEIAgAEEINH680OjERsIxnTCA2p6ufGQvDoodHUR1XoZRG4IKCSqkQT1ChQQVEtRlHPqNDYRlaqRSXNNN@hPV7Nm2UgsvzbCasNCCQA0EaBCgQYAWnCLZJ0m4ZzhbOOlwvnkyupfU44ohTUadldrnafbge8cV5vxm9EfZw3LF8hrSdIohrfB5NBb4WxEvmvxeFEXy/Ac)

Comment: Welcome to the site.  We don't do input from variables here for a number of reasons.  You should rewrite your submission to either define a function or be a complete program.

Comment: You can read about how we do input on [this post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods).  Prepending your answer with `lambda s:` will make it valid, but will cost you

Comment: Thank you! I modified the entry accordingly. I added a `f=` so that it is callable. From my understanding prepending `lambda s:` creates an anonymous lambda which would need to be called right away?

Comment: Ok, thanks! I wonder if the `range(0,len(s),6)` could be shortened.

Comment: I don't think you can, but the rest can be [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NZFNb8IwDIbP9FeYXtqKCk1C2gEJoYkD47Id2GVCHELrQkaaVEn4qND219mbSjnV9vPYreuu9yejZ89ns1CiPdSC3DzLpj9G6tztzpPZ/Dx53U8QIpjtG2PpTFKTFfrI@UupGF5RvhbFM/HsvKMF7ZLRKE8b1R8uvUtLSvFE5tKiHMinrjiUGUGsfVnZKfahjCcyH8nK1Exro5qhhdbIQxL7TPem3Y2tGweOGBU3RiEaH3xlS0ejtSC8gXpzodrc9DDOEjAAMAAwAHDs3WQtbY21fUkbehdX1pknQSt1GRbYGghAEIAgAEEINH680OjERsIxnTCA2p6ufGQvDoodHUR1XoZRG4IKCSqkQT1ChQQVEtRlHPqNDYRlaqRSXNNN@hPV7Nm2UgsvzbCasNCCQA0EaBCgQYAWnCLZJ0m4ZzhbOOlwvnkyupfU44ohTUadldrnafbge8cV5vxm9EfZw3LF8hrSdIohrfB5NBb4WxEvmvxeFEXy/Ac).

Comment: Oh yes, the concatenation instead of tuples, makes the list 1-dimensional which allows us to get rid of the `sum(...)`, very nice!

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 59 bytes

```
func[s][until[move/part skip s 3 s 3""= s: skip s 6]head s]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NU@xasMwEN3zFa9asrR0CHQItKV4SLOk0HYpQsPZOsUismQk2cZf76rUPji4997dPV5kvXyylmpnjljM4BuZlBx8tk52YeTHnmJGutkeCYe/FuIZ6bhRT6pl0khqMSEyNS0y5A6lhHFzPcxJ/KMP3/A6fkfbO84rqoJmnIIzmxr6N58mjuluZS48csQ1eE8od5jDAB0mv8rnfYevEON8jzPeaWS/zyBUbtgMK/JFKp6UGG3ZQDdj5Ctnqh0n1NTcXtfdn/KcIsNY51hjsrmF5syxs56yDcVVSfTR@hK0ZO5KYPHwImCQlVp@AQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 33 bytes

```ruby
->s{s.gsub /(...)(.{,3})/,'\2\1'}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LdExbtswGAXg3ad4YQfHgKKg6dbCNgIPbpZ0aJei6kDZv2SiMmmQlB1B0S2CTj1dL@I82prM/72PBGX6tuzO1fx8twh9yOvQlri/zfN8dpv32adhdp9Ni4fi43Q4RwkxYI5@oqqmK9suKMwXUFxxDiqbqG92I9dQuEzJD28OjcRryBXnmPKV2wrWrqlGjjWTNKY97vBow0l8uLm2nJiFG0apf5ajeNTOWg2ejc612LqTHY/yIGBFwIqAFUHa@TTd47vzvsvwhK/6KHYaobFq2vHabGnY0rClYUuTQLq1ttzIz9BBsON@7DscpZaoy0YCSr35s0wnKTJiMmKyC66JyYjJiJfpyJ@8vPaCyjSNbHEycYetRPF7Y3U0bvwqGspkUNFQ0lDSUCbGs65UTYbJ5a1y0Zsd@leTuVd4vlz1y/z@gkPLZ1QfeiZzOCyh/v97U/icfv@qoYgFSzMUCvJykE00tkaKHKOM/2q8TJ6TwnB@Bw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 64 bytes

```
{chunked(3).chunked(2).fold(""){a,v->a+v.getOrElse(1){""}+v[0]}}

{chunked(3)                                                       // split string into triplets
           .chunked(2)                                            // group triplets by two
                      .fold(""){a,v->a+                           // join to string
                                       v.getOrElse(1){""}+v[0]}}  // putting second before first (if exists)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY4/D4IwEMV3PsWlUxuk8c9GAk5uJg6OxqHKgQ21EDgaScNnx2Lwlncvv8t7VzdktJ2dMtAapE5TCtcgtpJcQJKvBrLZP1@DrbHgByH/617IsjEFZ0x4tXFJrmInK6RLdzI98p3wjE2xu23v0zSXg4W30jbk@gjCLKWEH4IMOlTFWVsM7JgCYz/ehmbi61t8uRQiCjlmfAxj/wU)

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 7 bytes

```
Σṁ↔C2C3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9zihzsbH7VNcTZyNv7//79zfkqqgnt@ThoA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `s`, 5 bytes

```
3ẇy$Y
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=s&code=3%E1%BA%87y%24Y&inputs=flybuys&header=&footer=)

```
3ẇ    # Divide into chunks of three
  y$Y # Swap each pair
```