# Lists of power!

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity

Generate the following list of lists consisting of the unique last digits of the powers from 1 to 9 for the numbers [0..9]

```
[[0], [1], [2, 4, 8, 6], [3, 9, 7, 1], [4, 6], [5], [6], [7, 9, 3, 1], [8, 4, 2, 6], [9, 1]]
```

e.g. For the number 2 we have:
\$2^1,2^2,2^3,2^4,2^5,... \to  2,4,8,16,32,64,128,... \to 2,4,8,6,4,8,... \to [2,4,8,6]\$

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer (as measured in bytes) wins and the usual golfing rules apply.

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20831/78186)

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't think of this while it was in the sandbox, but are different delimiters allowed?

Comment: Some explanation please as to what, exactly, that list is.

Comment: @Noodle9 It’s the unique last digits of the powers of each number 0 to 9 (e.g. \$2^1, 2^2, 2^3, 2^4, 2^5 = 2,4,8,16,32 = 2,4,8,6\$). Including this is the challenge would make it much better, and it’s omission is why I -1ed, as it seems like the OP cares more about people figuring out the pattern rather than actually golfing it

Comment: Why is the first entry `[0]` when `0**x = 1`?

Comment: @Shaggy `0**x = 0` when `x` is not `0`.

Comment: @WheatWizard \$0^x=0\$ but \$x^0=1\$, so \$0^0\$ is actually a conflicting case, and usually undefined. There are a lot of things that fall into place nicely in mathematics if \$0^0\$ would be \$1\$ however. Still, I would argue both `[0]` and `[1,0]` should be valid for the first list for the sake of this challenge, since languages have different behavior, and it doesn't really change the core of the language.

Comment: Ah wait, ignore my comment above. I now we see have a list of `[0,9]`, but the powers are `[1,9]`. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

## Lua, 71 bytes

```
for i=0,9 do u=i a=i while a*i%10~=i do a=a*i%10 u=u..a end print(u)end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P8/Lb9IIdPWQMdSISVfodQ2UyERiMszMnNSFRK1MlUNDeqAfKBUoi2EC1RTqqeXqJCal6JQUJSZV6JRqglk//8PAA)

Since you aren't specific about if you need a table/array or only printed results, I present my answer with printed results:

```
0
1
2486
3971
46
5
6
7931
8426
91
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, <s>71</s> <s>69</s> 67 bytes

Thanks to user81655 and tsh for reducing two bytes each

```js
(a=[...'0123456789']).map(v=>[...new Set(a.map(x=>+x?v**x%10:+v))])
```

```js
console.log(
(a=[...'0123456789']).map(v=>[...new Set(a.map(x=>+x?v**x%10:+v))])
)
```

Comment: [69 bytes](https://tio.run/##dY49C8IwEIZ3f0UWadKeod9NhdTdQYeOoUiQKhUsJQ2x/vpoQifB5eW957mDe0gj56saJr0zzCpuBaU0iJM0y4uyYnXQ0aecMDZwAUl44/TYv1Dbayy9WngTLQcThss2ifeRIaQjdlLDqPGxPZ/orL/9PtzeWBHO@Q8TIu4AicRFCigHxACVbsoA1YAqQN7lKy1c@FZ5n62e@dt03aod7QjZ/PmD2A8)

Comment: (a=[...'0123456789']).map(v=>[...new Set(a.map(x=>v\*\*x\*v%10))])

Answer (score 1):

## CoffeeScript, 46 bytes

It was not specified whether a set can be considered a list, so this outputs a list of sets:

```coffee
(new Set(v**x%10for x in[1..9])for v in[0..9])
```

Outputting a list of arrays would require **57 bytes**:

```coffee
(Array.from new Set(v**x%10for x in[1..9])for v in[0..9])
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 10 bytes

```
TFN4Lm€θÙ,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/xM3PxCf3UdOaczsOz9T5/x8A)

Comment: This is invalid as the program must eventually output something.

Comment: @emanresuA There's a meta post somewhere about allowing submissions that work in theory if they can be proved to work eventually. I don't remember the exact name but I do remember the post.

Comment: It doesn't "work in theory" if it can literally never terminate.

Comment: See [this message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/60273570#60273570).

Comment: [9 bytes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f8vDcc1tyz209tCxE9fDM//8B)

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 61 bytes

```javascript
f=t=>t>9?[]:[(g=x=>[x|0,...x%5>1?g(x*t%10):[]])(t),...f(-~t)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FclBCoAgEADA1wS7kVKHDgnaQ8RDmEoRbdQSHqKvG8111umeLn8uB4ud5lBK1KwNm2G0TllIOmtj89M2Uspc9aYbE@Saq65FZZ1DYPwrgngZXfG0X7QFuVGCCIjlAw)

---

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 62 bytes

```javascript
_=>[...'0123456789'].map(g=(t,x)=>[x,...x%5>1?g(t,x*t%10):[]])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcrtCkAwFIDhq5EdcTLf1LgQLS0fi8bE0u5@@Ps@7yYecY/Xepro0NPsFuYG1vaI6Mc0SbO8KKva57iLk0hGTGjhYxt@g/Xylnbyb4HxaAxNzzm4UR@3VjMqLclCANwL)

---

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 64 bytes

```javascript
_=>Array(10).fill(1).map(g=(x,t)=>[x=x*t%10,...x%5>1?g(x,t):[]])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HclBCoAgEADA1wS7UUseugRr9A6JkEopLMMk7PUGzXV2/eh7DtsV69MvazacJ5ZDCPoF0SCZzTkQSIe@wDKkKiJLlTiVsRBNRUSpaKXo7V@dGkfMsz9v71Zy3oIBxPwB)

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, <s>98</s> 90 bytes

```js
_=>{r=[];for(i=-1;++i<=9;){for(c=[],p=1;c[0]!=(a=(p*=i)%10);c.push(a));r.push(c)}return r}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcmxCsIwEIDhV9FBuLO2NJtyng/goINjKRKC0etQwyUtSOmzx4rbx/93drTRqYRUjvvsOd/5NCk3Lfm3gnBpqCjkyAfC6VfcsnaBDbmmbtcMliFsWXBjaiRXhSG@wCKS/ulw1kcatF/pnINKn@B8u16qmBY/xX/AAyLmLw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 50 bytes

```
DeleteDuplicates/@Array[Mod[(#-1)^#2,a]&,{a=10,a}]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2773yU1J7Uk1aW0IAcoUJJarO/gWFSUWBntm58SraGsa6gZp2ykkxirplOdaGtooJNYG/s/oCgzr0TBIf3/fwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 17 bytes

```
Ｉ﹪ＥχＸιＩ…1§22553ιχ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEwzc/pTQnX8M3sUDD0EBHISC/PLVII1NHASwZlJiXnqqhZKiko@BY4pmXklqhoWRkZGpqDBTI1AQBHQVDAyBl/f//f92yHAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs each list element on its own line with lists double-spaced. Explanation:

```
   χ                Predefined variable 10
  Ｅ                 Map over implicit range
     ι              Current value
    Ｘ               Vectorised to power
       …            Range from
        1           Literal string `1` to
          22553     Literal string `22553`
         §          Cyclically indexed by
               ι    Current value
      Ｉ             Cast to integer
 ﹪                  Vectorised modulo by
                χ   Predefined variable 10
Ｉ                   Cast to string
                    Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 55 bytes

```python
R=range(10);print([[*{a**-~i%10for i in R}]for a in R])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P8i2KDEvPVXD0EDTuqAoM69EIzpaqzpRS0u3LlPV0CAtv0ghUyEzTyGoNhbETgSzYzX//wcA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 71 bytes

```hs
l|d<-[1..9]=[foldl(\a x->a++[x|notElem x a])[][x^p`mod`10|p<-d]|x<-0:d]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcHBDoIwDADQX@lRQ0rgiBne/IpZQ8NAid3WCIce9u2O9z68fxeRWqUEh75v24FGv2YJcnkyGN65abyVlI@HLBEMmK6evL10ijlMfVfUYaBiDrtboBp5SzCC/rZ0gNT/vAq/94qz6gk)

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 57 bytes

```
9*¶

$.`
.
$& $.(**) $.(***) $.(****
.\B

(.+?)( \1)+
$1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/n8tS69A2Li4VvQQuPS4VNQUVPQ0tLU0IBae1uPRinLi4NPS07TU1FGIMNbW5VIB6AQ) Explanation:

```
9*¶

$.`
```

List the digits from `0` to `9`.

```
.
$& $.(**) $.(***) $.(****
```

Calculate the first four powers of each digit.

```
.\B
```

Take the last digit of each power.

```
(.+?)( \1)+
$1
```

Remove duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

## [Deadfish~](https://github.com/TryItOnline/deadfish-), 549 bytes

```
{{i}d}icc{dddd}dddc{iiii}iiiiic{ddddd}ic{iiiii}dddc{dddd}ddc{iiii}iiiic{ddddd}ic{iiiii}dddc{dddd}dcddddddc{i}ddc{d}iic{i}iic{d}ddc{i}c{iiii}dc{ddddd}ic{iiiii}dddc{dddd}c{d}iiic{i}iiic{d}dddc{i}ic{d}dciiiiic{iiii}iiiic{ddddd}ic{iiiii}dddc{dddd}ic{d}iic{i}c{iiii}dc{ddddd}ic{iiiii}dddc{dddd}iic{iiii}c{ddddd}ic{iiiii}dddc{dddd}iiic{iiii}dc{ddddd}ic{iiiii}dddc{ddd}ddddddc{d}dc{i}iiic{d}dddc{i}dddc{d}iiiciiiiic{iiii}iiiic{ddddd}ic{iiiii}dddc{ddd}dddddc{d}ddc{i}ddc{d}iiciiiiiicddddddc{i}c{iiii}dc{ddddd}ic{iiiii}dddc{ddd}ddddc{d}dddciiiiic{iiii}iiiicc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVBbCoAwDDuRh5JWMd9@lp59ro85RZgrbIw2ydLwtvKO81hKEYGygki4ltZDglpqF6Jrc28i5ol8AEc48pGhnVNBhvI7VTSVeCATxGQm1bnxprQ74wjdxMTHt@oQg18lbTGY288W3KLB/CbaBd/pIiR67nPmmp2PASrlAg)

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 10 bytes

```
9ʀƛn9ɾevtU
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=9%CA%80%C6%9Bn9%C9%BEevtU&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 0):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), <s>134 122</s> 112 bytes

[// this codegolf link specifies that lambda names could be ignored in calculating the bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/126464/tips-for-golfing-in-kotlin)

```kotlin
var listOfPower =
```

```kotlin
{n:Int->List(9){n}.mapIndexed{index,_->(1f*n).pow(index).toInt()}.map{"$it".last().digitToInt()}.distinctBy{it}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y84vycnM@/@/Os/KM69E184ns7hEw1KzOq9WLzexwDMvJbUiNaU6E0TrxOvaaRimaeVp6hXkl2uAxTT1SvKB@jQ0wcqrlVQyS5T0chKBZmjqpWSmZ5aEwKRTgAZn5iWXOFVWZ5bU1v7/DwA)

```kotlin
{n:Int->List(9){n}.mapIndexed{index,_->(1f*n).pow(index).toInt()}.distinctBy{"$it".last()}.map{"$it".last().digitToInt()}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y84vycnM@/@/Os/KM69E184ns7hEw1KzOq9WLzexwDMvJbUiNaU6E0TrxOvaaRimaeVp6hXkl2uAxTT1SvKB@jQ0a/VSgDoz85JLnCqrlVQyS5T0chKLwRJAc1BEgCrTM0tCoPpq//8HAA)

```kotlin
{n:Int->List(9){n}.mapIndexed{index,_->(1f*n).pow(index)}.distinctBy{"${it.toInt()}".last()}.map{"${it.toInt()}".last().digitToInt()}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y84vycnM@/@/Os/KM69E184ns7hEw1KzOq9WLzexwDMvJbUiNaU6E0TrxOvaaRimaeVp6hXkl2uAxTRr9VKAOjLzkkucKquVVKozS/RK8oEmaWjWKunlJBaDGCCTcMgBdadnloRARWv//wcA)

##### Ungolfed:

```kotlin
    var listOfPower =
    {n:Int->List(9){n}.
    mapIndexed{index,_->(1f*n).pow(index).toInt()}.
    map{"$it".last().digitToInt()}.
    distinctBy{it}}
```

create an array of size 9, set all of them to n,

set every single one to their power to their index, convert to int

remove duplicates by getting their last digit

create a list that holds in their last digits and return it

Answer (score -3):

## Pyth, 10 bytes

```
m.ue*Ndd)T
```

[Try it here!](http://pythtemp.herokuapp.com/?code=m.ue%2aNdd%29T&debug=0)

Comment: I don't think it's particularly good form to post the first answer to your own challenge, especially when it wasn't very well described.

Comment: Though you can post this after a few days, if you don't get a solution in this language, and to post it earlier you can set a bounty for people who can beat your this answer in the same language, thanks!