# Implement Minceraft

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, random

## Introduction

The game [Minecraft](https://minecraft.net) has a 1 in 10000 chance of showing "Minceraft" instead of "Minecraft" on the title screen.

## Your challenge

Your challenge is to code a function or program that takes no input, and on average 1 of 10000 times, returns "Minceraft" and the rest of the time returns "Minecraft".

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest wins!

Comment: All solutions so far will not satisfy the challenge as stated (they might, but highly unlikely). It has in fact been misstated - it is correct in the introduction, but the challenge asks for something different

Comment: @jonrandy What do you mean?

Comment: The introduction talks about a 1 in 10000 chance, whereas the challenge asks for a function/program that returns "Minceraft" EXACTLY once and "Minecraft" the rest of the time. This would be achieved with a loop. The solutions below are doing what is stated in the introduction, which is different

Comment: Suggest edit: "on average 1 out of 10000 times", assuming this is the intention, to satisfy nitpickers...

Comment: @jonrandy Sorry for any confusion, I meant what the intro says.

Comment: how precisly does it have to be 1/10000 ? multiple answers have 1/10001 for example

Comment: @Gulzar What do you mean on different processes?

Comment: @Ausername The program can be run from a new OS process each run (which happens if you run on a stateless server), or, it could be in the same process, such a for-loop in the simplest case. This has an effect on virtual memory, on which a 1 byte upgrade to the answer relies. See comments [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225075/103702)

Comment: @Gulzar I think that's fine, since every time you run it as a full program, it has that 1/10000 chance.

Comment: When I first saw the title I thought the goal is to implement the entire game of minecraft in shortest possible amount of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Jelly (fork)](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/jellylanguage), 16 bytes

```
ȷ4XỊị“ẹ?ŀɼƲṬ`Ỵȧ«
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASsA1P9qZWxsef//yLc0WOG7iuG7i@KAnOG6uT/FgMm8xrLhuaxg4bu0yKfCq///), or rather, don't

Tested on commit [6167f95](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/jellylanguage/commit/6167f95e9aa29b15dd31a848022cd9909ef8c8bd), made on March 13th. Doesn't work on the latest commit due to a bug (a.k.a I accidentally removed the functionality that makes this work)

### How it works

```
ȷ4XỊị“ẹ?ŀɼƲṬ`Ỵȧ« - Main link. Takes no argument
ȷ4               - 10000
  X              - Random integer between 1 and 10000
   Ị             - Turn 1 into 1 and everything else into 0
     “ẹ?ŀɼƲṬ`Ỵȧ« - Compressed dictionary string "Minceraft Minecraft", split on spaces
    ị            - Index into the list of words
```

`“...«` is a new string terminator introduced in my fork that's equivalent to `“...»Ḳ¤`/`“...»Ỵ¤` in the current version of Jelly. It decompresses the string in between the `“...«`, then splits on whitespace.

Answer (score 61):

## Minecraft, <s>358</s> <s>293</s> <s>277</s> 276 bytes

*Implementing Minceraft in Minecraft*

Should be run as a set of commands in game. Should be run on a fresh superflat (redstone ready) world.
Byte count is the amount of characters you need to type, including newlines.

```
/scoreboard objectives add s dummy
/summon bat
/execute as @e[type=bat] store result score o s run data get entity @s UUID[1]
/scoreboard players set c s 2147054151
/execute if score o s < c s run tellraw @s "Minecraft"
/execute if score o s >= c s run tellraw @s "Minceraft"
```

The UUID of an entity is (mostly) randomly generated and stored as four signed 32 bit integers. One of the integers is compared with `2147054151` which is one ten thousandth of the way between `2^31` and `-2^31`.

Previous solution because it was so high effort and I'm not deleting it:

### Minecraft, 293 bytes

```
/scoreboard objectives add s dummy
/summon horse
/execute as @e[type=horse] store result score o s run data get entity @s Attributes[1].Base 100000
/scoreboard players set c s 11883
/execute if score o s >= c s run tellraw @s "Minecraft"
/execute if score o s < c s run tellraw @s "Minceraft"
```

#### How does it work?

In Minecraft, there are only a limited amount of sources of reliable randomness usable in commands. In Minecraft Functions you can use predicates with specific random chances, but that requires multiple files and submitting that as a zipped data pack would be at least 1 KB.

To avoid this and have it run solely from commands a player can type in, this uses horses as a random source. When a horse is spawned, it is assigned a random speed between 0.1125 and 0.3375 (the units are arbitrary). The random speed calculation is as follows:

$$0.25(0.45 + 0.3x + 0.3y + 0.3z)$$

Where *x*, *y*, and *z* are uniform independent random variables **[0, 1)**. If you find the cumulative density function by convolving the distribution functions (to get the PDF) and then integrating, you will end up with the following piecewise function:

$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}-\frac{9}{16}+15x-\frac{400x^{2}}{3}+\frac{32000x^{3}}{81}&\frac{9}{80}\le x<\frac{3}{16}\\
\frac{29}{4}-110x+\frac{1600x^{2}}{3}-\frac{64000x^{3}}{81}&\frac{3}{16}\le x<\frac{21}{80}\\
-\frac{227}{16}+135x-400x^{2}+\frac{32000x^{3}}{81}&\frac{21}{80}\le x<\frac{27}{80}
\end{cases}
$$

We need to find the horse speed where the probability of a horse with that speed or lower spawning is one in ten thousand or 0.0001. This can be done by solving the first equation:

$$-\frac{9}{16}+15x-\frac{400x^{2}}{3}+\frac{32000x^{3}}{81} = 0.0001\\
f^{-1}(0.0001)\simeq0.11882574$$

This results in the horse speed being multiplied by 100,000 (because scoreboard values must be integers) and compared with 11883 in the code.

The precision is currently 1.00202 in 10,000. Two bytes can be added or removed for approximately each order of magnitude required. Two additional bytes will make it 1.00012 in 10,000.

Comment: I see no reason to run these separately over putting them all in a .mcfunction file and running that.

Comment: Minecraft datapacks require a pack.mcmeta which would make it too expensive. However, I am not certain of the consensus regarding Minecraft commands.

Comment: I'd argue the pack.mcmeta doesn't count towards the size, only the .mcfunction file. After all, https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224450/62991 doesn't count the time module's size either.

Comment: This is also a "full program" (as much as you can get a full program in Minecraft) compared to a function as you cannot reliably run it multiple times in one world.

Comment: Aww, I was hoping you built a giant Redstone computer in the game to run this program, would be hard to give that a byte-count though.  Maybe count in number of blocks?

Comment: The UUID version could be run multiple times by giving the summoned bat a custom scoreboard tag, using that scoreboard tag in the bat's target selector and subsequently killing all bats with the scoreboard tag. That would significantly increase the function size though, and it's irrelevant for the given task. If you want to put this in a datapack, on the other hand, that'd be the way to do that.

Comment: Do you have to include `/`? If you put your commands in a command block/.mcfucntion then you can remove those. Maybe we should have something in meta regularizing commands? Also if you can use time you can do [214 bytes](https://pastebin.pl/view/c2020eca)

Comment: -20 by replacing `tellraw @s` with `me`

Comment: If you count the amount of characters you need to type in chat than you should include a trailing newline

Comment: do you need `[type=bat]`? Also, since I assume you get inputs with a scoreboard and it's allowed to assume empty input (I'm fairly sure), can you assume there's a scoreboard existing?

Comment: Do you need `summon bat`? Can't you use the players UUID (or whatever other entity will spawn there)?

Comment: A player's UUID always stays the same so I wouldn't really count it as random, and I can't rely on another entity existing in the world by chance.

Comment: Not including `[type=bat]` can select the command executor, and it does include a trailing newline.

Comment: -50 characters by replacing the second and third lines (the ones with the bat) with: 
/execute store result score o s run seed

Answer (score 21):

## Python 3, <s>63</s> 59 bytes

My idea was to use the `time` module as a PRNG since the challenge stated

> on average 1 of 10000 times, returns "Minceraft" and the rest of the time returns "Minecraft"

and taking the time mod 10000 does exactly that.

Thanks [@movatica](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/86751/movatica) for -4

```py
import time
print(f"Min{'ceec'[time.time()%1e4>1::2]}raft")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEkMzeVq6AoM69EI03JNzOvWj05NTVZPRokrgciNDRVDVNN7AytrIxia4sS00qUNP//BwA)

Alternative, also 59 bytes:

```py
import time
print("Min%sraft"%"ceec"[time.time()%1e4>1::2])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEkMzeVq6AoM69EQ8k3M0@1uCgxrURJVSk5NTVZKRokqwciNDRVDVNN7AytrIxiNf//BwA)

Comment: Right, fixed. :)

Comment: you should add a tio link, so that it's easier for other people to test your code

Comment: Can't you replace `time()%1e4>1 and'ec'or'ce'` with `['ec','ce'][time()%1e4>1]` for -1?

Comment: [61 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEkMzeVq6AoM69EI03JNzOvOlo9OVVdRz01WT02GiSpByI0NFUNU03sDGNrixLTSpQ0//8HAA)

Comment: I believe you can remove the space in `1 and`

Comment: Welcome to codegolf!
[59 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEkMzeVq6AoM69EI03JNzOvWj05NTVZPRokrgciNDRVDVNN7AytrIxia4sS00qUNP//BwA "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: [45 bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/225075/103702)

Answer (score 13):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <del>78</del> <del>71</del> <del>69</del> 68 bytes

```python
from random import*
f=lambda:f'Min{randint(0,1e4)and"ec"or"ce"}raft'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYyxCoAwEEN3v6J00YqDopPgJ/gRVXt6YO/K0UXEb69tlhBekvDEi2lMCYS9EktHNvSBJbYVLLf122FnqFekt1Ck2PTd4CaTg3a7ZtG7059YiHUCFoUKqRydrhT7LDMHKTtojEk)

-7 bytes thanks to [@Alex bries](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/99744/alex-bries)

-2 bytes thanks to [@Alex bries](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/99744/alex-bries)

Comment: you only need to return it: [try it online](https://tio.run/##HcsxDoMwDEDRvaeIskAqhiDEgtoj9BABbLBEnMjNghBnD4TpL@/HPa2Bu5xRglfieL5DPgZJ7xd@N@fH2Q1Y/YgPPYEmfBBxqm3TQm8@LWx/0DDpUxymKmMQRYq4uAWKstYMUcqCtTH5Ag)

Comment: nvm i am stupid

Comment: `f=lambda:f'Min{__import__("random").randint(0,1e4)and"ec"or"ce"}raft'` is 69, but since you can remove `f=` that evaluates to 67.

Comment: [67 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P60oP1ehKDEvBUhl5hbkF5VoceUk5ialJFqlqftm5lUrJacqRVtZgZRk5pVoGOgYpppo2hjmF@kaxtYWJaaVqP//DwA)

Comment: [65 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P60oP1ehKDEvBUhl5hbkF5VocRUUZeaVaKSp@2bmVSdn5Gcmp2pEKyWnKsVqRyulJivFalkCgWZtUWJaibrm//8A "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: Can you save a couple bytes by printing your result instead of writing a function?

Comment: 63 bytes, I think it warrants its own answer: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224450/103324

Answer (score 13):

### Python 3 - <s>45</s> <s>42</s> 41 Bytes

41 bytes with the constraint of running from a different process every run.

```
print(f"Min{'ceec'[id(0)%4e4>1::2]}raft")
```

42 bytes with limited randomness unless running a different process each time [*].

```
print(f"Min{'ceec'[id({})%4e4>1::2]}raft")
```

The idea was to use the same wrapper as in [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224450/103702), but a different RNG:
Create a new object (a <s>set</s> dict in this case, because it takes <s>5</s> 2 characters <s>`set()`</s> `{}`), and take the `id()` of that, which is its memory address.

The memory address acts like a uniform hash[*], which has <s>`1/10000`</s> `1/40000` (thanks @ovs) chance to end with zeros.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EI03JNzOvWj05NTVZPTozRaM4tURDU1PVMNXEztDKyii2tigxrURJ8/9/AA)

**Update to 42 bytes:**
Instead of `set()`, use `{}` which is the `dict` constructor. Can't go shorter for dynamic object creation.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EI03JNzOvWj05NTVZPTozRaO6VlPVMNXEztDKyii2tigxrURJ8/9/AA)

**Update to 41 bytes:** - use static object creation!
Thanks to @dingledooper
**Works only if the program is run in a different process every run!**
Instead of `{}`, use `0`.
`0` is an object in Python, so it has an address in virtual memory, and that address is constant for that object during the lifetime of the program. If we were to run that in a for loop, it would not be random.
However, if we run it in a new process every run, we get the desired randomness.  This is the case in a [stateless server](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EI03JNzOvWj05NTVZPTozRaO6VlPVJNXEztDKyii2tigxrURJ8/9/AA).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EI03JNzOvWj05NTVZPTozRaO6VlPVJNXEztDKyii2tigxrURJ8/9/AA)

[*] - Objects in Python are freed immediately when they are no longer referenced (reference counting). Thus, running the solution in a loop might always output the same id, as the memory is freed and allocated at the same address. This is OS dependent, and environment dependent, thus may not work as expected, or in a reproducible way.
Running a new process each time solves this issue.

Comment: Welcome to CGCC, that's a very nice answer! By my [experimentation](https://tio.run/##RY4xi8MwDIV3/wotJTZtQ8rdVMh03NAtewhHz1GvhsQysjz016f2JaWL4EnvfU/hIXfyH8tyY5rB0jShFUc@gpsDscAXJS/IapMx/QYmizGq/8RbvwLdpftWijGmSSK0L4A2St2I4QecB776P9SnpjFnBVAA2fhG1R0F9LqvwvpddYDqaMsM7LxoN@qIoo3ZfZpqOEQZKUlbik3GrTIDC622NM/JO3sV1KZvhmzgfCuY1ViPaGnMx5Ld3u55gH0LJ7X2bVuzLE8) it seems that memory addresses of `set()` are always divisible by `4`, which means you would need to change `1e4` to `4e4` to get the right probability.

Comment: @ovs wow that's a very nice catch, thanks!

Comment: Wow. And I thought using `time` was nice...

Comment: Does `id(0)` work here?

Comment: @dingledooper no, it is always the same

Comment: Hmm, though on [TIO](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EIzNFw0BTB0hW12pq/v8PAA) it does seem to give similarly varying results.

Comment: @dingledooper I guess it is because they open a new process every time. Running it in the same process such as in a for loop, or even in the same ipython process will give the same every time due to the same virtual memory space

Comment: @ovs I try your experimentation, but I am getting that memory addresses of set is divisble by 64 (not only 4), and more of that they always terminate by "100011000000" in their binary representation. I also tried an other approach: [link](https://tio.run/##dY7LCsIwEEX3/YoLIiQLpbXgQuiXlC4indqBOC1J0Bbx22t8g4@7GGYGzuH2Y2g7yafJF2WVDNfRdA4MFjgjO1JZGqM3CWL80vQ9Sa1OZ43ZjoScCQQDoSM8BRw5tI@T6xsyPBGulS8XWaU1kt6xBGVJVITUoONvdiDHzYjQmgBjbVwoOjyMI9TcNORIgv9AeZ6tiyLFq/Pd9eTJ0v5KPSQH9ry1hO2IbP1lylc/TNK92/y35atpugA "Python 3 – Try It Online") which shows me that ids are divisible by 16. Is that normal?

Comment: @Jakque That's really odd, I'm quite sure I tested `%8` and got two different results. But now I'm even getting that all addresses are the same under `%4096`. After some more testing, `16e4` instead of `4e4` [seems to work](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v9g2OparAkSk5RcpZCpk5ikUJealp2oYGmhpmWlacSkAQbFeYkFBal6KRnWtJligAiaQmaJRHK1rGKupqcBVUJSZV6KRk5qnUZxaolGhqamJJpSpamiWaqIAtwik5P9/AA) for your script, but I'm not sure of how representative this is compared to running a new python process every time. When running `python3 -c "print(id(set())%16e4)"` locally 1e5 times I get 625 different results.

Comment: @Jakque I think this has to be OS specific. I would like to ask a question about this in SO, please add the specifications on which you tested, and the code.

Comment: @ovs see comment above please

Comment: [40 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQ8k3M09Vz6i4KDGtRElVPTk1WT06M0XDQFPVJNXEztAqVvP/fwA)

Comment: @c-- plz edit this answer + explain the diff

Comment: instead of using a `[::2]` selector, it truncates the string to 2 characters, which allows shortening the string to `'cec'`. See the python docs for [`printf`-style String Formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting) (also known as old string formatting) for more information.

Answer (score 11):

## JavaScript, 37 bytes

```js
_=>`Min${new Date%1e4?'ec':'ce'}raft`
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/ifZvs/3tYuwTczT6U6L7VcwSWxJFXVMNXEXj01Wd1KPTlVvbYoMa0k4X9afpFGpq2BtbZ2po1hqpG1ZnJ@XnF@TqpeTn66RpqGpuZ/AA)

First of all, write `Min`.

Then get the current time with `new Date`. Normally it returns something similar to "2021-10-05T10:29:58.432Z". But if you do a mathematical operation on it, this output becomes the epoch time similar to "1633429932422" (a number, basically).

Now divide the number by 10000 (1e4). If the remainder (%) is `0` i.e. `false`, add `ce` to `Min` otherwise add `ec`.

At last, add `raft` at the end.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice first answer!

Comment: Thanks, wonder if anything can be improved here!

Comment: I'm not that fluent with JavaScript, so I can't really see any improvements you could make. But there might be a way!

Answer (score 9):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 48 bytes

```c
f(){printf("Min%sraft",rand()%10000?"ec":"ce");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NQ7O6oCgzryRNQ8k3M0@1uCgxrURJpygxL0VDU9XQAAjslVKTlayUklOVNK1r/wOVKuQmZuZpaHJVcykAQVp@kYIGSDRPwVbBwBpI2SgYA2lt7TxNBYgSsDINTWs4B2ZjTJ4SVLSWq/b/v@S0nMT04v@65QA)

#### Version closer to \$\frac{1}{10000}\$

For a pseudorandomness as close to \$\frac{1}{10000}\$ as possible:

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 79 bytes

```c
f(){long p=0,m=1e4,i;for(i=m;i--;)p+=rand();printf("Min%sraft",p%m?"ec":"ce");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY1NCsMgFIT3nuLxIKAkQkq7qpWeoDfoRqwGIb6ICXQRcvVa@zubYYaPGSsHa0vxXKzjRAMk3XdR79yhC8pPmQcdVZBSidTqbOjGhUo50OI5XgI1czZ@wS418YzO4hGtQ6G2UgmIJhAXbGVQVbeAv1oCDb2qdoJ99bYlAR/kjdX9f/gdXQm/7ca28rB@NMNc5P0J)

Comment: Nice! Can you have 1e4 or 1e+4 in C?

Comment: @Ausername float can't be `%`ed

Comment: @Ausername Yes C has that but it's a `float` and you need an integral type for a mod (`%`) expression.

Comment: This will not result in a 1/10000 chance if `RAND_MAX` is not a multiple of 10000.

Comment: @ericw31415 You might as well post this comment for **every answer** since they're all using PRNGs that work on scales of powers of \$2\$. Plus they're PRNGs **not** RNGs so there's no way to make them perfectly random.

Answer (score 9):

## [Taxi](https://bigzaphod.github.io/Taxi/), 632 bytes

```
Go to Heisenberg's:W 1 R 3 R 1 L.Pickup a passenger going to Divide and Conquer.1073741824e-4 is waiting at Starchild Numerology.Go to Starchild Numerology:N 1 L 3 L 1 L 3 L.Pickup a passenger going to Divide and Conquer.Go to Divide and Conquer:W 1 R 3 R 1 R 2 R 1 R.Pickup a passenger going to Trunkers.Go to Trunkers:E 1 R 3 R 1 L.Pickup a passenger going to The Underground.Go to The Underground:E 1 R 2 L.Switch to plan A if no one is waiting.Minecraft is waiting at Writer's Depot.[A]Minceraft is waiting at Writer's Depot.Go to Writer's Depot:N 3 L 2 L.Pickup a passenger going to Post Office.Go to Post Office:N 1 R 2 R 1 L.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZFBT8MwDIX/im87EdGu0lBvE0NwKGPahnZAHELqttaKU5KUwa8vKW2lFRCDQxTFfvn0/OzkGzXNtQan4QbJIj@hySc23kEAa5j6E0AiVqT2dQUSKmm9JkcDuSbO228LeqUUQXIKl5pfajQiOJ9NZ1FwEUZ4FgFZOEhyrVw62DhpVEFlCsv6GY0udf4uOgM/teJla8AbSYb7v2Y69vfGaMQ1hN39K31rat6jsT1zeMZXfw5rWyDcc@ozNrrmdACNqz0v9KzNgZwqWk1VSoY5UAasQTMexSpuiVEZmbkvWe8MOTQTCwustBMP80evVHha2dkaF/0m2i2EJyZcaevgLstIYY85qnxuc8g6EU3zAQ)

There are two sources of randomness in Taxi: **Heisenberg's** (which holds a random integer passenger), and **Firemouth Grill** (which can hold any number of passengers, who are picked up in a random order).

This program uses **Heisenberg's** to grab a random number, which will be used to choose one of two strings randomly.

Here is the basic control flow of the program:

- Go to **Heisenberg's** and grab a random integer, in the range of \$[0, 2^{31}-1]\$. (\$2^{31}-1\$ is `RAND_MAX` in C++, and Taxi uses C++'s random functions.)
- Pick up the value `1073741824e-4` (that's \$\frac{2^{31}}{2 \times 10000}\$) from **Starchild Numerology**.
- Drop off both passengers at **Divide and Conquer**, giving us a result of \$\frac{n}{2^{31}} \times 2 \times 10000\$, which is a double in the range \$[0, 2 \times 10000)\$. (We use this range instead of \$[0, 10000)\$ because we will output `Minceraft` when this number is either 0 or 1.)
- Bring this result to **Trunkers**, which chops off the fractional part. (The range is still \$[0, 2 \times 10000)\$.)
- Bring this result to **The Underground**. One of two things will happen:
- - A passenger will be returned, which means that our number was greater than 1 (which has a \$\frac{2 \times 10000 - 2}{2 \times 10000}\$ chance of occurring). Do nothing.
- - No passenger will be returned, which means that our number was either 0 or 1 (which has a \$\frac{2}{2 \times 10000}\$ chance of occurring). Declare the value `"Minceraft"` at **Writer's Depot**.
- Declare the value `"Minecraft"` at **Writer's Depot**.
- Pick up the first passenger waiting at **Writer's Depot**. (If both `"Minecraft"` and `"Minceraft"` are waiting, `"Minceraft"` will be picked up, because it was waiting there first.)
- Drop off this passenger at the **Post Office**, outputting the string and (for purposes of Code Golf) ending the program.

## [Taxi](https://bigzaphod.github.io/Taxi/), 691 bytes

```
1e4 is waiting at Starchild Numerology.Go to Starchild Numerology:W 1 L 2 R 1 L 1 L 2 L.Pickup a passenger going to The Underground.Minceraft is waiting at Writer's Depot.Go to Writer's Depot:E 1 L 2 R.[A]Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.Go to Cyclone:N.Pickup a passenger going to Firemouth Grill.Pickup a passenger going to Firemouth Grill.Go to Firemouth Grill:S 1 L 2 L 1 R.Go to Fueler Up:E 1 L.Go to The Underground:N.Switch to plan B if no one is waiting.Pickup a passenger going to The Underground.Minecraft is waiting at Writer's Depot.Go to Writer's Depot:N 3 L 2 L.Switch to plan A.[B]Go to Firemouth Grill:S 1 R.Pickup a passenger going to Post Office.Go to Post Office:E 1 R.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVFLb4MwDP4rvu0WqdtO3No9eulYBat6qHqIggnW0hgFo66/ntECUoc2pO7k5LPl72HRX9Q0M3wEquCoSchb0AKp6GAKchnE9QEDO7YntWQQ/rUVbWEGK7iH5FK790qtyXzWJWgodVWhtxjA8pmhXfNRIGx8hsEGrn2m3sgbDDqXkZJtIMFwV8Ezliy9hp9g9DKwq918P0X6dDKOPfZb@l8UTwp9pYAHrqWAZSDnbprteEZolA4BtTUZZmp07aZN2Znp0VFIrdL0SGKKc6902sMCKAfP0Nq4yu3W4NH8M/gYHvpTj3TN1W6x/9t9MqlwzZXAe56TGS51hVzySVTTfAM)

This program uses **Firemouth Grill** to hold thousands of "Minecraft" and "Minceraft" strings to choose from randomly.

Here is the basic control flow of the program:

- Pick up the value `1e4` from **Starchild Numerology** to use as a counter.
- Declare the value `"Minceraft"` at **Writer's Depot** and go there (but don't pick it up yet).
- Repeat these steps:
- - Pick up the string currently at **Writer's Depot**, and clone it at **Cyclone**. (Having two strings along for the ride will earn us extra gas money!)
- - Take both clones, and drop them off at **Firemouth Grill**.
- - Take our counter, and drop it off at **The Underground**. One of two things will happen:
- - - A passenger will be left waiting, which was 1 less than our previous counter. Pick up this new counter, and declare the value `"Minecraft"` at **Writer's Depot** and go there. At this point, repeat the previous steps.
- - - No passenger will be left waiting, which means that our counter is now 0 and we are done.
- Go to **Firemouth Grill**, and pick up a passenger. It will most likely be `"Minecraft"`, but there's a 1/10000 chance it will be `"Minceraft"`.
- Drop off this passenger at the **Post Office**, outputting the string and (for purposes of Code Golf) ending the program.

## [Taxi](https://bigzaphod.github.io/Taxi/), 849 bytes

```
Go to Fueler Up:W 1 R.Switch to plan B.[A]Go to Fueler Up:E 2 L.[B]Go to Heisenberg's:N 3 R 1 L.Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.Go to Cyclone:N 1 L 3 L.Pickup a passenger going to Magic Eight.Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.Go to Cyclone:N 1 R 3 R 1 R.Pickup a passenger going to Equal's Corner.Pickup a passenger going to Equal's Corner.Go to Equal's Corner:N 1 R.2e4 is waiting at Starchild Numerology.Go to Starchild Numerology:N 1 R.Pickup a passenger going to Magic Eight.Go to Magic Eight:W 1 R 2 R 1 R.Switch to plan A if no one is waiting.Pickup a passenger going to The Underground.Go to The Underground:E 2 L.Switch to plan C if no one is waiting.Minecraft is waiting at Writer's Depot.[C]Minceraft is waiting at Writer's Depot.Go to Writer's Depot:N 3 L 2 L.Pickup a passenger going to Post Office.Go to Post Office:N 1 R 2 R 1 L.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVLLboMwEPyVveVmqbSn3BJK2wNJI9IoB5SDaxazKrWpMUrz9dQEVyIooo@jZ3dm1rtj@Se17aMGq@GhwRIN7Kr5Hm4gYdsjWVF0larkCpYsXRzGnREEELN06QtPSDWqVzRyVs/XcAuJU4rZhsRbUwGHiteuLh1XalKyo4QnUWqFrBfwL8d1PMef5q64JAERycL@0yPxMyaT/Oij4eWshlAbheYvrb3jJdgbswDvgGo4crIdl1vYWm5EQWUG6@YdjS61PHmFayWv89sF9UIDpD@zO2By7dwLoByUBrepwZiTbi8Fwk5l7vpGNyrzjiPUR2bkFl53W5FCYXhuR5vaG7Jo3EbvsdKWpeHBdQr8ubMf6RI8BzU@TzX1u42uLTznOYnvIA0QH6bAB75tvwA)

This was my first instinct. It also uses **Heisenberg's** to generate a random integer within the range \$[0, 2 \times 10000)\$, but it does so by repeatedly generating a random number until it is within this range. The taxi has to stop at **Fueler Up** to refill its gas tank, and it has to clone passengers at **Cyclone** and drop the clones off at **Equal's Corner** to make enough money to re-generate random numbers for as long as necessary, but otherwise, the functionality is the same as the 632-byte program.

It doesn't depend on the specifics of C++, but it *does* usually take longer to execute, because generating a small enough random number is rarer. If anyone can improve this one, be my guest.

Answer (score 8):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>45</s> <s>44</s> 43 bytes

```r
`if`(runif(1)<1e-4,"Minceraft","Minecraft")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PyEzLUGjqDQvM03DUNPGMFXXREfJNzMvObUoMa1ECcxOTQazNf//BwA)

Boring, but shorter than any more-interesting attempt that I've tried so far...

---

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 42 bytes <s>(p=0.000101)</s> p=1 in 10000.5

*Edit: much closer to exactly 1 in 10000 (for the same bytes) thanks to Robin Ryder*

```r
`if`(rexp(1)>1e-4,"Minecraft","Minceraft")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PyEzLUGjKLWiQMNQ084wVddER8k3My81uSgxrUQJzE5OBbM1//8HAA)

Outputs "Minecraft" if an exponentially-distributed random variable is greater than 1e-4.

The exponential distribution is governed by a parameter - lambda - that defaults to 1 in the [R](https://www.r-project.org/) `rexp()` function.  This gives cumulative p(up to x)=1-exp(-lambda*x), equal to 9.9995e-05 with x=1e-4 and lamda=1, which is pretty close to 1 in 10000 (actually 1 in 10000.5).

Comment: Alternate 43 byte solution: `c("Minecraft","Minceraft")[1.0001+runif(1)]`

Comment: @RobinRyder - That's nice.  I also realised we can also get almost to within 1% of the exact probability using a carefully-selected Poisson distribution, which would save 1 byte...

Comment: If you want an approximation of the probability, [this](https://tio.run/##K/r/PyEzLUGjKLWiQMNQ084wVddER8k3My81uSgxrUQJzE5OBbM1//8HAA "R – Try It Online") is also 42 bytes and is more accurate, with P("Minceraft")=0.000100005.

Comment: @RobinRyder - That's much better!  Before I update the answer and credit you, can you just check my maths?  Cumulative exponential distribution is 1-exp(-lambda*x), so with (default) rate=lambda=1, p(up to 1e-4)=1-exp(-0.0001)=9.9995e-05, right?  In other words, ```pexp(1,rate=0.0001,lower.tail=T)```?  Or did I get something upside-down?

Comment: Yes, you are right - the number I gave mistakenly was the value of lambda that would have led to an exact answer. Instead, the probability is indeed 0.000099995.

Answer (score 8):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), 42 bytes

```clj
#(str"Min"(if(<(rand)1e-4)"ce""ec")"raft")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87JzyotSv2vUVCUmVeioPFfWaO4pEjJNzNPSSMzTcNGoygxL0XTMFXXRFMpOVVJKTVZSVOpKDGtREnzv6bmfwA)

Answer (score 6):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 17 bytes

```
MinＰceraft¿‽×χφec
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvREPJNzNPSdOay7c0pySzACKUnFqUmFYCEs1MU9AISsxLyc/VCMnMTS3WMDTQUTA0MDDQ1NRUgBqQmgxU@f//f92yHAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Min
```

Print `Min`.

```
Ｐceraft
```

Print `ceraft` without moving the cursor.

```
¿‽×χφ
```

If a random number in the range `[0..10000)` is nonzero, then...

```
ec
```

... correct it to `ec`.

Answer (score 6):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 29 bytes

```
ce9999*$(ec
L@$`..
Min$&raft
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/nys51RIItFQ0UpO5fBxUEvT0uHwz81TUihLTSv7/BwA) Explanation:

```
ce9999*$(ec
```

Insert `ce` and `9999` copies of `ec`.

```
L@`..
```

Select one of the pairs of letters at random....

```
L$`
Min$&raft
```

... and wrap it between `Min` and `raft`.

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 17 bytes

```
’£Ì³±’œ4°LΩΘ5!*è™
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASoA1f9vc2FiaWX//@KAmcKjw4zCs8Kx4oCZxZM0wrBMzqnOmDUhKsOo4oSi//8)

```
’£Ì³±’                -- "minecraft"
      œ               -- permutations: ["minecraft", "minecratf", ...]
       4°LΩ           -- random integer in the range 1..10000
           Θ          -- 1 if it’s equal to 1, 0 otherwise
            5!*       -- multiply by 5! (120)
               è      -- index into the list of permutations
                ™     -- titlecase
```

Answer (score 6):

## APL, 26 bytes

```
'Min','raft',⍨'ec'⌽⍨1=?1E4
```

Saved 1 byte thanks to Adam

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833), and nice first answer! If you're interested in learning more APL, feel free to drop by [The APL Orchard](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52405/the-apl-orchard)

Comment: `10*4` is `1E4`

Answer (score 6):

## Minecraft, 226 bytes.

```
/scoreboard objectives add d dummy
/scoreboard players set c d 2147054151
/execute store result score s d run seed
/execute if score s d < c d run tellraw @s "Minecraft"
/execute if score s d >= c d run tellraw @s "Minceraft"
```

(Includes a trailing newline, to run the final command)

I saw [the other Minecraft answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224504/110376) by [Okx](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/26600/okx) and had some suggestions. I would've put them in the comments of the other response, but I figured I changed it enough for its own submission, and [another CGSE member said it's fine](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/63155893#63155893) so whatever.

I'm only just now noticing the only change I made was using /seed. Ah, well. The things you learn when you have five ideas for improvements and four of them don't work.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>18</s> 17 bytes

```
“ẹ?ŀɼƲṬ`Ỵȧ»ȷ4XỊịḲ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AS4A0f9qZWxsef//4oCc4bq5P8WAybzGsuG5rGDhu7TIp8K7yLc0WOG7iuG7i@G4sv//)

Full program.

-1 byte thanks to [Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53748/jonathan-allan)!

### How it works

```
“ẹ?ŀɼƲṬ`Ỵȧ»ȷ4XỊịḲ - Main link. Takes no arguments
“ẹ?ŀɼƲṬ`Ỵȧ»       - Compressed string "Minceraft Minecraft"; Call that S
           ȷ4     - 10000
             X    - Random integer between 1 and 10000
              Ị   - Is that equal to 1?
                Ḳ - Split S on spaces
               ị  - Index into the split S
```

Comment: A 17: ``“ẹ?ŀɼƲṬ`Ỵȧ»ȷ4XỊịḲ``. (Also, another 18: `ȷ4XỊ⁾ecṙ“¡Œ!“¡^Ð»j`.)

Comment: @JonathanAllan Oh, nice, thanks! (also, got to love comment markdown ಠ_ಠ)

Answer (score 5):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 38 bytes

```powershell
"Min$(('ec','ce')[!(random 1e4)])raft"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X8k3M09FQ0M9NVldRz05VV0zWlGjKDEvJT9XwTDVRDNWsygxrUTp/38A)

Comment: I don't know Powershell, but 1000 is `1e4`, not `1e5`. Is that a mistake?

Comment: thanks. The rule is "The game Minecraft has a 1 in 10000 chance". `10000 == 1e5`  isn't it?

Comment: Sorry, typo in my original comment. I meant 10000, not 1000. However `10000 == 1e4`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EwzDVRPP/fwA "Python 3 – Try It Online") A helpful way to remember is that the number after the `1e` counts the zeros, not the digits

Comment: [Of course!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/3zDV5P9/AA "PowerShell – Try It Online")) I'm sorry. Fixed. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>62</s> 61 bytes

-1 byte thanks to [xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor)!

```python
from random import*
print'Min%sraft'%'ceec'[random()>1e-4::2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P60oP1ehKDEvBUhl5hbkF5VocRUUZeaVqPtm5qkWFyWmlairqienpiarR0OUaWjaGabqmlhZGcX@/w8A)

If a probability of \$\left({92 \over 256}\right)^9 \approx 0.0000999841\$ to print *Minceraft* is fine, 59 bytes is possible:

```python
import os
print'Min%sraft'%'ceec'[max(os.urandom(9))>91::2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/PzO3IL@oRCG/mKugKDOvRN03M0@1uCgxrURdVT05NTVZPTo3sUIjv1ivtCgxLyU/V8NSU9PO0tDKyij2P1iHgrqqnqFBmrqqhoalkZ6@kamZppaWpeZ/AA)

---

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 63 bytes

```python
from random import*
print'Min%xraft'%(236-30*0**randrange(1e4))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P60oP1ehKDEvBUhl5hbkF5VocRUUZeaVqPtm5qlWFCWmlairahgZm@kaG2gZaGmBlAJxeqqGYaqJpub//wA)

Comment: The CE/EC reversal is cute but it turns out shorter to just do a generic `[::2]` selector: [TIO](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P60oP1ehKDEvBUhl5hbkF5VocRUUZeaVqPtm5qkWFyWmlairqienpiarR0OUaWjaGabqmlhZGcX@/w8A "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Comment: instead of a `[::2]` selector, you can use 2 character precision `%.2s` which lets you shorten the string to `'cec'` for [-1 byte](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P60oP1ehKDEvBUhl5hbkF5VocRUUZeaVqPtm5qnqGRUXJaaVqKuqJ6cmq0dD1Glo2hmm6ppYxf7/DwA)

Answer (score 5):

## [V (vim)](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 80 bytes

```
iMin<Esc>:r!echo $RANDOM
C<c-r>=<c-r>"%10000
<esc>:s/^0\n/ce
:s/\d\+/ec
kgJAraft
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/P9M3M8/GtTjZzqpIMTU5I19BJcjRz8Xfl8vZJlm3yM4WTCqpGhoAAZdNKkhhsX6cQUyefnIqF5AZkxKjrZ@azJWd7uVYlJhW8v//f90yAA)

Generate a random no. in 0-9999, and then replace 0 with ce and anything else with ec.

Comment: `i<C-r>=rand()%10000<cr><esc>` is the random generator I came up with, doesn't work on TIO though sadly.

Comment: I think `rand()` needs a seed but I'm not too sure of it.

Answer (score 5):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>28</sup> 25 bytes

```
'Minecraft'120&A.~0=?@1e4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/pvqWhlGGumaGWprs6lpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/1X0z81KTixLTStQNjQzUHPXqDGztHQxTTf5rcqUmZ@QrpCkA9VOZ9R8A)

<sup>-3 thanks to Bubbler</sup>

*Note: J does not allow 0-argument functions, but this function ignores it's argument, which is the J equivalent*

To see this work, change `1e4` to `2` in the TIO, which will make the letter swap happen 50% of the time.

- `0=?@1e4` Does a random number between 0 and 9999 inclusive equal 0?  Returns `1` one in 10000 times.
- `120&A.` Transposes the requires letters.
- Conditional execution at rate according to step 1 happens as a result of the way `&` works when invoked dyadically.

### alternative 1, 27 bytes

```
4|.'raftMin','ec'|.~0=?@1e4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/pvqWhlGGumaGWprs6lpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/TWr01IsS00p8M/PUddRTk9Vr9OoMbO0dDFNN/mtypSZn5CukKair/wcA)

Rotate `|.` the string `'ec'` with probability 1/10k, then append it to the string `'raftMin`, then rotate the result by 4.

### alternative 2, 28 bytes

```
'Minecraft'C.~3<@,4#~0=?@1e4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/pvqWhlGGumaGWprs6lpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/1X0z81KTixLTStSd9eqMbRx0TJTrDGztHQxTTf5rcqUmZ@QrpCmoq/8HAA)

Comment: [25 bytes](https://tio.run/##y/pvqWhlGGumaGWprs6lpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/1X0z81KTixLTStQNjQzUHPXqDGztHQxTTf5rcqUmZ@QrpCkA9VOZ9R8A) for `120&A.` one.

Answer (score 5):

## [Swift](https://developer.apple.com/swift/), <s>55</s> 53 bytes

```swift
print(.random(in:1...1e4)<2 ?"Minceraft":"Minecraft")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky7PTCsx@f@/oCgzr0RDrygxLyU/VyMzz8pQT0/PMNVE08ZIwV7JNzMvObUoMa1EyQrETk0GszX//wcA)

This is also my first Code Golf post.

Thanks to [@Dingus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92901/dingus) for getting taking off 2 bytes!

Comment: Welcome to CGCC! [53 bytes](https://tio.run/##Ky7PTCsx@f@/oCgzr0RDrygxLyU/VyMzz8pQT0/PMNVE08ZIwV7JNzMvObUoMa1EyQrETk0GszX//wcA "Swift – Try It Online") with two small tweaks.

Comment: @Dingus Had no idea you could do `1e4`, thanks! Also the `<` is smart to remove the `==`.

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>19</s> 18 bytes

```
„ecтnиćRªΩ”–·ÿraft
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASkA1v9vc2FiaWX//@KAnmVj0YJu0LjEh1LCqs6p4oCd4oCTwrfDv3JhZnT//w)

[Run 10000 times](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W9oAARu/x81zEtNvtiUd2HHkfagQ6vOrXzUMPdRw@RD2w/vL0pMKwHKzz20Quc/AA)

```
„ec      push string "ec"
т        push 100
n        squared, 10000
и        repeat, push ["ec"]*10000
ć        head extract
R        reverse
ª        append
Ω        choose random element
”–·ÿraft push "Min" + tos + "raft", which is implicitly outputed
```

Comment: Minor alternative 18-byter: [`’£Ì³±’™4°иć„ecÂ‡ªΩ`](https://tio.run/##ATAAz/9vc2FiaWX//@KAmcKjw4zCs8Kx4oCZ4oSiNMKw0LjEh@KAnmVjw4LigKHCqs6p//8) EDIT: Oh, if I scroll down _Grimmy_ apparently found a 17-byter.

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, <s>48</s> <s>44</s> <s>43</s> 41 bytes

```
If[Random[]<.1^4,"Minceraft","Minecraft"]
```

Here's a simple unit test which found a bug in my first version.

```
Table[If[Random[]<.1^4,"Minceraft","Minecraft"], {ix, 10^6}] // Counts
```

And the result:

```
<|"Minecraft" -> 999909, "Minceraft" -> 91|>
```

Comment: Nice work.  To save 4 bytes, note that `Random[]` does the same thing as `RandomReal[]`;  it's been deprecated since v6 but it still works.

Comment: [41 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2Zl@98zLTooMS8lPzc61kbPMM5ER8k3My85tSgxrUQJzE5NBrNj/wcUZeaVODjnl@aVFEen1YUkJuWk1hkagEHsfwA) without the `<>`s.

Comment: @att, I thought I had tested that idea.  Obviously not.  It's very pleasing to me, that this version is shorter, and more readable.

Answer (score 4):

## [Befunge-93](https://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93), <s>100</s> <s>97</s> 81 bytes

```
"tfarec"v
77+:v>0#<
v*2\_v
?1v0:#
^#< ^-1\$#+
+55:$<  |`-1*:*:
>:#,_@ |<
^ "Min"<
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcE7CoAwDADQPacIjVOrYAURQlAv4A2k/qji4iCaybvX99a4v9cRUzLPvtxxMwpN41jbkgTUVuOk0HktmSCQYCj8mJEDV9ecCeI3F96yZWiZ8qnHTyCgGc7LSEo/)

Uses rejection sampling to generate a random integer between 0 and 9999 inclusive, and then swaps the letters if that number is 0.

I abused some coincidences that arose in my code to golf it.

Comment: is the null byte printed after "Minecraft" intentional?

Comment: @Razetime No, it wasn't. I fixed it and removed 3 bytes. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), <s>27</s> <s>20</s> 18 bytes

```
`↔ṅ`₴k2ṁċ[`ec`|`ce`]₴`r…ż`,
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJg4oaU4bmFYOKCtGsy4bmBxItbYGVjYHxgY2VgXeKCtGBy4oCmxbxgLCIsIiIsIiJd)

Edit: this is actually 7 less bytes, at only 20:

```
k2ṁ[`↓∑ġ¬`|`↔ṅ⇩ṡ…ż`]
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJrMuG5gVtg4oaT4oiRxKHCrGB8YOKGlOG5heKHqeG5oeKApsW8YF0iLCIiLCIiXQ==)

Edit 2: Thanks to [@emanresu A](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/100664/emanresu-a?tab=profile), this has been shortened to 18 bytes.

```
k2ṁ[`↓∑ġ¬`|`↔ṅ⇩ṡ…ż
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJrMuG5gVtg4oaT4oiRxKHCrGB8YOKGlOG5heKHqeG5oeKApsW8IiwiIiwiMTEiXQ==)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice first answer!

Comment: @TheThonnu Thanks, glad to finally be able to get an answer worth submitting to one of these.

Comment: Nice! You don't need the closing `]` or backtick.

Comment: @emanresuA forgot about that, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 43 bytes

```bash
x=(ce ec);echo Min${x[RANDOM%9999?1:0]}raft
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v8JWIzlVITVZ0zo1OSNfwTczT6W6IjrI0c/F31fVEgjsDa0MYmuLEtNK/v8HAA)

`RANDOM%9999` has a range of [0,9999], and in bash `0` evaluates to false, so the ternary works as expected. Supposedly, the `$RANDOM` function has an "[approximately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15939495/is-the-bash-function-random-supposed-to-have-an-uniform-distribution) linear distribution", but I haven't proved that with a million iterations. Hat-tip to the [Zsh solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224552/15940).

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, <s>51</s> 44 bytes

```js
_=>`Min${Math.random()*1e4>1?'ec':'ce'}raft`
```

[try it online](https://tio.run/##BcFRDkQwEADQy2zSlqyo@FrKCZyBSU0ZoSPV@Nk4e723wQ2XDXTGr@cZkzNpNN00kP/8B4hrEcDPfEiVaaw73Qu04icsiieAi1NyHCSZsqFWY9VQnivL/uIdi50X6aRS6QU)

That's a lotta bytes for such a simple task...

*-7 thanks to the OP*

Comment: 44 bytes: `_=>\`Min${Math.random()*1e5>1?'ec':'ce'}raft\`` - [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFBDoMgEADAz/QAGo008VJFX@Ab3A0udY1lDRIvxrfTmQ0vPF3kI1VBFsre5tkOMHF43ROmtY4YFvkpXRhqBzMCOfiAI3gi@gTZS1Rsm457Q@@Oy1I7CafsVO/yVV5pnf8 "JavaScript (Node.js) – Try It Online")

Comment: or  a=>\`Min${+new Date%10001?'ec':'ce'}raft\`;  but doesn't work consecutively

Comment: What's strange here is that someone still upvoted my answer even though I (accidentally) used 1e5 instead of the correct 1e4.

Comment: Why not `>1e-4` if you use `Math.random()`?

Comment: 41 bytes, using `Date.now()` (Like in my Python solution) `_=>"Min${Date.now()%1e4>1?'ec':'ce'}raft"`

Comment: @Alexbries I think the `+` is not necessary for that alternative since the `%` already causes a type coercion

Comment: @TimSeguine your right, then it should be 37 bytes  `_=>"Min${new Date%1e4?'ec':'ce'}raft"`

Comment: 37 bytes: 
_=>`Min${new Date%1e4?'ec':'ce'}raft`@Alex bries solution won't work, it needs backticks.

Comment: @mmaismma lose the `+`

Comment: @ophact It wasn't meant to be there, fixed now. Still 37 bytes cuz I had counted that without the +. It was a copy and paste mistake.

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>35</s> 34 bytes

```ruby
$><<"Min#{rand<1e-4?:ce: :ec}raft"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/X8XOxkbJNzNPubooMS/FxjBV18TeKjnVSsEqNbm2KDGtROn/fwA)

Thanks to Dingus for a saved byte.

Comment: If we consider `$$` as random number, then we can make it 1b shorter `$><<"Min#{$$%1e3<1?:ce: :ec}raft"`

Answer (score 3):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 59 bytes

```bash
printf "%0.sMinecraft\n" {0..9999}|sed '1s/ec/ce/'|shuf -n1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v6AoM68kTUFJ1UCv2DczLzW5KDGtJCZPSaHaQE/PEghqa4pTUxTUDYv1U5P1k1P11WuKM0rTFHTzDP//BwA)

Change 9999 to 1 to see it work with 50% probability.

Repeats the line "Minecraft" 10,000 times.  Changes the first line only to "Minceraft".  Shuffles the lines randomly and returns the first.

Comment: -1 byte: Replace `\n` to actual newline character. [Try It Online](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v6AoM68kTUFJ1UCv2DczLzW5KDGthEtJodpAT88SCGprilNTFNQNi/VTk/WTU/XVa4ozStMUdPMM//8HAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), <s>40</s> 38 bytes

```
1e-4 [ "Minceraft"] [ "Minecraft"] ifp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQnJ@blJmXCBQp1itKzEvJz1XIzFew/m@YqmuiEK2g5JuZl5xalJhWohQL5aYmQ7mZaQX/C4oy80r@AwA)

*-2 bytes thanks to @Bubbler!*

Factor has a version of `if` called `ifp` that calls either quotation depending on a probability.

There is also an interpolating version that is slightly longer:

```
1e4 random 1 < "ce""ec"? [I Min${}raftI]
```

Comment: You can omit spaces after closing `"` :)

Answer (score 3):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <s>40</s> <s>32</s> 29 bytes

```php
<?=Min,rand()%1e4?ec:ce,raft;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt7WNzNPpygxL0VDU9Uw1cQ@NdkqORUokFZi/f8/AA)

Not a bad score for good ol' PHP

Or even shorter if we allow plain text ouside of the PHP tags (Thanks to Tim Seguine)

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <s>33</s> <s>29</s> 28 bytes

```php
Min<?=rand()%1e4?ec:ce?>raft
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fNzPPxt62KDEvRUNT1TDVxD412So51d6uKDGt5P9/AA)

EDIT: saved another number of bytes by removing all quotes, inspired by another suggestion from Tim Seguine

EDIT 2: thanks again to Tim Seguine, now using `rand()%1e4` instead of `rand(0,1e4)` which is not even shorter but more accurate, (at least in TIO, so far as `getrandmax()` has a high value), and using `,` to remove the round brackets

Comment: isn't this 1 in 10001 instead of 1 in 10000 ?

Comment: @MarcMush yes, totally, like many other answers, including the currently most upvoted one. It's as the question states, "on average"..

Comment: To have an "exact random chance" to happen, we could just have `9999` instead of `1e4` for 1 byte more

Comment: If you move the tags around you can save 7 bytes: `Min<?=rand(0,1e4)?'ec':'ce'?>raft`

Comment: @TimSeguine Nice suggestion! I'm always a bit uneasy about having plain text outside of the php tags, as strictly speaking, the PHP is what's inside the tags, but it's worth mentioning ;)

Comment: @Kaddath Yeah I was unsure even to suggest it TBH. But at it's core PHP really is a template processing language, so I figure it is fair game to treat it like one since you can't really separate the two aspects.

Comment: @TimSeguine yeah PHP is a bit borderline as we are allowed to omit the `<?php` tag from the byte count, but not `<?=` as it is considered a shorthand of `echo`. It means we cannot really consider it as a language that have a implicit output, like many golfing languages have.. So I added both versions

Comment: By abusing some deprecated features and sacrificing some randomness you can knock it down to: `<?=@Min.(rand()%1e4?@ec:@ce).@raft;` or `Min<?=rand()%1e4?@ec:@ce?>raft`

Comment: @TimSeguine your comment about deprecated features inspired me, we can actually remove all quotes with the "assumed constant" trick. I'm not sure about `rand()%1e4` because `rand` without parameter [gets a value between 0 and getrandmax()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) which can vary depending on the system. On TIO I got 2147483647 for `getrandmax()` and that would be a bit off, I need to calculate the odds

Comment: Yeah, the at signs are only there to suppress the warnings for assumed constants. But if nobody cares about them then get rid of them. As an alternative to `rand()`, you can use `time()`, like some other answers have done. Although that is a different can of worms. Most of the answers here are playing pretty fast and loose with the interpretation of "random" and how exact the distribution actually has to be. With the mod trick there is going to be a slight skew of the odds on the order of 1/200000 which is smaller than the skew from not using the correct constant of 9999

Comment: I'll stop posting after this I swear: you can also remove the parens and dots by exploiting comma operators behavior wrt echo which coincidentally fixes the operator precedence issues that PHP's ternary operator has for this golf: `<?=Min,rand()%1e4?ec:ce,raft;` At this point it almost doesn't even look like real code anymore

Comment: @TimSeguine thanks for calculating for me, I'm in a kind of busy time right now.. I'll take your last version, If it doesn't look like real code anymore, it means that it's a good golfing :P but if you want to post as a separate answer, be sure I'll upvote it!

Comment: No I already had my fun collabing, and I don't really care about internet points.

Answer (score 3):

## Excel, <s>41</s> 40 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to MarcMush*

```
="Min"&IF(RAND()<0.1^4,"ce","ec")&"raft"
```

I tried typing 0.0001 as 1E-4 to save two bytes.  Excel changes it to 0.0001.

Answer (score 3):

## [Thue](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Thue), 100 bytes

```
A::=~Minecraft
B::=~Minceraft
10::=A
10::=1
12::=A
12::=A
12::=A
12::=A
12::=1
13::=B
::=
1000022223
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8koTf3/39HKyrbONzMvNbkoMa2EywnKTU4Fcw0NgHxHCGXIZWgE4eGkgEqMgZQTF5AAagICIyAw5vr/HwA) *NB: TIO's version of Thue requires a trailing newline. [Here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/thue) is one such interpreter that has no such restriction.* You can replace `1000022223` with `103` to convince yourself that a 50-50 chance works (although note again TIO's Thue interpreter seems to seed the RNG with the time in seconds, making quick, successive runs often have the same output). For more convincing, feel free to read my justification below.

### Explanation

(For this explanation, I shall substitute "Minecraft" with `x` and "Minceraft" with `y` for clarity.)

Outputting numbers with an arbitrary random chance isn't straightforward in Thue. We need to output `y` with a 1 in 10000 chance, and `x` otherwise. Thue's source of randomness is the way it chooses replacements to make: It samples the available valid substitutions and picks one at random to perform. We can bias the selection by increasing the number of substitutions we want to inflate. The naive approach would be to include 9999 replacements mapping to `x`, and 1 mapping to `y`, but this would be an inordinate amount of bytes.

Instead, we'll encode 1/10000 by simulating its prime factors: \$2^4\cdot5^4\$. We can pretty easily simulate a binary choice:

```
A::=~x
B::=~y
13::=B
10::=A
10::=1
::=
103
```

50% of the time, we'll replace `10` with `A`, immediately terminating further substitutions with `A`. The other 50% of the time, we'll replace it with `1`. When we reach `13`, we'll output `B`. We can generalize this quite easily, as inserting \$N\$ `0`s gives a \$\frac{1}{2^N}\$ chance to output `B`. This process can be thought of as moving the `1` forward along a strip of `0`s, with a 50% chance each time to terminate and output `x`. The `3` acts as the end of the road, allowing us to output `B`. The odds of it reaching the end are quite clearly \$\frac{1}{2^N}\$. Observe the following examples:

```
For 10->A, 10->1:
    103 = 50% / 50% (1/2)
    1003 = 75% / 25% (1/4)
    10003 = 87.5% / 12.5% (1/8)
    100003 = 93.75% / 6.25% (1/16)
```

In fact, we can simulate a \$\frac{1}{K^N}\$ chance by having \$K-1\$ copies of the replacement `10::=A`, and 1 copy of the replacement `10::=1`. For \$K=5\$, this gives an 80% chance at each step to terminate and output `x`, rather than the 50% chance in the previous example. Observe the following:

```
For (12->A)x4, 12->1
    123 = 80% / 20% (1/5)
    1223 = 96% / 4% (1/25)
    12223 = 99.2% / 0.8% (1/125)
    122223 = 99.84% / 0.16% (1/625)
```

Concatenating both yields `1000022223`, with a combined chance of \$\frac{1}{2^4}\cdot\frac{1}{5^4}=\frac{1}{10000}\$.

We can justify this to ourselves empirically. For N=1000000 trials, we would expected to see about `1000000/10000 == 100` instances of `y`. And, from one such trial:

```
x: 999892 (99.98%)
y: 108 (0.01%)
```

We can see this is quite convincingly the case.

### Alternative version, 102 bytes

```
A::=~Minecraft
B::=~Minceraft
013::=A
013::=13
12::=A
12::=A
12::=A
12::=A
12::=01
.13::=B
::=
.122223
```

This one generates the `0`s on the fly, exploiting the symmetry between the prime factors. It's unfortunately 2 bytes longer, as the more complicated behavior requires extra symbols.

### Metagolfer

For similar tasks, where one must output something with a 1/n chance, I've written a Ruby script that compiles a corresponding program. Of course, this works nicer for some numbers rather than others (a prime encoded by this approach requires lines equal to its value), so perhaps some ingenuity would be required for certain cases.

```ruby
if ARGV.empty?
    STDERR.puts "Insufficient arguments. Usage:"
    STDERR.puts "    #$0 n"
    exit 1
end
require 'prime'
$alphabet = "02456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

n = ARGV[0].to_i
comp = ""

puts "[COMMENT]::=Inserts B with 1/n probability, A otherwise."
Prime::prime_division(n).each_with_index { |(prime, count), i|
    (1..prime).each { |k|
        print "1#{$alphabet[i]}::="
        puts k == prime ? "1" : "A"
    }
    comp << $alphabet[i] * count
}
puts "13::=B"
puts "::="
puts "1#{comp}3"
```

Comment: I was about to post my own Thue answer before I saw this one, but this one beats it by more than half
Well done

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), <s>56</s> <s>50</s> 48 bytes

```javascript
print(`Min${1e4*Math.random()<2?"ce":"ec"}raft`)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/v6AoM69EI8E3M0@l2jDVRMs3sSRDrygxLyU/V0PTxsheKTlVyUopNVmptigxrSRB8/9/AA)

Credit to @caird for removing 2 bytes! (Took off a semicolon and changed `==5` to `<2`)

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833), and nice first answer! Be sure to check out our [Tips for golfing in Javascript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2682/tips-for-golfing-in-javascript) page for ways you can golf your program

Comment: [48 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/v6AoM69EI8E3M0@l2jDVRMs3sSRDrygxLyU/V0PTxsheKTlVyUopNVmptigxrSRB8/9/AA)

Comment: In what environment does `print()` do that? It doesn't work in Node or Firefox dev console for me?

Comment: It's V8 - Chrome console, for instance.

Answer (score 3):

## [Pxem](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Pxem), 0 bytes: content + 30 bytes: filename.

- Content is empty.
- Filename (escaped): `\144\144ceraft.!.r\001.z.s.sXXec.aMin.p`

### Algorithm

1. Push "ceraft".
2. Generate a random number between 0 to 9999.
3. Unless it is 1, fix the string "ceraft" with "ecraft".
4. Insert "Min" and print it.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVh9V6JMG/9/P8XIkgwBwhiWSVSu9rTed7nVtp02tQ4CloboDVgWen/1fa4ZMBX32fN0TjHzu17nepmXnsOnX58/l919y96z3W6xV9wpO3va7q5dcrTdUq9r9TRHK@olrVQipU@hGyHFnRiToRU@I00rFg13Oh4FETqrPVTPzsyagaO3sYse3cge@b18ns3s0XBo@Y54qDrui@pPPA8VD/Mkn0@FL6rXX02OxykfUsYLBYwk8jH9SJV5MlDm3MLsj2bj9uH7dd0satrOArz49r1xe/bzofbt6uqkdm0So4U4Pv5S/f714ebk6nvjW7Mivc05ZKI31Mnn2apGaDwK@9NkJn1JRO7@h4Q7nHhW5KLwifGPxhEMX0eBE469fpTPW17fCpHyiAQ@JhLHH3NzwRToV8jnmz/OzmrndbPCbGBqzzHCp34vMtgYUb4UcO2nEeI/i9QyoZZzYKg48pzDPIT@xfIQl0M9ywtdbjZbpTHVTHo6C10HCaE6Vd9UI4Q/76rAFL6jDhViXMCzELWxiEeQhKqPlJdoQmZRgJRaiNotTdnvIKHV9rc7wuwxcMeokChX7/VdXo0rVYPvGk1DbftsfgHm7guFtq@qRrdqzJNp657qIaTIq2PViFbBsraJEUJ4dZQB9/Y3MUJA2s8yljcxopV4tZ9l3NnE9oHvIYuBZTuD7e5tYoSAcJhd384mRgi4@JJl3N3EiAYR62Xd1jYxokHE3KyP@5sYITqvBlnTxU2MEJB@zTLubWKkCP5Ms4zlTYwUwce3LOP@JkaK4M97NgnabzBwx8ouurSJEQKxjbKW9U2MaODOMBvvvU2MaOCOkzVd3sR0SL@UxcBFJYPtAF8ui4HXfBYDZ7YoNhdm2LbS7cIR06Zk/arGp7Qpp4YD/XdKpdu40BbbuO3Tv4Xttsir7Z12sU1U4ArVwjZ063S9vyueweditfU6fXu3nI6ai5tG1wOFc@MNml1FqqG27lMqLXFeRY66pkPxkZCab90fyx2wCx7gVjIEF4rHiLrwlPIkOCpsA4l5lliH9YyZm7wqU7QLLkCKY5jl4hBGVXVsdC8BTdjkY1Dwweh8MDpqfcG4xragpHGoBAYfJ@aOEVUNWxzjRtUFElVZaPlcEyhtv4WU9862Q7VFwQoCS2Lx6SSLVRnJArYxy2myOCuRmoO3lcsPlQXmW3SZ2XPTeHyFyNSrEJdpmlwW2WXckvicpprYb@JK4kma9d8JCmhxdKwkRO33sGd1Xc80uTbhxJitBLfGI7//YIcvPTeIhlKO31I6lLtNsGiojwkPrcd2TOT2nJIucJukNGvVpXDSxRxNCCdT6SMYcxXumJOZWXGeGlzn/xNznVe7gWs9swnkrYo5bzQaI38UoaEV2U99/5EDVmGxXAmLahcTkfmmsImSznJspiUTHib/LCZbbELZoBlZIwq9UZDGCjwyDDEWjI8uFeaCKP76T7N6fmIKbaLr9Nd2A6sXFXKFoK1ppPBeCAvh7a1rF6zzvl8YC59q35rXJ81rUxA@4XHQ96MenPNMCZ@SuNmrjRRbhJP8VxjYpvDl5LTRjCFrUui6jhgGcMPCbDjvTXw76o98dIHrYvy99Sz/jcWOWTdg2JGkJf0Ei3HgRpPARzkJeJaUv5YUwA/JkvL3kkLVLQnXawRqUiEr5Ft8JcZXJnAxNxTFSJmvljwTXBNjtn5UW6Kn@Eq@@9ANN0iv77uH2hGvVZQVx74mBnhisMq5Z2UpQQFxnLgGoQTaNP@Dmp/45ortKj5feHQ@4yDLEH96S@1HaMX0GJb@@tT3XJyDkIqj1UjCJAZwNpvgW6AtCT5uyDdyXfZEmkUmGN@YwGN4puf6j9ETvhENWmsNuOo2DkzPECcY101YSxgF@EZuSJJMRPFfjq2LO6pLermil8T50kgfrF/g0zXDD/hcrsl38k8xPje5wkMFNaFjLOS4dn8IV09YrPvoBvAdTyLOqJkgbtyBD9QXWu7grr53UMvnawelssh60ACs9i93r7d2Sh0eto87U9eVWiqctCmw4HIiRnQISM00d4pinLDAqyDq@xN3TiNOWWsHehl4Dkt7IoUS40uziWbxp4l/iqim6GWDZs@4wHfbP1fWai@if4Gv14IQLgi3q8l6gZwM5BsxbpgaszgwWR1D@Ae0bOWBonTMG5ooOmt0GAh56LD5oLMS@mBpGiKKWX@K27QGVgy@Lptm05spvpSZrRy0I41wDmaXrERuzMsDypvK3iyF3v4odPh7ofcPN6gUc0NZcyVaLOYJetdcIw2B9AzFguDRdIEpfYXYxRYENCnxv2iFX2DrCMQli0aicptGxFjuGNsmUYrb2DrQxG2aM/iuBPWfrL5B2jG36WLxYNsToWLADFfYgjOjANXIVdCdG8AVqv/SD0ENRwuFJsU6Ghx6R4Mtr@JtDSpsrLIx5Gie7LDgmal1oBzgnZfZm7mZLXLC0rkeRGKN62Pv3nx3/eHZZSbnVXJJgDsYnF/0@asE/jOZ2RMYOQISkNIrLg42uNNc4LxI338r7rismJMDM4bCZQX9LEmGJA0OMN2EadFCyJPwD9IpDETj98ugy3Vcz4UnMuQZWiHdnqBBJKlxAOISSVqCnTQNplEi0CfJpi8l885cMOhJRf83ALcoG7H/H0xoh4yG9DUMYLABLmPo6Ehp6msMsxkew8u8Cs/9viO7UX/oymN7PJFfwnfDgTe9uJoD/c9vXxRZfQ9utvpKgOntOi7TGw67Rwkz6/UZdCHLVIpE39PLO7t6GQmxJZm8Nj9p1tNTw4L7APfp/85/qjWNDv1wkAA48DlGEngNrmfww6EwSQ/mtkaczGuiMJtawSPEoDFFaeamn9Cv/wI)

Answer (score 3):

## [PPL 1.0.10](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ppl-lang), 108 bytes

```js
importRandom
declarex=Random.random()*10000
ifx>1{
printLine("Minecraft")
}
ifx<=1{
printLine("Minceraft")
}
```

This **must** use v1.0.10 because imports were introduced. This reuses the "mash together tokens" that emerged as a product of my sloppy lexer writing.

## Commented

*note, comments do not exist in PPL*

```js
importRandom           // import the module `Random`, one of three standard libraries
declarex=              // declare variable `x`
Random.random()        // set to pseudo-random number between 0 and 1 (`random` property)
*                      // ... times...
10000                  // 10000 (no 1e4)
ifx>1{                 // if x is greater than 1 then
printLine("Minecraft") // print "Minecraft" to STDOUT
}                      // closing code block
ifx<=1{                // no "else" in PPL, so use opposite condition instead
printLine("Minceraft") // print "Minceraft" to STDOUT
}                      // closing code block
```

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3, <s>87</s> <s>77</s> 73 bytes

Kinda noob solution. Just using random and then substituting with %s.

```
import random;print("min%sraft"%"ec"if random.randint(1,1e4)<1e4else"ce")
```

Comment: Got it down to [67 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEoMS8lP9e6oCgzr0RDKTczT7W4KDGtRElVKTk1NVkpGiKvB6JAKgx1DFNNNO0MrayMYjX//wcA)

Comment: Impressive! I forgot that you could do that with python :)

Answer (score 3):

## x86-64 Machine Code, Microsoft Calling Convention, 33 bytes

Works by checking if 32 bits of the time stamp are less than `2^32/10000`. Technically, it's about 1 in 9999.994, but it should be close enough. The functions would have a signature of:

```
extern "C" void minceraft(char* out);
```

but the output is not null terminated.

```
0F 31                            rdtsc  
3D B8 8D 06 00                   cmp         eax,68DB8h  
48 B8 65 63 72 61 66 4D 69 6E    mov         rax,6E694D6661726365h  
77 02                            ja          minecraft  
86 C4                            xchg        al,ah  
minecraft:
48 C1 C0 18                      rol         rax,18h  
48 89 01                         mov         qword ptr [rcx],rax  
C6 41 08 74                      mov         byte ptr [rcx+8],74h  
C3                               ret
```

An alternative, also 33 bytes:

```
48 B8 4D 69 6E 65 63 72 61 66    mov         rax,66617263656E694Dh  
48 89 01                         mov         qword ptr [rcx],rax  
C6 41 08 74                      mov         byte ptr [rcx+8],74h  
0F 31                            rdtsc  
3D B8 8D 06 00                   cmp         eax,68DB8h  
77 06                            ja          minecraft  
66 C7 41 03 63 65                mov         word ptr [rcx+3],6563h  
minecraft:
C3                               ret
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `Ṫ`, <del>27</del> 16 bytes

```
‛↔ṅ‛cek2ʁ℅ßṘ`r…ż
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyLhuaoiLCIiLCLigJvihpThuYXigJtjZWsyyoHihIXDn+G5mGBy4oCmxbwiLCIiLCIiXQ==)

Comment: Niice! A couple of ways you can golf this down: [decrementing instead of >1](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyLhuaoiLCIiLCJgTWluYGsy4oSF4oC5W2BlY2B8YGNlYF1gcmFmdGAiLCIiLCIiXQ==) saves a byte, dictionary compression saves a bit more, you can save even more by conditionally reversing `ce`, and... I'ma just go all the way and give you [this 16 bytes](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyLhuaoiLCIiLCLigJvihpThuYXigJtjZWsy4oSF4oC5w5/huZhgcuKApsW8IiwiIiwiIl0=)

Comment: @emanresuA Thanks. You misspelled Niice, by the way.

Comment: @emanresuA By default, `℅` casts numbers to the range `[0..n]`, which means that this is actually using a 1/10001 chance. Normally, you would be able to fix that by using a flag, but that doesn't seem to be working for that command atm. However, once it gets fixed, you can use flags to get the range generation to `[0..n)`, at which point you can remove the decrement for 15 bytes.

Comment: @AaroneousMiller [Here's a patched version](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyLhuaoiLCIiLCLigJvihpThuYXigJtjZWsyyoHihIXDn+G5mGBy4oCmxbwiLCIiLCIiXQ==)

Answer (score 3):

## Bash, <s>58</s> <s>57</s> 54 bytes

```bash
s=ec;[ `shuf -n1 -i0-9999` = 0 ]&&s=ce;echo Min$s\raft
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v9g2Ndk6WiGhOKM0TUE3z1BBN9NA1xIIEhRsFQwUYtXUim2TU61TkzPyFXwz81SKY4oS00r@/wcA)

Comment: [48 bytes](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v9g2NdlaQyMhK79EQbdIwVDBQMESCBI0NWtqim2TU61TkzPyFXwz81SKY4oS00r@/wcA) using arithmetic evaluation `(())` which automatically tests if the result is `0`, and `jot` instead of `shuf`.

Comment: [42 bytes](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/v9g2NdlaQyPI0c/F31fVEgg0NWtqim2TU61TkzPyFXwz81SKY4oS00r@/wcA) using `RANDOM%9999`, equalling my other bash solution

Answer (score 3):

## [Rattle](https://github.com/DRH001/Rattle), 43 bytes

```
Min&e&c&raft&1e4|I<b0=?~%~[0b2b1][^0b1b2]b3
```

[Try it Online!](http://www.drh001.com/rattle/?flags=&code=Min%26e%26c%26raft%261e4%7CI%3Cb0%3D%3F%7E%25%7E%5B0b2b1%5D%5B%5E0b1b2%5Db3&inputs=)

### Explanation

```
Min&e&c&raft&1e4|            passes ["Min", "e", "c", "raft", 10000] as hard-coded input
  I                          parse input, place into consecutive memory slots 
                                 and move pointer to next free slot
   <                         move pointer left (to the slot with 10000)
    b0                       add item in slot 0 to print buffer ("Min")
      =?~                    set the top of the stack to a random integer value 
                                 from 0 to the value in storage at the pointer (10000)
         %~                  set the top of the stack to the result of 
                                 this random value mod 10000
           [0    ]           if the result is 0...
             b2b1            add the values in slots 2 then 1 to print buffer ("ce")
                  [^0    ]   if the value is not 0...
                     b1b2    add the values in slots 1 then 2 to print buffer ("ec")
                          b3 add "raft" to print buffer and print implicitly
```

Want to test this but don't want to run the code 10000 times? Try replacing "1e4" with "4".

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>25</s> <s>24</s> <s>23</s> 21 bytes

```
’£Ì³±’™D„ecÂ:‚тnLΩΘè™
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcPMQ4sP9xzafGgjkPmoZZHLo4Z5qcmHm6weNcy62JTnc27luRmHVwAl/v8HAA)

I am once again grateful for Kevin's [string compressor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/78850) for providing me with the compressed strings.

### Explained (old)

```
.•2žéhαP”·úεÕŸ•#тnLΩ1Qè™
.•2žéhαP”·úεÕŸ•#         # the list ["minecraft", "minceraft"]
                тnLΩ1Qè  # indexed at the position (random.randint(1, 100 ** 2) == 1)
                       ™ # title cased
```

Comment: You can push the same list with [`’£Ì³±’™D„ecÂ:‚`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcPMQ4sP9xzafGgjkPmoZZHLo4Z5qcmHm6weNcz6/x8A). Or the happier version: `’£Ì³±’™D„ecÂ:)`.

Comment: And `Θ` is a shorthand for `1Q`.

Comment: [You don't need the second `™`](https://tio.run/##ATEAzv9vc2FiaWX//@KAmcKjw4zCs8Kx4oCZ4oSiROKAnmVjw4I64oCa0YJuTM6pzpjDqP//)

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language](https://www.wolfram.com/language/), <s>50</s> <s>47</s> 42 bytes

Thanks to [MarkMush](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/98541/marcmush) for -1 byte and [Michael Seifert](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/70768/michael-seifert) for -4 bytes

```
If[Random[]<.1^4,"Minceraft","Minecraft"]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73zMtOigxLyU/NzrWRs8wzkRHyTczLzm1KDGtRAnMTk0Gs2PV/gcUZeaVRKdFx8b@BwA)

Unfortunately, joining strings doesn't help to shorten this at all; the following is one byte longer:

```
"Min"<>If[Random[]<.1^4,"ce","ec"]<>"raft"&
```

Previous solution:

```
RandomChoice[{9999,1}->{"Minecraft","Minceraft"}]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7PygxLyU/1zkjPzM5NbraEgh0DGt17aqVfDPzUpOLEtNKlHRA7ORUMLs2Vu1/QFFmXkl0WnRs7H8A)

Comment: If you're OK with deprecated functions, `Random[]` does the same thing as `RandomReal[]` and saves you four bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia](http://julialang.org/), 41 bytes

```julia
print(:Min,rand()<1e-4 ? :ce : :ec,:raft)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPifll@kkKmQmadgaGVoYPC/oCgzr0TDyjczT6coMS9FQ9PGMFXXSMFewSo5VcFKwSo1WceqKDGtRBOiMidPQ5MrNS/lPwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 55 bytes

```cs
()=>$"Min{(new Random().Next(0,9999)>0?"ec":"ce")}raft"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7BCsIwEETvfsWyCE1QSzzamnooelIPIniUGrcl0G6gSVEQv72mF@f85s0YvzLejoeBzdaH3nJTQA16FFIXczxZ/gimF1wqfrpOyPRM7yDUchMjC7VDMpihIZTfvqoDjvmsdOxdS@mtt4GOlkng1YWqhSTaDE2YT8AyrJVKlFJgqrb1GSAsYM9DF4lHrMfFhuLShMXItHQDB3EHHQ8KCVoD/oUoZT7@AA)

Comment: Exactly the same length without interpolation.
(I like interpolation too. I was just surprised by the tie.)
()=>new Random().Next(0,9999)>0?"Minecraft":"Minceraft"

Comment: @MerkleGroot I didn't even consider that idea as I was sure it would be longer, but surprisingly it's exactly the same! Guess I overcomplicated it a bit haha

Answer (score 2):

## [Scratch](https://scratch.mit.edu/), 71 bytes

```
define
say[Minecraft
if<(pick random(0)to(9999))=[0]>then
say[Minceraft
```

Uses [scratchblocks](https://scratchblocks.github.io/) syntax.

Comment: but then wouldn't this say minecraft **and** minceraft one in 10000 times? I believe only `Minceraft` should be outputted in that case

Comment: @ophact The "say" block makes the sprite display the specified text in a speech bubble, overriding the previously displayed text. Only `Minceraft` would appear.

Answer (score 2):

## [Raku](http://raku.org/), 31 bytes

```
{"Min{<ce ec>[rand>1e-4]}raft"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/Wsk3M6/aJjlVITXZLrooMS/FzjBV1yS2tigxrUSp9n@aXnFipUJafpFCnKGB9X8A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia](https://julialang.org/), 39 bytes

```
f()="Min$(rand()<1e-4 ? :ce : :ec)raft"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/P01D01bJNzNPRaMoMS9FQ9PGMFXXRMFeQSk5VUnBSkEpNVlJsygxrUTpf7pGhaaCrUJxaa4GSBNYV3IqWE4hLb9IId7W0KpCU7@CK13DSMsw1VxTocZOoaAoM68kJ@8/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), <s>54</s> 53 bytes

-1 thanks to caird coinheringaahing

```cs
_=>$"Min{(new Random().Next(10000)<1?"ce":"ec")}raft"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY4xC8IwFIR3f8XjITRBLXW1TR1EJ3UQwbHU@FoC6Qs0KQrib69RwVtuufvutF9ob8bdwLrwoTfczn9WQgNqrFQ5xYPhp2C6w6nmm@uETI/0CGKZRcliuUZNuELSKF993QQc88nGsXeW0ktvAu0Nk8CzC7WFJMI0fWI@AcMQIUnEgK6t9StAmMGWhy4mrrEeB1sS2Ry@W5lMN27gICpQ8Z7gwVoJSgH@oShlPr4B)

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833), and nice first answer! Be sure to check out our [Tips for golfing in C#](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/173/tips-for-code-golfing-in-c) page for ways you can golf your program. You can assume an [unused input](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12681/are-we-allowed-to-use-empty-input-we-wont-use-when-no-input-is-asked-regarding), so can change `()` to `_` for -1 byte

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Those posts are super helpful

Answer (score 2):

## Perl -M5.010, 31 bytes

```
say"Min${time%1E4?\ec:\ce}raft"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/784sVLJNzNPpbokMzdV1dDVxD4mNdkqJjm1tigxrUTp//9/@QUlmfl5xf91fU31DAwNAA)

Prints "Minecraft" when run during a 2h 46m 39s window (9999 seconds), and "Minceraft" during a 1 second window. This takes advantage of the fact the challenge just stays "on average 1 in 10000 times", without mentioning a distribution.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2/3, 58 bytes

```
from random import*;choice(["Minec"]*9999+["Mince"])+"raft"
```

No idea whether the result has to be printed, so...

+ 6 bytes in Python 2 if print necessary

```
from random import*;print choice(["Minec"]*9999+["Mince"])+"raft"
```

and + 7 bytes in Python 3

```
from random import*;print(choice(["Minec"]*9999+["Mince"])+"raft")
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 45 bytes

```java
e->Math.random()<1e-4?"Minceraft":"Minecraft"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU49D4IwEN35FRemMkBi4iR@zAxMJi7G4SwFi6WQ9iAhht9eCxj1Lfdyd@@jxgHjung6rtBayFFqeAUBeEhNwpTIBWR@BR@cyUhdAXadGtmllQUMUbpcp1XW9XclOVhC8mOYPxrvylbh9QZoKhv9OWYg4QBOxMcc6ZEY1EXbsGi/EfH2FOZSc2GwpHA3c8EX7tJfodGSaJK2p6TzCaQ0k8laT/dKRd92k3sD)

Answer (score 2):

## [Troll](http://hjemmesider.diku.dk/%7Etorbenm/Troll/), 40 bytes

Prints *Minceraft* if throwing a 10000-sided die(!?) results in a 1.

```
if1=d10000then"Minceraft"else"Minecraft"
```

[Try it online!](https://topps.diku.dk/torbenm/troll.msp?noOfDice=1&userExp=if1%3Dd10000then%22Minceraft%22else%22Minecraft%22) (<kbd>Make random rolls.</kbd> produces a single output, <kbd>Calculate probabilities.</kbd> shows the probability of each possible output)

Sadly a lot less things are possible with strings rather than integers, otherwise this would be possible:

```
"Mince"U9999#"Minec"pick1||"raft"
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python, <del>73</del> 71 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to @cairdcoinheringgaahing

```python
from random import*
print("Minec%sraft"%("e"if randint(1,1e4)<1else""))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P60oP1ehKDEvBUhl5hbkF5VocRUUZeaVaCj5ZualJqsWFyWmlSipaiilKmWmgVWCJA11DFNNNG0MU3OKU5WUNDX//wcA)

Explanation:

The first line imports everything from the `random` module. `randint(1,1e4)` chooses a random number from 1 to 10000 if it is 1, print `Mineceraft`. If not, print `Minecraft`

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833), and nice first answer! You can remove the space after the `,`, you can change the `==1` to `<2`, and be sure to check out our [Tips for golfing in Python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54/tips-for-golfing-in-python) page for ways you can golf your program

Answer (score 2):

## [Silicon](https://github.com/m654z/Silicon), <s>28</s> 23 bytes

-5 bytes thanks to @ovs

```
"Min""ec"Ôs~={R}"raft"â
```

**Explanation**

```
"Min""ec"Ôs~={R}"raft"â

"Min""ec"                 - Push "Min" and "ec"
         Ôs               - Push 100 and square it
           ~=             - Pick a random number between 0 and 10000, then
                            check if it's equal to the previous stack item
             {R}          - If true, reverse the topmost stack item ("ec")
                "raft"    - Push "raft"
                      â   - Join stack
<implicit>                - Implicit output
```

**<s>28 bytes</s>**

```
"Min"ÔÔ*~={"ce},{"ec}"raft"â
```

First code golf challenge in 5 years! It's good to be back.

Silicon uses the CP037 code page.

Comment: I think `"Min""ec"Ôs~=(R)"raft"â` works for 23

Comment: @ovs Outgolfed in my own language! Thank you haha :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Braingolf](https://github.com/dylanrenwick/braingolf), 25 bytes

```
"Minec"v%*rc?:,|"raft"&@;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLz89J@/9fyTczLzVZqUxVqyjZ3kqnRqkoMa1ESc3B@v9/AA)

#### Explanation

```
"Minec"                     - Push "Minec" to stack
       v                    - Switch to next stack
        %                   - Niladic modulus, push 100
         *                  - Monadic multiplication, square top of stack (10000)
          r                 - Pop top of stack and generate random integer 0 <= n < x where x is popped val
           c                - Collapse stack to main stack
            ?: |            - Pop top of stack, if 0...
              ,               - ...swap top 2 items on stack ('e' and 'c')
                "raft"      - Push rest of string
                      &@    - Print entire stack as ASCII
                        ;   - Prevent implicit output
```

When and only when the generated random number is 0, this will output `Minceraft`, otherwise it will output `Minecraft`.

Braingolf's `r` instruction uses Python3's `random.randrange` function, which to my knowledge should be sufficiently uniform for this challenge, and takes an exclusive maximum, meaning calling `r` on `10000` is equivalent to `random.randrange(10000)`, which generates a number `x` where `0 <= x < 10000`.
This leads to a 1/10000 chance of generating a 0, and thus a 1/10000 chance of outputting `Minceraft`

Answer (score 2):

## [APOL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/APOL), 39 bytes

`+("Min" +(¿(!(∿(õ)) "ce" "ec") "raft"))`

Comment: 30 bytes: `+(Min +(¿(~(ö) ec ce) "raft"))`

Comment: @AaroneousMiller That's good, but keep in mind my interpreter doesn't ofccically support strings w/o quotes.

Comment: In that case, `+("Min" +(¿(~(ö) "ec" "ce") "raft"))` should work for 36 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## Rust, 87 bytes

```rust
print!("Min{}raft",if (rand::random::<u16>()as f32/6.5535).ceil()==1.{"ce"}else{"ec"})
```

Scales the 0-65,535 to be from 1-10,000 and checks if the result is 1.

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b3fc4d9f9e44994f8d8ac18fef3a8f80)

Answer (score 2):

## T-SQL, 44 bytes

```sql
PRINT'MIN'+IIF(RAND()<1E-4,'CE','EC')+'RAFT'
```

Notes:

- `PRINT` saves one character over `SELECT`
- To easily validate the code, replace `1E-4` (1/10,000) with `1E-1` (1/10), and run it a few dozen times; it should be quick to demonstrate it works as expected.
- `RAND()<1E-4` is one character shorter than my original version, `1E4*RAND()<1`.

Answer (score 2):

## Kotlin, <s>67</s> 81 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y84vycnM@/@/oCgzr0RDKTczT6U6M00jGyysV5SYl5KfqxcEofJSK0pCPYHKNFUNDQwMDEvtLIGgVFMpOVVJITWnOFVBKTVZqbYoMa1ESfP/fwA)

```kotlin
print("min${if(kotlin.random.Random.nextUInt()%10001u>9999u)"ce" else "ec"}raft")
```

or this if import's are allowed, which is 67 bytes in this context:

```kotlin
print("min${if(Random.nextUInt()%10001u>9999u)"ce" else "ec"}raft")
```

explanation for the code:

```
if(Random.nextUInt()%10001u>9999u)"ce" else "ec"
```

`Random.nextUInt()` Returns a random Kotlin `UINT` Number, the `%` (modulo operator) is to make it be within the ranges of `0, n`, 10000 in this case, i could have used `1e4` to accomplish it but it would be a `double` and it would need conversion, which just adds extra bytes, if the expression is true, "ce" would be used, which is the odd possibility, also since it starts from 0 and not 1, the possible combinations inbetween 0, 10001 is 100000, `2%2` is 0 and not 2 for example, and since `>9999u` can only be 1 smaller than 10000, which the > compansates for, also it is the same as == 10000u, it is for saving bytes.

Proof:

```kotlin
        var count = mutableListOf<Int>()
        for(z in 0..10)
        {
            count.add(z, 0)
            for(i in 0..100000000)
            {
                if(Random.nextUInt()%10001u>9999u) count[z] += 1
            }
        }
        var avg = 0
        for(i in count.indices)
        {
            avg += count[i]
        }
        avg /= count.size
        println("ratio: ${100000000f / avg}, normal ratio: ${10000/1f}")
```

> ratio: 9995.003, normal ratio: 10000.0

Comment: Welcome to code-golf, nice first answer! It would be nice to place a link to an online interpreter, so anyone can test your submission, eg. here: https://tio.run/#kotlin, like other answers usually do. Also, I'm not familiar with Kotlin, but it may be of use to check this [tips question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/126464/tips-for-golfing-in-kotlin).

Comment: thanks! i added the interpreter link however i'm not sure whether i need to include the imports, implement the main class etc

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript 37 bytes

```
$=>`Min${new Date%1e4?"ec":"ce"}raft`
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno) `KJ`, \$ 27 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 22.22 bytes

```
"raft""ceec"ZlZ4RZw0>AI"Min
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_WbSSt5dS7IKlpSVpuha7lYoS00qUlJJTU5OVonKiTIKiyg3sHD2VfDPzICqgChdAaQA)

Replace `Z4` with a small number like `4` if you want to test it.

##### Explanation

```python
"raft" # Push "raft"
"ceec" # Push "ceec"
Zl     # Uninterleave to get ["ce", "ec"]
Z4R    # Push range(10**4)
Zw     # Pop and push a random element
0>     # Is it greater than 0?
AI     # Index into the list ["ce", "ec"]
"Min  "# Push the string "Min"
       # The flags join the stack
       # (which is reversed in Thunno,
       # so "Min" is actually the first item)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 17 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ʋẠĿ&⁺9ṗk2ɼḅṇŒ×iJḟ
```

Port of Grimmy's 05AB1E answer.

### [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 18 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
k2Lɼ?ʋẠĿ&⁺ḟ:ʋẠṬĠȤḟ
```

Alternatively:

```
k2ɼḅ‘ẠĿ&⁺ ẠṬĠȤ‘Oiḟ
```

Port of caird coinheringaahing's Jelly (fork) answer.

##### Explanation

```python
ʋẠĿ&⁺9ṗk2ɼḅṇŒ×iJḟ   # Full program
ʋẠĿ&⁺               # Push dictionary compressed string "MineCraft"
     9ṗ             # Permutations of the above with length 9
       k2ɼ          # Push a random number in the range [1..10000]
          ḅ         # 1 if it equals 1, 0 otherwise
           ṇŒ       # Push codepage compressed integer 120
             ×      # Multiply these together
              i     # Index into the list of permutations
               J    # Join the resulting list into a string
                ḟ   # And title case this string
                    # Implicit output
```

```python
k2Lɼ?ʋẠĿ&⁺ḟ:ʋẠṬĠȤḟ  # Full program
k2                  # Constant for 10000
  Lɼ                # Push a random number in the range [0..9999]
    ?               # If it's truthy (non-zero):
     ʋẠĿ&⁺          #  Push dictionary compressed string "MineCraft"
          ḟ         #  And title case it to get "Minecraft"
           :        # Otherwise:
            ʋẠṬĠȤ   #  Push dictionary compressed string "MinceRaft"
                 ḟ  #  And title case it to get "Minceraft"
                    # Implicit output
```

```python
k2ɼḅ‘ẠĿ&⁺ ẠṬĠȤ‘Oiḟ  # Full program
k2ɼ                 # Push a random number in the range [1..10000]
   ḅ                # 1 if it equals 1, 0 otherwise
    ‘ẠĿ&⁺ ẠṬĠȤ‘     # Push dictionary compressed string "minecraft minceraft"
               Oi   # Split on spaces and index into the list
                 ḟ  # Title case the resulting string
                    # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), `R`, 21 bytes, Courtesy of Lyxal and ManishKundu

```
«ɽL3Gp↵¢¨Π°ꜝ«½k2℅1=iǐ
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=R&code=%C2%AB%C9%BDL3Gp%E2%86%B5%C2%A2%C2%A8%CE%A0%C2%B0%EA%9C%9D%C2%AB%C2%BDk2%E2%84%851%3Di%C7%90&inputs=&header=&footer=)

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 30 bytes

```
`Min`k2ʀ℅1>[`ec`|`ce`]+`raft`+
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%60Min%60k2%CA%80%E2%84%851%3E%5B%60ec%60%7C%60ce%60%5D%2B%60raft%60%2B&inputs=&header=&footer=)

<s>Well someone help me to compress these strings....</s> no no don't compress, compressing this yield larger strings....

Comment: I think you can just push the strings to the stack and use the `s` flag to concatenate them, so you can remove the `+`s

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing i have tried that way earlier but it didn't work

Comment: I think that might be a bug then. If you remove the `+`s and just add a `W` though, you can get [29 bytes](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=s&code=%60Min%60k2%CA%80%E2%84%851%3E%5B%60ec%60%7C%60ce%60%5D%60raft%60W&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Comment: [how about 22 bytes?](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=s&code=%E2%80%9B%E2%86%94%E1%B9%85%C2%AB%E2%88%A7%E2%82%80F%C2%AB%C2%BDk2%CA%80%E2%84%851%3Ei%C2%AB%C2%AC%C8%AE%E2%86%B5%C2%ABW&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Comment: [or this for 21 bytes?](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=R&code=%C2%AB%C9%BDL3Gp%E2%86%B5%C2%A2%C2%A8%CE%A0%C2%B0%EA%9C%9D%C2%AB%C2%BDk2%E2%84%851%3Di%C7%90&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Comment: I swear this is the last one: [19 bytes](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=R&code=%60%E2%86%93%E2%88%91%C4%A1%C2%AC%E2%86%94%E1%B9%85%E2%87%A9%E1%B9%A1%E2%80%A6%C5%BC%60%C2%BDk2%E2%84%851%3Di&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Comment: [proper 18 byter](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=R&code=%60%E2%86%94%E1%B9%85%E2%87%A9%E1%B9%A1%E2%80%A6%C5%BC%E2%86%93%E2%88%91%C4%A1%C2%AC%60%C2%BDk2%E2%84%85%C2%B1i&inputs=&header=&footer=)

Comment: Note that the 18 byte answer also requires the `m` flag

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 25 bytes

The code snippet below seems to bug out on the compressed nonprintable chars, please see the link for the correct string.

```
"ec"                  // U = string constant
`M  {MqL²Ä ?U:Uw}ft`
    {           }     // Insert
           ?U:Uw      // either U or U reversed depending on whether
     Mq               // a random number in range
       L²Ä            // [0, 10001) is truthy or not
`M               ft`  // into a compressed string
```

[Try it here.](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=ImVjIgpgTYh7TXFMssQgP1U6VXd9n2Z0YA==&input=)

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 25 bytes

A port of Jonah's [great J answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/224383/95792).

```apl
{4⌽'raftMin','ce'⌽⍨×?1e4}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkG/9OAZLXJo5696kWJaSW@mXnqOurJqepAgUe9Kw5PtzdMNan9/19bv1odKJecClKk/qhzYdqj3jW1h1Y86t1saJpqovCod65CcEZ@aU6KQnFGfrlCaYFCYlJ@aYmCoalCSWZuajEA)

### My previous answer, 30 bytes

```apl
{'Min','raft',⍨2↑'cec'↓⍨×?1e4}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkG/9OAZLW6b2aeuo56UWJaibrOo94VRo/aJqonpyarP2qbDOQenm5vmGpS@/@/tj5YaXIqWOWjzoVpj3rX1B5a8ah3s6FpqonCo965CsEZ@aU5KQrFGfnlCqUFColJ@aUlCoamCiWZuanFAA)

A dfn whose argument doesn't matter. Requires 0-indexing.

```apl
{'Min','raft',⍨2↑'cec'↓⍨×?1e4}
                          ?1e4 ⍝ Random number in range [0, 10000)
                         ×     ⍝ Signum (0 if 0, 1 if >0)
                  'cec'↓⍨      ⍝ Drop those many elements from 'cec'
                               ⍝ 1 in 1e4 chance of not dropping the first 'c'
                2↑             ⍝ Keep only the first 2 characters
       'raft',⍨                ⍝ Prepend to 'raft'
 'Min',                        ⍝ Append to 'Min'
```

Comment: You might be able to save some bytes with one of my J approaches.  The APL translations are typically shorter than the J, which is 27/28 here.

Answer (score 1):

## [F# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 70 bytes

```fs
fun _->"Min"+(if System.Random().Next(9999)=1 then"ce"else"ec")+"raft"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyvWTc4vSv3/P600TyFe107JNzNPSVsjM00huLK4JDVXLygxLyU/V0NTzy@1okTDEgg0bQ0VSjJS85SSU5VSc4qBRLKSprZSUWJaidL//wA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 44 bytes

```
Str("Min",if(random%10000,"ec","ce"),"raft")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/j/P7ikSEPJNzNPSSczTaMoMS8lP1fV0AAIdJRSk5V0lJJTlTR1lIoS00qUNP8XFGXmlWiQokXzPwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [CSASM v2.4.0.1](https://github.com/absoluteAquarian/CSASM/releases/tag/v2.4.0.1), 110 bytes

```
func main:
push 10000
extern Random.Next(i32)
brtrue a
push "Minceraft"
br b
.lbl a
push "Minecraft"
.lbl b
print
ret
end
```

`extern Random.Next(i32)` calls `Random.Next(int)` on a `System.Random` object
Therefore, it will return a value in \$[0, 10000)\$
Non-zero integers are truthy in CSASM, so the `brtrue` instruction will be successful \$1/10000\$ of the time

Answer (score 1):

## [Batch](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands), 55 bytes

```
@if %RANDOM% LEQ 3 (echo Mincecraft)else echo Minecraft
```

(No TIO link because TIO does not support batch.)

`%RANDOM%` returns a random integer between 0 and 32767, and the `if` statement checks to see if it is less than or equal to 3. There are 4 integers between 0 and 3 inclusive, and a \$4 \over 32768\$ chance is *just slightly* better than 1 in 10000.

---

## Exactly 1 in 10000 odds, 72 bytes

```
@set/a r=%RANDOM%%%10000
@if %r%==1 (echo Mincecraft)else echo Minecraft
```

Comment: It would be nice to also see how many bytes you'd need in BATCH to get *exactly* 1 in 10000...

Comment: Q: is r equal to a random integer between 0 and 32767, modulo 10000?  If so, surely the chance of getting '1' is still 4 in 32767 (with r values of 1, 10001, 20001 and 30001)?  Or don't I understand BATCH properly...?

Comment: You're right about four values returning 1, but the odds are better now because there are also four values that return 2, four values that return 3, four values that return 4, etc.

Comment: 4/32768=1/8192, or 18% better than 1/10000.

Answer (score 1):

## Bash (pure Bash, 54 bytes)

```
[ $[RANDOM % 10000] = 0 ]&&s=ce||s=ec;echo Min${s}raft
```

Since `echo` always returns 0, this kind of condition works.

Comment: 53 bytes: `s=ec;[ $[RANDOM % 10000] = 0 ]&&s=ce;echo Min${s}raft`

Comment: 42 bytes [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifll@koKGRaWtonWljaAAE1tramZqa1tVc/xNtNZJTFVKTNa1TkzPyFXwz81SqE6ODHP1c/H1VwWrtDGJrixLTSv7X/gcA "Bash – Try It Online")

Comment: `$RANDOM` is between 0 and 32767, so the odds are 4/32768 or 1/8192 rather than 1/10000.

Answer (score 1):

## TI-Basic, 38 bytes

```
"ec
If rand<ᴇ-4
"ce
"Min"+Ans+"raft
```

Ti-Basic is a [tokenized language](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4764/98541), I used what my TI-83+ says (48-10=38)

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 59 bytes

```
import time;print(f'Min{"ecce"[time.time()%1e4<1::2]}raft')
```

Basically combining a few other suggestions here (although I did mostly work it out myself anyway). It took a while to realize that using `from time import*` actually costs a byte overall.

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833), and nice first answer!

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia](http://julialang.org/), 35 bytes

```julia
"Min$(rand()<1e-4 ? :ce : :ec)raft"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPhfUJSZV5KTp/FfyTczT0WjKDEvRUPTxjBV10TBXsEqOVXBSsEqNVmzKDGtROm/5n8A)

Comment: this is a full program, so you have to include println in the code.

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 52 bytes

```lua
print(1<math.random(1e4)and'Minecraft'or'Minceraft')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/J@WX6SQaWuoY2gABAop@f8LijLzSjQMbXITSzL0ihLzUvJzNQxTTTSBLHXfzLzU5KLEtBL1/CIQJzkVzNH8n5qX8h8A)

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833), and nice first answer! Be sure to check out our [Tips for golfing in Lua](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/24392/66833) page for ways you can golf your program

Answer (score 1):

## [Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/), 71 bytes

```
import'dart:math';f()=>"Min${Random().nextInt(10000)<1?'ce':'ec'}raft";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYy7CoAwDABn@xkipFlEV@tjdnDxD4Kt2KFRSgah@O21tx0cZylKzj48dxSwRYZAcoE5NU5zvXlu0k5s76CxZffKyqL7roBjv8DhYAB3wBfplNrkQJ41JlU90ZewTNCoL/8)

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript, 59 bytes

```js
console.log(`Min${['ec','ce'][+(Math.random()<1e-4)]}raft`)
```

One less thanks to @ophact !

Comment: minus 1 byte by removing the zero: `+(Math.random()<1e-4)`

Comment: And where did you get that 47 byte figure?

Comment: @ophact The text inside the console.log is 47 bytes length. Wasn't sure of how to count there, console.log is not really part of the solution :)

Answer (score 1):

## [BRASCA](https://github.com/sjoerdpennings/brasca), 21 bytes

```
`Minec`HH*{?0=#$`raft`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zVt7V9y2Ev9/P4UKbdkNu7Dk0SRcllxI0hvaEnKAnvYeDjXatZZ1aluOLbNw0varpzPyYy1bu5bDk3PagC3N/OapkTQOrsSE@09eBOEXxwt4KEh0FXWJR8WkNQ65R4TjMZK9chkLksch9W34J32Bf8F/56yVPhAhHbEhHf3Zao1cGkVkN6TRiL7G3zdbBH6WlpaOBAzokpCdO5FgYUSACrmgoUOHLotggBxoszGxLMd3hGW1I@aOO5st@QJ/liUNOTEnk7/EwWuRHDAgJ6fqcwrP@uqjofJoxmMnZGTKgAG1Hf@csAsWgtbwVxqR0YSCrMj3VZlxCEMsj9sM6P5I3YgVcH9wAmb3HJ/YVND8sTMmPpcmgOnAbM2JqBBX7c5mPqRAHwZYOB3Iz2YgynbnZHOzt3GqTBrzkFhdYhFgyvzYYyEVrF0iVWKkYYb2imJXIFP1zQmy7FaelnGollmjQcB8u81Du50Q7nTy4Qx0Vic5eMlMq@8oOlFqnCFjPgnACILZ5IqJkn2oi6q6srIRVRsdT5yITB3XJZHg4AMUfhMTRoZg8D@ZIAGPHOFwv@Rx04njMsvlPIiA6Oe/FYqMjNAh0GGRVMCReagSwBFW@qbqpaPEoYpyy@cQea4zgigB2@bC6EcIHqjiLn@IowmBiUPgKLiEJs2TR2AAA6xkgPSZLo4ueEvVovi@SP2CujEjfDyLGOSk4YLvUx7460Im6DZyUGe@IEMuBKQq4LxQLCsZVyed40csFO1@MqReQCMEOEPlP1/yGYCq8GBXmZ1LLHiQJc5yosnJqmEWMhGHfsHzqpGYDikAQzZJ7JbQ1KqAB0Xh7wBmP9PYEYQxAsoWjxxTxISVPUxNkv2p4suekgHEJF3SpCuapcqZghKs5dlD3exhdXbB54rYV6LUBbUBjMnupiRSQjCRsaOXu99U3CrpYUevlH5qwkNcjyOmFVm@KTtVgU82opPTkt6CpFzmn4uJ3mGTd2W6qavBy/aMRSE0YxcWXElNrhAEVwjigj5Iu7xudHJWw9hx7eRhmZ9gXqAWNvjEgrpDqTnUl7AwuuxTzAVTrIPFQbacQfLhnocrVLVSwMWnVCOAWSukt0m/WkhURvUGZEMZJX2kinMwn1pJ1jKwTBB0t5OlZNVV5qUT9eQzN8wU06mCLTI4bcQAvCPEIkoyUjPDvGriRM45hUkZovop2UicJacvlmFlqVbTx2HM6m07II8XczprbI7isAoIU/o4sZ586k0t3IMcXUHG8ggNzyESfAHbl0DumbAMhC3NWnBFxmRrDCr3qce2q29HZAvDZrvVOuYQT7i5gdAexuddEkPeGtvrIww14EJtzDfj9dEaDo1cPiU2n/qExyKIRTo8Wh9FEpiD@yLkaVlSYsvyKNTFVmrCBAAYorD1Sp0sxZZXkktfzvYdn43O3r179PlVf7D87VlIx@LsS7pRS1IY2cVclCRHTF0eDYrUipkqy3pkHxDJ0fLvJO8VuOdV7pZMm4U3xTwXXqkWy81cJHWiIXtazgfpGGVrNtfnKg@WiVxztyAlbqu164K009dEVEFrxbq6X00BFbfeMCe3YUDusTm5xwbknpiTe2JA7qk5uacG5J6Zk3tmQO4Hc3I/GJB7bk7uuQG5F@bkXhiQe2lO7qUBObeBG5uExS8N6Jl4HmsQFybGfdsgMEwCzW4QGSbmfdPAl01iY9LAXUy8@V0TfzFxmJ8bETSh@Hlpkyy/YaOQYZlgSjx7hAVgzyRj/41s9vxrsFk1YRMiG7ncHcpzXR0fOluB9QWsBGMyCLcfDm435CFye9glFFDqLTRHQqfTqi7YUoBktYeyaULDWsFXzlYWOoZ6qquthY2K6rIU8tCrppxZ3TjtLCKkVFSruLmqamSf4qY2wC0dLxyVz8W@in6wY9u37AA6l12lBn7aQ3xH8RAvHMQ9gOyZgHyEIPdjVziBe3UPIB@ZgFxPEotg5@A9tnPhRLoN5u2DXV83QfudVCm3Y5ffA8bvTCD@gRDfXgbcn5eob9nqRmaPZAB9Cq@DsMoc7w/XxrDxS3@NgEGbdjq6JL3riKkDO9sGWekfBP3@4PhGMf9joq7vZT58/@Ye7Pm9Cb6/EN/B4T3A@8sEnoXwfr8XfH8APo33HWk38RXgFIEH8sidz46xdxaWCsUrBCBgoJ6hlsuuOZehCZcdySW7nTETRr0@MJNmV89ntwEfI3m6yCc9yp9zKKNwyM78awlvImE7xltTeXQPovDxAg5fm3nodUZWUP9HRT27eTMFnl3GmaLKxtMbmFCRxkNpPH6hqh/jIyGiZZncg32VMTJskoQBvv0cX0nR8houPfisx9dU58b4ghr9EV@2@ER6v/B47AvTHZw/28H1u8nUBXs4YxvdjJ0@1NjpAelhsS9c0x9eyWSZdG@lfRL93sbj56Z@l7d6tWGfWT5X6BgA@CZf42ZXrLVJW3OWkV7CmrD8FllGUxpIQ4spJ45gXkS4f@1kfusZf2gg36G0KRfZIiUmIWN3K@Po1hUxuo7KtPc5FT0eoR5H3Md108@VCe6SEI7u3k8wxiKBIq3iP9Qows7LYsx3gLSHANmsrKx95I4v2fmdWSLLD76wm2F@0hthmoNkUkh9hSu9dHb9iV4T5SB4A3U4qTqg7BMEiDgOpvw097V7uvNxRahumqKVbghFrvliAZRk8vaAPH2RNrji31sD8uz5/HnKiSOwOJFI8BJfTgfQ9XLvFeWetcQlGmiv3pncfVXsl18tNUBu1Yt9KctfB4iEdn3JvtDvKrR/L9I2KaxNFvUKlxi5/Or3jrQkfdMyRPbvJNHc7CQdkoFtkmd@TXGez8VZzCmXSU65rOSUVp0bqE1ONy2m5kxgb/3AwNG4PGqRrRnYCL5z9HpvL214rPO6WStCpQt5bjtCSZRq@7L2MgJ/5JD2aKJeA3W6ENb2YGXFwNIHc0U1CYL7lzYPviZC@6rQaQZ9uAYuGreBmO/ni/lQjasx7ExgTTy/5r4IuUt@dPm0XiFbqJBfWBRBHU1v@wYE1bdFGyWuDT0lZqLqpu1G26iL/4F5ZDf73ahj@@GqYyCvdD7F4NZ3oIjB4MFqYuX/K6CJXSamjPkPYWuJ@sLqcoT/e7gO9F90oGMWeg5uzFo3kxTx4y926QiT2nIZAUA@tGVXMHXJx9gLahK71DrqtV@rj2oLQi2ij4joJ0CB1dwUCuuoSY@D2j9Tz@2nnBt@ndiMXU9lt2rA7gTZ/YZtrz3ZM1ttwa6qO6l5v8Gid@EGS9kp9TZOayw0T6pcqGLbeG0zrVba05K0sCTflqzbtyqqiSe9XtzVU/ocz6xT6NiQZvIBn6TZUncuyecqUoogZPJAJsq/XMWvI9N2qGrzvL43Wt8vv3yMX7o4AkrDMZlOmA9bfA6MQxlVwgGbAtsx7N7tmv7oZv1W6hctOZoDZC17COS5siNa5sm80oSVgit1KizvyyuU7PvN8nebRimQXY5YIMjP7GrIIfFgr00YxoEofQZVzebpxLfyH0jbaMiSOMtH3GPJd69T5gsyDbl/3sWTYD4F4xDgxFW4SSm99Pbw8OBwk@iml@5ekwn5l91rkK49KiwAVz6EL4iQfAewlzpu@iVDq@nGYTZWCQHwMc0OY@E97zWOKulgYRWiwYihr8dY3azSuj3bHOL6AJ3RplWyWnKpPqvkFojdWOR6cZuLOldM/PnyLw)

### Explanation

```
`Minec`                 - Push "Minec"
       HH*{?            - Push a random number between 0-9999 (inclusive)
            0=#$        - If 0, swap the top two stack items (the "e" and "c"), else skip
                `raft`  - Push "raft"
<implicit>              - Output the string
```

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 44 bytes

```javascript
e=>`Min${Math.random()<1e-4?'ce':'ec'}raft`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/V1i5ByTczT6XaN7EkQ68oMS8lP1dD08YwVdfEXj05Vd1KPTVZvbYoMa0k4X9yfl5xfk6qXk5@ukaahqbmfwA)

Edit : port of Java answer from : jadeFalk

Comment: Why's there a `"` near the start? It's not meant to be there, and you can save a byte by removing i.

Comment: @emanresuA : sorry for late reply(very late) , removed `"` and not sure about `i` ?

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 16 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
ùMin♫╢♂a*├x▌w╕rß
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ASoA1f9tYXRoZ29sZv//w7lNaW7imavilaLimYJhKuKUnHjilox34pWVcsOf//8) or [output 10,000 space-delimited results at once](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/2jm6ur/h3f6ZuYBWY@mLno0sylR69GUORWPpvWUP5o6tejw/P8K/wE).

**Explanation:**

```python
ùMin              # Push string "Min"
    ♫             # Push 10000
     ╢♂           # Push compressed string "ec"
       a          # Wrap it in a list: ["ec"]
    ♫   *         # Repeat it the 10000 amount of times: ["ec","ec","ec",...]
         ├        # Pop and push the first item (without popping the list): "ec"
          x       # Reverse it: "ce"
           ▌      # Prepend it back to the list: ["ce","ec","ec",...]
            w     # Pop and push a random item from this list
             ╕rß  # Push compressed string "raft"
                  # (after which the entire stack joined together is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), <sub><s>47</s></sub> 40 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/mlochbaum/BQN/blob/946df11216a89db2d03ebf476c789462eeb92e2e/commentary/sbcs.bqn)</sup>

<sup>-7 bytes thanks to DLosc</sup>

```
"Min"∾"raft"∾˜⌽⍟(0=•rand.Range 10⋆4)"ec"
```

[Try it!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=Ik1pbiLiiL4icmFmdCLiiL7LnOKMveKNnygwPeKAonJhbmQuUmFuZ2UgMTDii4Y0KSJlYyI=)

### Explanation

```
"Min"∾"raft"∾˜⌽⍟(0=•rand.Range 10⋆4)"ec"
              ⌽⍟(0=•rand.Range 10⋆4)"ec"  - If rand(0,9999)==0, reverse "ec"
"Min"∾"raft"∾˜                            - Join it to "Min" and "raft"
```

Comment: [40 bytes](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=Ik1pbiLiiL4icmFmdCLiiL7LnOKMveKNnygwPeKAonJhbmQuUmFuZ2UgMTDii4Y0KSJlYyI=)

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/) 107 bytes#

```
use rand::Rng;fn main(){println!("Min{}raft",if rand::thread_rng().gen_range(0..10000)==0{"ce"}else{"ec"})}
```

There's unfortunately no try online option as this solution does require the use of crates.

Pretty straight forward though, it generates a random integer between 0-999 inclusively and then if it is 0 it fills in "ce" instead of "ec" into the string template.

Answer (score 1):

## Snap! (scratchblocks3 syntax), 73 bytes

```
when gf clicked
if(pick random(0)to(9999
say[Minecraft
else
say[Minceraft
```

The number `0` is falsy in Snap!, and all positive numbers are truthy.

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 24 bytes

```
"Minec"e!1e3mrHG?="raft"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/X8k3My81WSlV0TDVOLfIw93eVqkoMa1E6f9/AA)

```
code
-------------------------|--------
"Minec"e!1e3mrHG?="raft" |
                ?        | If...
         1e3mr           | a random number 0-9999
                         | is not zero..
              H  =       | Get the index 16 in...
       e!                | all permutations of...
"Minec"                  | string literal "Minec"
                         | else...
                G        | Get index 15
                  "raft" | Push 'raft'
```

Index 16 in the permutations is "Minec", index 15 is "Mince".

Answer (score 1):

## C (GCC), 48 bytes

```c
f(){printf("Min%sraft",rand()%10000?"ec":"ce");}
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NQ7O6oCgzryRNQ8k3M0@1uCgxrURJpygxL0VDU9XQAAjslVKTlayUklOVNK1r/@cmZuZpaHJVcylAQTFYbUlmbqqGgaamNVwcaLI1V@1/AA)

62 bytes solution where the chance is exactly 1/10000:

```c
i;f(){while(i=rand(),i>9999);printf("Min%sraft",i?"ec":"ce");}
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/TOk1Ds7o8IzMnVSPTtigxL0VDUyfTzhIINK0LijLzStI0lHwz81SLixLTSpR0Mu2VUpOVrJSSU5U0rWv/5yZm5mloclVzKUBBMdiIkszcVA0DTU1ruDjQFmuu2v8A)

Comment: A few of the other solutions (like the top rated one, a Minecraft solution) has an almost 1/10k chance but it's actually something like 1/10000.001 or something so I suspect using rand%10000 would be legal

Comment: @TsumikiMiniwa Okay, thanks! I'll change the post :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 70 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcyxCsIwEIDhPU9xdEoGC4JT0UFwdVGcxCFNr@UkvZTkikrps8cWHb9/@JOz3mbqhxAF0opyFPLlxXITeqVC/UQncLbEMCmABlvoF2gbu1TBMUb7uV8lEncPU8GNSeAAUx6WIp41tZrxBb@dNiXjW05hrD1qs9/iZmeKM7FDF20rBfqEq/80GWBWc/4C)

```scala
println(if(new Random().nextDouble()<1e-4)"Mincecraft"else"Minecraft")
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <strike>71</strike> 66 bytes

-5 bytes thanks to Unrelated String

```python
from random import*
print(f"Min{'ecce'[randint(1,1e4)<2::2]}raft")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P60oP1ehKDEvBUhl5hbkF5VocRUUZeaVaKQp@WbmVaunJienqkeDVIAEDXUMU000bYysrIxia4sS00qUNP//BwA)

Comment: [66?](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P60oP1ehKDEvBUhl5hbkF5VocRUUZeaVaKQp@WbmVaunJienqkeDVIAEDXUMU000bYysrIxia4sS00qUNP//BwA)

Comment: -3 Bytes:  [TIO](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P60oP1ehKDEvBUhl5hbkF5VocRUUZeaVaKQp@WbmVaunJienqkdDVGho2him6ppYWRnF1hYlppUoaf7/DwA) proof of working: [Another TIO](https://tio.run/##JczBCgIhEAbgu08x7GW1CNbqJPkIPUF0WNyxPOwog4ERPbutNpcfhv//0js/I51q9RxX4JmWLcKaIuedWNCDl8oIYMwvJvDDNdBnROdwvP3LUl00Hs7GHO9fnn0earGT8JEhQKAmPlDqqV@TQietbRK6vti@UPZWi8SBsiyq/gA)

Answer (score 1):

## C++, 150 bytes

```
#include<iostream>#include<ctime>
int main(){srand(time(NULL));int a=rand()%10000+1;if(a==5432){std::cout<<"minceraft";}else{std::cout<<"minecraft";}}
```

Comment: [100 bytes](https://tio.run/##Sy4o0E1PTv7/XzkzLzmnNCXVJimzpFi/uCQlWVtbL8OOKzOvRCE3MTNPQ7O6uCgxL0WjJDM3VcNAU9MaqMbKKjm/tMTGRik3M08JSCWnJhclppUoaWuAlWqqGhoAgaKtqYmxoaZ17f//AA "C++ (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## Python, 70 Bytes

```python
from random import*;print(randrange(0,1e4)and'Minecraft'or'Minceraft')
```

[Try it onlien!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P60oP1ehKDEvBUhl5hbkF5VoWRcUZeaVaIAEgTg9VcNAxzDVRBPIVffNzEtNLkpMK1HPLwJxklPBHM3//wE)

Answer (score 0):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), <s>38</s>  <s>33</s>  <s>31</s> 30 bytes

```
"Min"10000rand"ec""ce"if"raft"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/X8k3M0/J0AAIihLzUpRSk5WUklOVMtOUihLTSpT@/wcA)

```
"Min"10000rand"ec""ce"if"raft" | whole program                   | Stack:
"Min"                          | push "Min"                      | "Min" 
     10000rand                 | generate a random number 0-9999 | "Min"<0-9999>
                      if       | If it is truthy.... (non-zero): | "Min"
              "ec"             | Push "ec". Else:                | 
                  "ce"         | Push "ce"                       |
                        "raft" | Push "raft"                     | "Min"<ec/ce>"raft"
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 46 bytes

```arturo
$[]->~«min|(2>random 1 1e4)?->"ce"->"ec"|raft
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?Bj88wT)