# Is This Scrabble Board Valid?

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem, game

##### Background

[*Scrabble*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrabble) is a word game in which players collaboratively build a board consisting of letter tiles that spell words. Each word must be connected to another word, and players gain points based on the letters they use and where they are placed. Words can be spelled either from left-to-right or top-to-bottom, and their validity is determined via the Scrabble Dictionary. Each contiguous set of more than one letter in a row or column must be a valid word.

##### The Challenge

Your challenge is to write a function that accepts a 2D grid of letters and determines whether or not it consitutes a valid Scrabble board. A board is valid if every word in every column and row is a valid word according to [this text file containing a Scrabble Dictionary](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/redbo/scrabble/master/dictionary.txt).

Your function should take a 2D grid of characters and a list of valid words as input. The board is assumed to be contiguous (every word is connected to the board) and padded with spaces to be rectangular. Your function must return a truthy value of your choice if the board is valid, and a falsey one otherwise. The board is assumed to contain at least 2 letters. This is [Code Golf,](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest answer wins, and the usual rules/loopholes apply.

##### Test Cases

All boards' validity is determined according to [this list of Scrabble words.](https://scrabble.hasbro.com/en-us/tools)

Valid boards:

```
MAP   
O APP
NEW O
T EEL
HAD E
```

---

```
DANCING 
  A     
  SEEING
  A    O 
  LAZY T
```

---

```
SORDID   
O U      
LEEWAY   
E        
L        
YESTERDAY
       A
```

Invalid boards:

```
MOLAR
A    
RATS 
CR   
HC   
 H
```

---

```
RASCAL
A     
BAKING
B   OO
ISLAND
T
```

---

```
JOYFUL 
  OFFER
```

Comment: how does our function get the dictionary?

Comment: @thejonymyster "Your function should take the list of valid words as input".

Comment: I suggest moving the link of the example dictionary down to the Test Cases section and wording as "should take a list of valid words and 2D grid...".

Comment: @JonathanAllan The end of the first paragraph states *"Each contiguous set of more than one letter in a row or column must be a valid word."* This sounds to me as if a single letter is not considered a word. Which probably means a input grid containing a single character is supposed to be valid, though IMO it would be nicer if we can assume the input contains at least one word.

Comment: @JonathanAllan that would never be an input because *"The board is assumed to be contiguous"*

Comment: Do we only need to check that all the words are valid, or also that they could have been played?  For instance, do we need to detect words that require playing more than 7 letters in a turn, or that use letters which are no longer available in the bag.  And how is the blank tile represented in the input?

Comment: Words longer than 7 can be done if a continuous part is already a word, too

Comment: @TobySpeight You only need to check that each word is in the dictionary.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>12</s> 9 bytes

-3 bytes thanks to Jonathan Allan

A dyadic function taking a list of lines on the left and a list of words on the right.

```
Z;⁸KḲḊƇfƑ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZExcsMgEEX7nGI7Gt0g1VqsLMUYNIBGgzUq4yLjC6RMmsykyynSpEqlPjO@h30RhQUpDoXe18KH5fP0eDo9z/Ph/voy7S7T92V6P78dzx/zz@f19Wueh0HssQUQhTCAbRupqQcT6YFIRdYogcRY3A1Coi4bveXVAAg8knREsXyrmlxWeAjgs9UZKxsJy0kdrGZF1GPImgBu9X86kPNkJYa0axoIedu9UWhjGZelFr1jljb/1@XSY81MFouuRLV6eHKDu9z@hnvnuzdOoZYpBPgzPphQdSpfzVQVWTGO8yBQFCAwfzlAWGNimSIEsTWeEaNkcC6J6e6s4hskGO1rFhodJmN8DEaLPSVraxQxbZewBh9VnFAhK06a1S238Rc)

```
Z;⁸         -- concatenate list of columns and list of rows
   KḲ       -- join on spaces and split on spaces to get list of words
      Ƈ     -- keep words that are truthy (non-empty)
     Ḋ      --   when the first character is removed
         Ƒ  -- is this resulting word list invariant when
        f   --   all words not in the dictionary are removed?
```

Comment: Isn't this 9 characters, but *17 bytes*?

Answer (score 7):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <sup><s>60</s></sup> 57 bytes

```ruby
->b,d{(b+b.transpose).all?{|c|d==d|c.join.scan(/\w\w+/)}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PZJbT8JAEIXf51fMk6UBy7tJNSNdBF27TVtCqvLQCwYMFEJVYqy/HXeGSx96Tqc7nTNfuvsqfg7v/uH6tuhVv52iW3ifu7xutptm7nr5anX325Zt5ftVW3ofm2XtNWVed/pv@7d9t@/@/R2@89Wy8l/BeaYIEQxSFEGopmggRaU0jChA5fQAnIDCwTh8QEAk5MuaRClbOleMNZpeMkylITFxMA5QPjvBY4tWakoZO4V4rl1cppJUxQFlcKoQOjADWNaSE33kpEZTDDIQYkoThEHMfjSQTCN7l/ExJQPScMp6T0@c9J5jGhgnmsLArojn048mG060LIVmOFSxDJaRDpHTQ8eSYTlhYGv5sDyYlMWSYmEAorIpO4tWxITpiE1ICUmj5cwS0VRJa2S0Yo0nIke44uwLnR0dM2V3YeXMoCN4uidMrjfPywVWG2yL1u5T2CUKb7Ws5423zredq5tysVlv3ctDvmtce26L76/2P5rBvK4O/w)

Takes the board as a list of lists of characters. Returns `true` for valid boards, `false` otherwise.

The board is valid if for every word on the board, the union of that word with the dictionary is equal to the dictionary.

Comment: [57 bytes](https://tio.run/##PZJbT8JAEIXf51fMk6UBy7tJNSNdBF27TVtCqvLQCwYMFEJVYqy/HXeGSx96Tqc7nTNfuvsqfg7v/uH6tuhVv52iW3ifu7xutptm7nr5anX325Zt5ftVW3ofm2XtNWVed/pv@7d9t@/@/R2@89Wy8l/BeaYIEQxSFEGopmggRaU0jChA5fQAnIDCwTh8QEAk5MuaRClbOleMNZpeMkylITFxMA5QPjvBY4tWakoZO4V4rl1cppJUxQFlcKoQOjADWNaSE33kpEZTDDIQYkoThEHMfjSQTCN7l/ExJQPScMp6T0@c9J5jGhgnmsLArojn048mG060LIVmOFSxDJaRDpHTQ8eSYTlhYGv5sDyYlMWSYmEAorIpO4tWxITpiE1ICUmj5cwS0VRJa2S0Yo0nIke44uwLnR0dM2V3YeXMoCN4uidMrjfPywVWG2yL1u5T2CUKb7Ws5423zredq5tysVlv3ctDvmtce26L76/2P5rBvK4O/w)

Comment: @dingledooper Thanks, was just editing exactly that in!

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <sup><s>138</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>86</s></sup> 79 bytes

```python
lambda b,d:all(i in d+[*s]for s in[*map(''.join,zip(*b))]+b for i in s.split())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVJhb9owEP2eX3HKF8fUq9Z2UqVKmeQSU9hCjJIgxNJ8ABLUrBQi7KpdEb@d5ewQEVl5zz4/vzv76n/6Zbe9O63959Nm8bYsFrBkxcNis/EqqLZQXGU9la93e1DNNOu9LWqPkOu/u2rLvqra6y0pza@WgDuMQF2relNpj9LTx25fKD8jnDAg3P4nE4SAR/1R9IRUiBDhSaYIQx4ghPzP3KAQM27YmBvhWEbpEEnEE26EkZghTPhMGOlEhgIxnhpIhGiNkiYQzi2Lg5HZPBdJKuKgscgdXSqtwAcvcxszAJeBK6FJGEnjAhJJCk3CSJpMQbg5g8xtqzEKAA74WW7dL9al5VgfpFZts4Gz4RQ6va2@nQiAi8jlpCvCnm0@NLPHj2XIY4zw8/6Yp4kh/bhdGfbPGQ87XcyTPg87oQk/8t9tOY9YiylmlIQ8CuzVQKf@JeeDadjeghwMROzm1Ck/63KlywJv@YaBHd/toM7qpVy9lnsMkuf32/sfK3wiZDd3hDrYYZqV2GPYeOa5GJyPpA8OuuMDrj3NTOtRs1Tvq6321uSgj/DtJxzUEQ6tVVb6vsqPhJ7@Aw)

*Saved a whopping <s>27</s> 33 bytes thanks to [Bubbler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78410/bubbler)!!!*
*Saved 7 bytes thanks to [Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53748/jonathan-allan)!!!*
*TIO testing now works thanks to [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs) and [Bubbler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78410/bubbler)!!!*

Inputs the boards as a list of strings (space padded so they're all the same length) and the dictionary as a list of strings.
Returns `True` for a valid board or `False` otherwise.

Comment: [86](https://tinyurl.com/m26v8waf) using `zip(*b)` (also added ovs's dictionary to actually check the test cases)

Comment: [80](https://tinyurl.com/32dcbhtj) using set difference.

Comment: [79](https://tinyurl.com/habxxkxp) using Bubbler's 86 and using the lines themselves as the "acceptable" one letter words.

Comment: @Bubbler Wow, that's super sweet - thanks! :D

Comment: @JonathanAllan Very nice - thanks! :D

Answer (score 3):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 8 bytes

Basically the same as my Jelly answer, but Gaia has a superset builtin.

```
:t+ṡṡḥ⁇⊃
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYwxCsIwGEZ3T5FBcFBw95t@zE9bSJPQRErcOoh09wLiUPEWgvYMuvYm9iIxgQcfHw/eueu7GHeX9e/7zHze83WYH7e4WWE7jafptZzGebjHmqwQMIKsheZWGHjBrFCSFLwgUCIpSXpf6QJZFcZnDUXHAMXcUkDKoDbal9DkSOUULLUsYY1iNAeGY84Fl74KaRpZSQR2nhtJ4Q8)

```
:t+ṡṡḥ⁇⊃     -- function that expects a 2d-list character above the dictionary as a list of strings
:t           -- duplicate the grid on the stack and transpose the copy
  +          -- append transpose to original grid
   ṡ         -- join list by spaces
    ṡ        -- split resulting string on spaces
     ḥ⁇      -- keep words that are truthy when the first character is removed
       ⊃     -- is the dictionary a superset of this word list
```

`⊃` only considers unique item and a list is a superset of itself (`⊇` might've been a more accurate symbol).
Almost all operators in Gaia are overloaded for different types, which is why `ṡ` can both split and join.

Comment: Isn't this 8 characters, but *18 bytes*?

Comment: @TimothyZorn that would be true if you encode these characters in UTF-8, but Gaia  has a [custom codepages](https://github.com/Glan9/Gaia/blob/master/codepage.md) which allows to encode each of those characters in a single byte. The same applies for Jelly

Comment: Thank you for the information! The characters in the answer are UTF-8 and in fact 18 bytes, so it confused me.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/fb4a2ce2bce6660e1a680a74dd61b72c945e6c3b), 12 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
Dø«ðý#ʒ¦Ā}åP
```

First input is the board as a list of string lines; second is a list of words.

Uses the legacy version of 05AB1E, because it can zip/transpose lists of strings, where in the new version zip/transpose can only be done on character-matrices.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##JY0xDsIwDEV3ThGFlQEGDmARq60UkigJqkrVAaQeA4kzcAdYWBhZWBomLhXsZnn/2/r2X29P582Ys0rv6Zle6bP83abH93pJd5dzL/fghJAraQU4R2qwFZY0CkRNWoMSKIdFL4EmmDEHFZhdYypyJVjZWOJEDceOBbEFNlTCtCbWXAEBdKkiOmiRb5zVSOIPzIBYfgfa6m42XjWc6zBE9Ir@Dn8)

**Explanation:**

```python
D          # Duplicate the first (implicit) input-list
 ø         # Zip/transpose; swapping rows/columns
  «        # Merge the two lists together
   ðý      # Join the strings with space delimiter
     #     # Then split the entire string by spaces
      ʒ    # Filter this list of strings:
       ¦   #  Remove the first character
        Ā  #  And check if it's non-empty
      }    # After the filter: we have a list of the words
       å   # Check for each word if it's in the second (implicit) input-list
        P  # Check if this is truthy for all of them
           # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

I came up with it independently, but I noticed it's basically a port of [*@ovs*' Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/236410/52210), with just larger builtins / stack management. (For convenient I also copied their test case to my TIO.)

Comment: Isn't this 12 characters, but *20 bytes*?

Comment: @TimothyZorn No, 05AB1E uses a custom code page with the 256 characters it knows (linked in the title of my answer), which are 1 byte each. It's fairly common for codegolf languages, like Jelly, Charcoal, etc. The 12 bytes of my program above (in hexadecimal) are: `44, F8, AB, F0, FD, 23, 01, A6, 90, 7D, E5, 50`, and 05AB1E's codepage simply transforms it into something more readable with those 256 characters. You can run and verify the program with these 12 bytes with the `--osabie` flag: [try it online](https://tinyurl.com/6epjecf8).

Comment: Thank you for the information! The characters in the answer are UTF-8 and in fact 20 bytes, so it confused me.

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/), <sup><del>159</del></sup> 129 bytes

```kotlin
{d,b->(b+b[0].indices.map{c->b.indices.joinToString(""){"${b[it][c]}"}}).all{r->r.split(" ").filter{it.length>1}.all{w->w in d}}}
```

-30 bytes thanks to using lambda and type inference (Parlor Trick)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVTfb9owEH7vX3GyeEi0EG2v04hkwBS2QFAShBjiIeRH6y1NUGLWalH@dmY7NBRirfWD73y@8/fdne3fOUtpdkqOGTwFNANNh@oO@PgTpPCcF1EJA0hpyZxEQxgZgHAzL5dCjPFiNFvcC5UQW4h7xxdiisdC2PjnRkpC1lhqcywD587CnwplgT0sAxdkLcQSrwkPlRwUAy0dmwg/dyWFR8gZ3@Mb9qbR3PFMwm@I5xN3zJH1NikWl@xNUi3Q7VqicbZ8vmaDHJDZXxs5fXBujT7IqlwbeWmAIN34P/K5sh1wANwoHftrKZT@TtcuegP@u0SaaoKqDCtQUmmardggYp6qIlrtZuPSwA59OURu72Ywd2zs3h6AVXAu9r2OceQqPKcjVQ@mH6HjYm@EbSWfzolD/EPR06FoaKejM8/Gi3H3CsJHSH13NpOVrbhVzmRC3PPzuTyi@OUQhyyOLu@IFcfYgGZOgrRUi8sJyVfN5pHfPFbQ7MEy4O1K71vDPE/jIBucqsjY9y1t/2m//bwzaRbRMC7Np@BQhX1r3xp@5TTz8yZeQ0ivUK/abynbbcNdjepaN4M0rYq@VZjlIaVMQ7woZkJTFhcVZWYaZw/s0fpSS7/nvvUM/DuM6ro@Ccpa8238pYc2dx6dFyQIH6ECbZ8HRWSIPR36VltEkWkQsiMXA0g0@aEaIJ311unAObM00zhjmoD26j9oTkPLoCzjCEHM6wdoEtCUr2rg4NCTJ3FA6DVR50bVd/XpHw)

**Explanation:**

First, merge the original and transposed board. In each row, find all words longer than 1 letter and for all of them, check their presence in the dictionary.

Comment: Welcome to CGCC! The code looks good but the third test case is showing `false` because of a stray `H` under the `Y` in `LEEWAY`. You might like to check out [Tips for golfing in Kotlin](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/126464/92901) if you haven't already.

Comment: I actually added this `H` on purpose, to produce an "invalid board" case with this single two-word vertical word. How do we approach the topic of using test cases in our TIO links? I saw other people using other test cases. Thanks for the golfing tips, I'm planning to read it thoroughly and iteratively improve my solution.

Comment: Ah I see. Often people use the test cases provided in the question to illustrate that their code behaves as expected but you're free to change them if you want to. All that really matters is that the code works.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 12 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
cUy)¸¸fÅe!øV
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=Y1V5Kbi4ZsVlIfhW&input=WyJNQVAgICIsIk8gQVBQIiwiTkVXIE8iLCJUIEVFTCIsIkhBRCBFIl0KWyJBIiwiQUEiLCJBUFAiLCJEQU5DSU5HIiwiRUVMIiwiR09UIiwiSEFEIiwiTEFaWSIsIkxFRVdBWSIsIk1BUCIsIk1PTlRIIiwiTkFTQUwiLCJORVciLCJQQVdFRCIsIlBPTEUiLCJSVUUiLCJTRUVJTkciLCJTT0xFTFkiLCJTT1JESUQiLCJZRVNURVJEQVkiXQ)

Comment: Isn't this 12 characters, but *16 bytes*?